# Question closed by both Android Enthusiasts and Ask Ubuntu while they referred to each other

Tags: support, scope, android, askubuntu

I asked [a question related to an android app in Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217211/205764) (android.stackexchange.com) which is linked to linux (Ubuntu). My question was put on hold saying that it is off topic, and I was told to post the question in Ask Ubuntu (askubuntu.com).
So [I posted the same question in Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1178064), it was flagged saying that it is off topic.

Please help me!

Comment: FTR: [Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217211/205764) is OP's question on Android Enthusiasts, which appears to me to suit perfectly on Ask Ubuntu. Dunno why AU rejected it...

Comment: You can also take it to their individual meta's to get replies, or chatrooms too, in case this get closed here..

Answer (score 2):

I see that the question has been opened again on Ask Ubuntu.