# Post for clarifications on the updated pronouns FAQ

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct, meta-faq, announcements

Over the past week we've been busy reviewing our previous FAQ to directly address concerns over pronoun usage. We tried to anticipate likely questions, but… missed the mark a bit. Inspired by the Community's excellent curated one, we created a new combined FAQ and, after running it by the moderator team, we're happy to officially release it. Check it out in its new question: [What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336364/what-does-the-code-of-conduct-say-about-gender-pronouns)

We know some of you may still have questions or additional clarification on some points. We're happy to further improve the wording of either questions or answers or add answers to new questions. This post here is the place to talk through that. For ease of voting and responding, **please limit each answer to one specific concern**.

However, note that debating the core of the new rule ("please use stated pronouns") or the validity of people's identities or gender expressions is off-topic for this post, and we won't be entertaining those debates at this point and posts that aren't questions or requests for clarification may be deleted.

Please also note that the FAQ is very long as it is but the questions in it represent a broad spectrum of questions we've seen repeatedly over the last weeks. It doesn't cover many edge cases as an FAQ is not meant to cover/address every edge case that may come up - trying to preemptively legislate for *everything* hypothetically is a bad practice. Some of the bridges we will have to cross when we get to them, and the Community Management team will work with Moderators to deal with those as they come.

So, with all that said... Here's the place to post your requests for clarification/new questions.

Comment: (10K+) If anyone wants to see the old FAQ, it's [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes?cb=1).

Comment: @aCVn The Wayback Machine has [several archives of the FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes), including [an early revision 2 hours after it was posted](https://web.archive.org/web/20191010181002/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes).

Comment: Reminder that comments on meta, like the main sites, should not be used to hold a long, increasingly-tangential discussion between two people on a third person's post - they get all the pings, you get nothing. [chat] is a good venue if you just want to have a conversation with someone .

Answer (score 378):

The FAQ says:

> Many trans people have told us that they feel ***uncomfortable***, unwelcome, or even unsafe here. That isn't what we want

They're not the only ones who are uncomfortable. Other users may feel uncomfortable too, unless they follow the FAQ's advice and change their writing style,  which in itself could be uncomfortable for them:

> #### 4. I find it *really distressing* to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong. Is there really no alternative?

Mods might also feel uncomfortable, but unlike users, they don't have a recourse:

> #### M2. I'm a moderator. I often have to refer to other users, I can't choose which ones I have to refer to, and often it isn't feasible to avoid pronouns. So do I really have to use pronouns I find *uncomfortable*?

It seems to me that this FAQ is okay with making certain people distressed and uncomfortable, and considers this an acceptable trade-off.  Is that true?

I can imagine several groups of people:

1. Users who want others to use their neopronouns
2. Users who find using neopronouns "really distressing"
3. Mods who find it "uncomfortable" to use certain pronouns (probably neopronouns).
4. Users who find it "really distressing" to use pronouns in a way they think is wrong (other than neopronouns)
5. Users who don't want to be misgendered, but don't have neopronouns.

Some of these groups contain people with autism.
Some of these groups contain religious objectors.
Some of these groups contain trans people.

**Whose comfort is priority here?** By answering that, the question of 'whose comfort is given the least consideration' will also be answered.  I'd like that clarified.

---

#### Answer:

> We believe that all participants on Stack Exchange’s websites have the right to participate using the gender pronouns that reflect their identity. You cannot knowingly misgender people. This is what the CoC update is about at its core. Our intention is not to tell you what to think or force you to act in a way that makes you uncomfortable. Interacting with people online is often confusing and distressing. We want to minimize this for everyone. When users are in a situation that makes them uncomfortable, they can always step away or ask for help (raise a flag).
>
> Following the CoC doesn’t require someone to go out of their way to use pronouns. If someone prefers to omit pronouns entirely, they’re welcome to do so, as long as it’s not used in an obviously unnatural way. For example, you can change "The OP wrote in his question" to "the OP wrote in the question" this is a non-obvious rephrasing. If you're writing "The OP wrote in the OP's question" for a user who asked you to refer to them with a neopronoun, that is more clearly discriminatory unless this is your default way of writing.  **No matter the case, no one can knowingly misgender people, so if/when you use third-person pronouns for someone, use their stated pronouns.** – Cesar M♦

Comment: Right now the FAQ says the user's comfort counts for more than the mods, because mod is a special position and is held to a higher standard.

Comment: This is already answered by the FAQ. They are aware that attempts to be inclusive will make some people uncomfortable and they are stating that this is a known and accepted repercussion. That seems like a reasonable line to draw. Also: this answer to the FAQ strongly implies that the comfort of people who state pronouns is less serious and less important than the comfort of people who don't. That's not really okay.

Comment: @Aza You are saying they merely feel uncomfortable. For some, it is **really distressing.** Let's not mince words - Caleb found it **really distressing** to not exercise his freedom of conscience and religious thought. He wasn't "just uncomfortable." He intensely disliked it. Don't read this as a request to debate gender identity, or request to go out of one's way and call them he instead of she or zir instead of xe. It's a request for how SE is weighing anyone else's emotions.

Comment: @TheAnathema Trying to beat down one group by saying your distress is Worse is really missing the point, no matter how you cut it. I'm... not getting into a distress battle here.

Comment: @Aza Hold on. I never said it was a request to "beat anyone down." In fact, I explicitly said it wasn't.

Comment: There's always the alternative of not engaging with users if your personal beliefs clash with theirs for some reason. It's a purely theoretical issue for 99.9% of SE users anyway.

Comment: @JonathanReez: From the text, it seems that moderators are not allowed to *not* engage, nor to disengage.

Comment: @Cerberus dunno, I've been a mod for two years now and never once used anyone's pronouns in all this time. I always call users "OP" or address them by their username.

Comment: @JonathanReez  : It seems to me like not engaging with a person because they self label as having "xe" pronoun is discriminatory. I have a hard time seeing why it should be less problematic then answering them their question and calling them "they".

Comment: I apologize if my previous comment was unclear, it was past 2 am when I wrote it and it was probably not my best. I've written an answer to the question and posted on the answer as a quote and deleted a bunch of no longer needed comments that were about it.

Comment: @CesarM: Since the FAQ does much to say *Use the preferred pronoun if asked to do so*, are there limitations on when it is required to satisfy such an ask? Are we required to defend our writing style if it is challenged? Will we be given time to improve our writing style if it is stilted at first?

Comment: @jxh That's too hypothetical to answer, essentially it will be handled by moderators on a case by case basis. A moderator will always talk to you first and point what needs to be adjusted (if anything).

Comment: @CesarM: Will sentences that have the phrase *male or female* need to be changed to be more inclusive?

Comment: @CesarM: I apologize if my questions seem petulant, but I am genuinely curious what other cases will be considered disenfranchising, and how much I will have to mentally monitor myself when I write to remain inclusive and gender blind.

Comment: I also apologize to you, @Houseman. I got pointed to your answer as a dup of one I had written.

Comment: @jxh Your comment about _male or female_ might be easier to answer if you put the phrase in a complete sentence to provide some context. Otherwise, the only reasonable answer is "it depends on the context".

Comment: @DoctorDestructo The phrase *need to be changed* should be read *need consideration to be changed*, and you are saying *Yes*.

Comment: @jxh I honestly don't understand what you are asking by "male or female need to be changed". If you mean you're not allowed to write that... then, hmm, you are? It feels weird making a call completely out of context. That by itself is not an issue, but depending on the context it might be?

Comment: @CesarM If *he or she* is used as a pronoun, and a neopronoun is asked to be used instead, then if the same individual had been referenced as *male or female*, would it need to be changed too? If I had a sentence that said "this bag would look good on a male or a female", would a challenge to its inclusivity be entertained if the person asking about the bag used a neopronoun as their stated pronoun?

Comment: @jxh Okay, I understand now, please correct me if I am wrong, but since we have stated that some people are neither male nor female, you are saying that "male or female" isn't including everyone. That is not a violation of the CoC, but if a person points out that they are left out (and you are writing it for them, as you said they are the asker), you could rephrase that as "would look good on anyone". Or someone could make that edit to make it more neutral and all's well.

Comment: Unless, of course, the bag _only_ looks good on males and females, and doesn't look good on any other gender. Then that's just a non-inclusive bag, but the sentence would still be accurate.

Comment: @CesarM Yes: *since we have stated that some people are neither male nor female, you are saying that "male or female" isn't including everyone* that is what I meant. And thank you for: *That is not a violation of the CoC*.

Comment: Related: [FAQ contains language likely to offend or alienate people based on religion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336529/628364)

Comment: Can someone give one example of a religion that prohibits specific pronouns? That scenario is being thrown out everywhere, but I can't think of one religion that has this pronoun limitation.

Comment: @CesarM A final note, I appreciate that what you label as edge cases would require  a moderator to review. My gut tells me that the moderators will face many distinct edge cases, and a few of them won't be as "edge" as originally anticipated. In any case, while I, by and large, trust the judgement of moderators, they are after all humans, and the decisions rendered may appear like selective enforcement. So I urge caution and some more thought placed into some of the hypothetical edge cases.

Comment: _"[Trans] are not the only ones who are uncomfortable."_ : Totally agree about that and show how all this mess in in fact a XY problem.

Comment: @Orace Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Legxis, *context*: I only use SO on a regular basis. *fact*: new user poorly welcomed on SO is a known issue. *a priori*: LGBT+ and new user feeling unwelcome are poorly welcomed because they are new, not because LGBT+. *personal advice*: *Most Q&A doesn't event need a third person pronoun (TPP)*, most of the time *I* appear in the Q. and *You* in the A. *Most uses of TPP is not specific* it's used for examples, like: _Alice and Bob_. *Uses of a specific TPP* are for person to person public conversation and at this point the No Asshole Rule apply. Knowingly use the wrong TPP is being an AH._

Comment: If I feel uncomfortable or deeply upset for any reason on this site, am I encouraged to express this feeling to SE and vie for an update to the CoC?

Comment: "Our intention is not to tell you what to think or force you to act in a way that makes you uncomfortable" actually, that's exactly what you're doing, you're literally forcing people to use language that is distressing to them.

Comment: The two types of discomfort are not remotely equivalent. The discomfort trans people feel when being misgendered is a form of gender dysphoria--the very thing that caused them so much harm they had to transition. The discomfort felt by being required to use polite language is self-imposed, and quite small. It at best is just clinging to an outdated understanding of language known as prescriptivism. And, at worse, it is just a desire to be able to voice one's opinion on trans identities, and such is not welcome here or in polite society.

Comment: You guys keep acting like the rules are some sort of horrible disposition, when it's literally just how you have to act in normal society. It doesn't matter if you're more comfortable calling a black person the n-word: you don't get to say it. It doesn't matter if you are more comfortable calling gay people the f-word. It doesn't matter if you are more comfortable referring to a trans person by a different pronoun--such is not acceptable outside of bigoted places, and SE doesn't want to be bigoted.

Comment: @trlkly Also main problem here is that it is easy to ban n-word or f-word... but it becomes harder when same unoffensive sentence suddenly becomes offensive depending on whom you are addressing.

Comment: `"The OP wrote in the OP's question" for a user who asked you to refer to them with a neopronoun, that is more clearly discriminatory unless this is your default way of writing` - what??? we're now saying "OP" is discrimanatory? I'm done with all this.

Comment: There were like -1800 votes on the last post how is this `Interacting with people online is often confusing and distressing. We want to minimize this for everyone.`? It's seems more to us like you SE want to their own thing and not listen to the community.

Comment: Related question on Community Building: https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3126/4159

Comment: @Sam It's not that "OP" is discriminatory, it's that you're avoiding their preferred pronoun.  I have no idea how mods are supposed to know if you meant to discriminate or if you simply thought "OP" sounded better.

Comment: @Ryan_L even still, simply _avoiding_ a _preferred_ pronoun isn't in itself discrimnatory. Discrimination isn't that implicit, it just very much feels like the stance taken by SE on this topic is "guilty until proven innocent" and ever since Joel posted _[that post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand/342615#342615)_ it feels like I can't just help people anymore without all the political bullshush. My stance is very much if you want my help on a programming matter, cool. If you want me to shut up and drink the koolaid at the same time then byyyeeeeeee.

Comment: @Sam "simply avoiding a preferred pronoun isn't in itself discrimnatory." According to the new rules it is.  Not saying I agree with it, but that's SE's stance.

Comment: Edit as an attempt to reply. I thought that was a bannable offense.

Comment: @Lyd: Catholicism (and probably other Christian denominations) teaches that God created men and women for the purpose of procreation. So, sexual acts between people who are not trying to procreate when doing so is knowingly committing a sin. This is not a pronoun issue per se, but using a non-binary neopronoun is as good as just calling the person a sinner outright, which would be a bare insult. A gender neutral pronoun may provide a better pretense of politeness.

Comment: Not an answer to the concern. Sneers and jeers are prohibited by the current policy. What the suggested policy attempts to declare is that willingly avoiding neo-pronouns is automatically a sneer or a jeer. Sometimes it is. But it does not work like this always. Personal relationships is a deeply subjective matter. Sometimes such use would not be any kind of sneer and would be an innocent expression of someone's identity. For avoiding to use neo-pronouns or pseudo-words like "foo" or "bar" *is* an identity in its own right.

Comment: I don't understand how anyone knows what the sex of anyone online is anyway.  This all seems like a huge ordeal out of almost nothing.

Comment: It seems to me that this is finally the answer to the question that Monica had been asking all along. Why couldn't someone just say this and avoid all this trouble?:  `For example, you can change "The OP wrote in his question" to "the OP wrote in the question" this is a non-obvious rephrasing. If you're writing "The OP wrote in the OP's question" for a user who asked you to refer to them with a neopronoun, that is more clearly discriminatory unless this is your default way of writing.`

Comment: Wow, the "answer" by Cesar M is a really spectacular way of dodging the question. So ridiculous.

Comment: @CesarM, could you please remove you change and put it as a separate answer/question. You shouldn’t hijack the others post. I wish to upvote the original question, but I can’t, because I disagree with your answer.

Comment: @CesarM, please follow https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts  **never change meaning**

Comment: @Ryan_L '*@Sam "simply avoiding a preferred pronoun isn't in itself discrimnatory." According to the new rules it is.*' Ehm.. discrimination is an existing concept outside of SE, SE doesn't get to decide the definition no matter how many rules they make.

Comment: @jxh God created xxy people, xxxy people, xy females, xx males, and a dozen other intersex conditions. She created some xx people without a vagina, some without a uterus, some xy people without testicles. How does the bible refer to these people? Note that this is an argument against "god created men and women for the purposes of procreation" and is not related to non-binary people whose sex and potential intersex condition is unrelated to their gender.

Comment: Arguing that trans people are merely "uncomfortable" while everyone else is "distressed" is extremely disingenuous. Many trans people are extremely distressed to be continually misgendered and this unacceptance and disdain for our identities contributes to our high suicide rates. People don't tend to kill themselves for feeling a bit "uncomfortable".

Comment: @Quantic I'm quoting directly from the FAQ, which uses "uncomfortable" for trans people and "really distressing" for others. These aren't my words.

Comment: @Quantic: I think they could be politely referred to by some gender neutral pronoun.

Comment: @CesarM, do you feel that saying “If you're writing "The OP wrote in the OP's question" for a user who asked you to refer to them with a neopronoun, that is more clearly discriminatory unless this is your default way of writing” is hypocritical after hurling Monica out of the door for mere _asking_ if the _future_ policy _might_ proscribe her regular pronounless default way of writing, especially given that she never spoke in such foot-in-mouth sentences like in this example? If your answer is no, do you feel it's a doublethink? (Deleting my question is an answer "no" to both questions.)

Comment: @CesarM, may I suggest a touch-up copyedit? “Interacting with people online is often confusing and distressing. We want to minimize this for everyone.” — The _this_ in this statement is ambiguous in a wrong way. The [priciple of late closure](https://doi.org/10.1016/0749-596X(91)90034-H) makes it read at first as if your goal is to minimize "interacting with people." A rewording of the first sentence can make it closed in the Ferreira-Henderson sense, avoiding the “garden path,” for example: “Interacting with people online often causes confusion and distress.”

Answer (score 252):

In [What does the Code of Conduct say about gender pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336369/269940),

> **3. My religion tells me that people can't change their gender. Aren't you treating me with disrespect in the name of treating others with respect?**
>
> Our users may hold any beliefs they do - be it about gender or even having strong opinions about religions themselves. But if you go out of your way to point out your disagreement about their gender, you aren't behaving in a way we want here - just as people pointing out how wrong they think your religion is aren't behaving in a way we want here. Do not be rude to other people.

This item is a bit offensive, as it mischaracterizes an issue and the people to whom it relates.

In the back and forth of discussion about the CoC and FAQ, a number of people in the trans community raised the point that trans members should not be put in a position of being asked to explain or justify themselves.  That is absolutely the case.  However, that same courtesy was not extended to people with religious prohibitions concerning pronouns.  A number of people were put in a position of needing to explain why the compelled speech issue was a violation of their beliefs.

They explained beliefs that some other people found objectionable.  A key point is that the entire context was an explanation of "why" in response to the CoC/FAQ. They were describing a "conscientious objector" issue.

Aside from those discussions, nobody suggested that anybody thought it would be appropriate to raise religious objections to other people's gender identity, or to air those beliefs in the normal course of business.

Item 3 is a strawman that suggests that people with a religious issue against compulsory speech might use SE sites to express religious-based views that would be disrespectful to others.  At the same time, it completely ignores the religious issue that was actually raised.  So it is both insulting and dismissive.

Aside from that specific issue, parts of the document are unnecessarily inflammatory.  There are a number of paragraphs that provide general context and cover innocent mistakes.  Those are fine.  Other parts characterize any failure to use preferred pronouns as rude, insulting, and other similar terms.  Much of the "Edge Cases" portion is like this.

It is certainly possible to be rude and insulting by purposely using pronouns contrary to what someone has requested.  But many people take offense at characterizing any and all failures to use the right pronoun as being rude or insulting.  It demonizes other users.  The intent may be expressed in the "good parts", but that doesn't make the wording in the "bad parts" not inflammatory.

Comment: People, such as in the [most prominent post on the subject](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6718/brothers-i-must-go), raised objections to a requirement to use preferred pronouns that went beyond just the "compelled speech" objection with phrases like "even if it is a mismatch for their genetic sex." Those read to me like an objection to other people's gender identity. I'm not sure how to interpret that as other than a statement that it could be a "potentially compromising scenario" to the author's religion to respect someone else's self-stated identity in this way.

Comment: (1) On religion: if someone intentionally uses "she" to refer to an user who asked to be referred as "he" because of their religion-grounded views on gender, they also are, in the terms of item 3, "point[ing] out [their] disagreement". Also, item 4 addresses the compelled pronoun usage issue more directly. (2) On rudeness: the FAQ also has several references to good faith mistakes, distinguishing that from intentionally using pronouns contrary to someone's request.

Comment: The fact that this comes after B1 and B4, which both state they their beliefs are objectively, factually wrong just takes the cake.

Comment: @onetothrowaway, that was actually one of the posts I was thinking of.  It explains the author's beliefs and why using certain pronouns would be a problem for them.  That was the entire context, and it was posted in direct response to the CoC/FAQ.

Comment: @rockwalrus, B1 and B4?

Comment: @duplode, I'm totally missing your 1st point and how it relates to religion.  On your last point, those other references don't address the issue.  It's a bit like calling someone a scumbag and then saying, "I didn't mean that in a **bad** way".

Comment: @onetothrowaway As I see it, that prominent post doesn't cross this particular line, as it was written under the (now known to be incorrect) assumption that people would have to use stated pronouns, with no recourse to consistently avoiding pronouns. (It might be worth noting that I did see a comment by someone else that distinctly veered towards that, by arguing that guiding someone towards accepting their true nature was more respectful than using stated pronouns.)

Comment: As item 3, itself, explains, people are free to believe whatever they believe.  The only reason those beliefs were described on a SE site was to explain a personal response to the CoC/FAQ.  Outside of that context, nobody has suggested that it would be appropriate to air those beliefs here.

Comment: @fixer1234: Items 1 and 4 in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336368/628364).

Comment: @fixer1234 I am referring to situations in which someone uses pronouns other than the stated ones as a way to express their disagreement with some conception of gender. As for the other point, passages such as U3 ("Honest mistakes are fine, and everyone should understand that non-native speakers can make a lot of honest mistakes") look pretty clear to me, and not at all offensive.

Comment: @duplode, you may be making a more general point; I was referring specifically to the religious issue as people have framed it.  I agree that some other paragraphs have much better tone and are clear.  But some paragraphs are worded in an unnecessarily inflammatory way.

Comment: [My answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335945/155659) may provide some additional helpful context. I think the FAQ **Am I forbidden to express my opinion about this?** adequately covers the issue. I agree that the **My religion tells me...** section feels a bit off, but I don't have any ideas for improvement.

Comment: @onetothrowaway I think you are characterizing my position there. The issue is not so much that I have an objection to somebody else's identity, but it sets a precedent for being able to express mine when situation arises. I mapped out the direct parallel this compelled speech has to other topics. Also if you can't see why your framing this as "respect" is problematic when I go out of my way to respect others but only refuse to say something that _plainly means something I don't believe is true_, then you have not understood the problem.

Comment: @Xirema, 1. That belief is not trans-compatible, but it isn't transphobia.  People can have different personal beliefs that are inconsistent with someone else's.  2. Nobody has said anything about anyone defending that position on the platform.  Nobody with a religious objection has suggested interfering with trans users rights.  The religious objection is to being compelled to do something themselves.  3. Your objection is to what someone else believes, not to their behavior in treating other people.

Comment: I don't care about what a person believes, but if they refuse to call a trans woman using she/her, that's undeniably a behavior, not a belief, yes? And if users (or ex-moderators...) are blanketly refusing to use the correct pronouns when referring to transgender users, that's undeniably an interfering with the rights of transgender users. So I don't really understand how that isn't transphobia, or what the difference is supposed to be between transphobia or "being not trans-compatible".

Comment: @Xirema, here's an analogy.  Suppose people with certain religious beliefs were experiencing less than welcoming behavior on some SE sites.  So the company published a policy stating that **you** must positively affirm that God says any gender other than what people are born with is wrong.  You'd be pretty upset about that, right?  What if it was framed as simply a matter of being respectful to the religious members and refusing to do it is disrespectful; you could be sanctioned for that rude behavior?  And if you have a problem with that, you're being Godphobic.  That's the issue here.

Comment: If that was the policy SE was setting, I would oppose that policy and not use this site, because I would plainly see that the site does not tolerate the presence of transgender users. What's your point?

Comment: @Xirema then SE should just state that they do not tolerate religious people and delete all religious communities. At least that would be honest!

Comment: @Josef You don't have to be secular to respect the identities of transgender users, unless your religion is wholly and incontrovertibly specifically intolerant of transgender people.

Comment: @Xirema Well, so just don't be a Christian or Muslim or Jew or ... is what you mean?

Comment: @Josef There are lots of transgender people who are still members of each of those religions. Perhaps the people who want to be allies just need to find churches/mosques/etc. that better reflect the kinds of beliefs they want to uphold.

Comment: @Xirema, a religion can be intolerant of transgendering, but adherents can still act respectfully toward transgender people.  Religions can hold that you should not engage in something yourself, but that doesn't mean you should hate others who do.  The point is that a policy of being welcoming and inclusive shouldn't be based on polarizing members against each other, and people gritting their teeth and tolerating the presence of specific groups.  Everybody needs to be a little tolerant and look for simple compromises that everyone can live with.  (cont'd)

Comment: It isn't productive to frame things in a manner that anything not 100% compliant with how one side views things is by definition disrespectful.  I'd suggest that someone whose religious beliefs says non-biological gendering is wrong, who goes out of their way to be polite and to find alternate ways to interact in a positive way, is being **more** respectful.  There needs to be good faith on both sides.  The revised guidelines already provide alternate ways to interact respectfully.

Comment: Ultimately the *policy* relates to misgendering people ("Use stated pronouns (when known)"). Regardless of what your beliefs on gender fluidity may be, whether those beliefs are based in your 4th grade biology class or your religion, if you engage in this behavior, you are in violation of the code of conduct as written today, and as written previously in "be nice". That much is not up for debate at this point.

Comment: But what is that "alternate ways" in this context? Because if all they're doing is trying to find ways to avoid calling a trans woman a woman or avoid calling her by she/her, that doesn't really sound like respect. That doesn't sound like a good faith effort. It just sounds like someone looking for loopholes and thinking they're being clever.

Comment: @Unionhawk, that's not actually what the guidelines currently say.  The current guidelines are to use the stated pronouns if you are using pronouns.  But it is acceptable to not use pronouns at all as long as you are not conspicuously avoiding pronouns just for transgender users.

Comment: @fixer1234 [I was quoting the actual code of conduct directly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: @Unionhawk, I was referring to the clarifications of the generic statement.  :-)

Comment: @Xirema, it isn't a matter of being "clever". Some mechanism is needed to allow people to interact without requiring them to violate their own values. The objective is to avoid innocent mistakes and prevent malicious misgendering. Avoiding pronouns entirely is a safe way to accomplish that, and is not disrespectful.  The objective is not (or at least should not be), to require one user to validate or affirm another user's gender identity.  Except in rare cases, that should be irrelevant.

Comment: Related: [FAQ contains language likely to offend or alienate people based on religion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336529/628364)

Comment: @fixer1234 [I talked about that exact example in a chat room for a post I made a few days ago.](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1386/conversation/avoiding-pronouns).

Comment: Out in the larger world, religious reasons are the most common way to object to trans inclusion (and LGBT inclusion in general). For example, people try to use religious freedom laws to justify keeping trans people out of certain restrooms or to try and avoid providing services to gay people who are getting married. As such, even if the issue was not explicitly brought up here on this site, it is important to establish that no religious exemption will be made to the rules. As, otherwise, people will try them, as they have in the wider world.

Comment: @trlkly, a distinction needs to be made between legitimate issues and trolls who abuse provisions. People do have legitimate religious issues; you can't trample their rights because trolls might find a way to abuse the loopholes. Examples of the kinds of stuff you refer to have gone to court and the courts have generally ruled that people are entitled to act according to their conscience, even if the effects of that aren't inclusive.

Comment: @Xirema - I think avoiding pronoun use where it can be naturally done is a good, reasonable, and non-phobic way of writing when writing to strangers.  I know some trans individuals who aren't out to very many people and who still go by their someday-to-be-deadname, so I know a name is not a good way of identifying someone's gender identity.  I also know some genderfluid individuals whose gender identify can change with the circumstances.  In order to avoid accidental friction or discomfort in the person being replied to, it seems safer to avoid pronouns altogether if I don't know someone.

Comment: "just as people pointing out how wrong they think your religion is aren't behaving in a way we want here" - just trying to understand: does that mean people who go around saying how my religion (or some other religion) is wrong in an off-topic context will be punished under the new guidelines? I feel like I've seen *that* happen a lot more time on StackExchange sites than people using other-than-preferred pronouns intentionally.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery: I know it's half a year later, but that seems "not nice" and seems like a potential Code of Conduct violation even before it was updated. Such messages should probably be flagged. (Obviously, whether it breaks the rules would probably depend on the exact nature of the comment.)

Answer (score 241):

Since all answers to the previous FAQ have been deleted and this concern isn't addressed in the new FAQ I guess I'll ask again:

**How do you think this is going to work for regular (Stack Overflow) users?**

Regular users don't read Codes of Conduct, FAQs or other guidelines. We know this because thousands of garbage questions come in every day.

And for 99% of the users, 99% percent of the time, on 99% percent of posts gender pronouns are completely irrelevant. So you can't rely on users stumbling upon them via normal interaction with the site.

This means the first interaction regular users are going to have with neopronouns will probably be an unpleasant one. You might say that doesn't matter since 99% of the time this won't come up. But keep in mind that 0.01% of first time Stack Overflow users is still a lot of people. Every day.

Also keep in mind that in most parts of the world (like mine) gender (neo-)pronouns are not a thing. We don't learn about them in English class, we don't encounter them when consuming media, we don't hear them in every-day life. This means for most of your users, the Code of Conduct holds surprises.

**If your Code of Conduct includes surprises for at least half of your users, you are going to have a bad time.**

To me it seems in your quest for inclusiveness, you just forgot about everybody who doesn't speak English natively.

Do you have any plans to make this easier for non-native speakers, other than canned reassurances (like U3)?

Comment: Hi, I'm a non-native English speaker. I had a hard time (and still do, fellow CMs can attest) getting out of neutral he - as it is de facto the neutral pronoun in Portuguese (nothing remotely similar to they/it). But I try, sometimes I don't get it right, I correct myself next time and move on. Users who see this for the first time may not fully grasp it, and we are okay pointing them to resources or the CoC through mod messages and helping them along. This isn't going to be applied draconianly (is that a word?) and we're here to help people along.

Comment: @CesarM Kudos to you for effort. But now imagine how hard English is on people who are not in constant, intense contact with native-speakers who are there to gently correct your use of the language. And StackOverflow points users to various resources all day long, it doesn't seem to make much impact. I realize it's not your intention to apply this draconically (dictionary says not a word, but I don't care), but on SO neither users nor moderators have the time to hand-hold every user, adding another hurdle isn't going to make it any easier.

Comment: @CesarM, put yourself in the shoes of someone who speaks Cantonese (no gendered pronouns) or worse, Japanese (linguists are still arguing as to whether it *has* third-person pronouns, or even pronouns at all).  When it comes to understanding the fuss about pronouns, you've got a major advantage by speaking a language that changes pronouns based on gender.

Comment: I'd say this was covered by "Does this mean that I will be in trouble if I ever get someone's pronouns wrong?", but mostly by the fact that use of third-person pronouns is rare on SO. Talking about a third party *at all* on SO probably indicates comments that are getting out of hand anyway.

Comment: @CesarM But right now you're perfectly proficient in English. I could say I'm not a native speaker either, but I'm also perfectly proficient. The real question here isn't about who is or isn't a native speaker, it's about who is proficient enough to understand A) They're doing something against the CoC and B) to figure out how to fix that. I've seen questions where the grammar was bad enough that I couldn't figure out what they were asking. Those are users it's about.

Comment: @Raedwald this would be easier if our previous exchange on this exact topic was not deleted along with the previous FAQ. But the fact that this will rarely occur on SO makes it worse in my opinion, not better. It's an incredibly complicated policy that is useless most of the time, because it simply does not apply. So normal (ie non-meta) users will stumble upon it and either be totally confused or start the same discussion we are having right now.

Comment: This is an absurd proposition. If we allow people to misgender others because they haven't read the CoC, shouldn't we also allow off-topic questions, spam and other stuff because people have not read the site rules?

Comment: @Renan there are two key differences: 1) You can see good examples of stellar, on-topic questions all over SO. Off-topic questions are deleted fairly swiftly most of the time. On the other hand you'd be hard pressed to find pronouns anywhere. And 2) Spam is frowned upon all over the internet. Nobody can arrive on SO and expect Spam to get through without opposition. Pronouns on the other hand are exotic. At least for *me* both on the internet and in real live, SO is the only part of *my* life where anybody cares about pronouns at all.

Comment: @Renan besides, if the argument seems absurd it's because you have constructed a strawman here. The argument is not that misgendering (huh, my Firefox-dictionary doesn't know this word?) should be ok. But that the CoC as presented (along with the FAQ) is unsuitable for at least SO, and possibly for other Sites. **Especially** since it makes it harder for non-native speakers to participate. Meaning in order to be inclusive for one group, this CoC unintentionally excludes another group.

Comment: I don’t know, it seems like the only **real** rule in the CoC is to use specific pronouns *when requested* (it specifically states that they do not expect people to do research or look in someone’s profile). So no one can stumble into a violation – someone would have to *specifically* ask them to use a different pronoun, and then they would have to repeatedly refuse.

Comment: @Mena "neopronouns are not part of the English language". This is not how the English language works. English is a living, evolving language. For English there is nothing equivalent to the [Académie française](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise) that makes official pronouncements about what is and is not "correct English". The respected [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary) does not *specify* the permitted words and their meanings, it *describes* which words are used and how they are used.

Comment: It might be useful, as 194636 suggested, to provide mods with guidance for how to approach these situations to explain things to non-native English speakers. But I can’t see how you could run into a problem without multiple people talking about the issue with you first.

Comment: @Raedwald I get your point, but if you don't find those words on the recent edition of any established English dictionary, you can say in all certainty that they are not, in fact, English words. Otherwise any given word should be considered as English just because it's being used contextually to an English sentence. Language is a living thing: I totally agree, which is why attempting to impose arbitrary norms and conventions generally fails. Neologisms become part of the language through widespread adoption, not coercion.

Comment: @Raedwald Command + space (spotlight/apple dictionary) "zir" gives a proper definition.

Comment: @divibisan the second rule that was added recently was "Prefer gender-neutral language". And I think Monica's and Robert's cases show that "stumbling" into a violation can happen anytime to anyone. Furthermore if even a long-standing mod [is confused by the warnings sent for CoC-violations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389906/im-resigning-as-a-moderator-from-all-stack-exchange-sites?noredirect=1#comment736979_389906) how do think this will go for average users?

Comment: I think, that the "Prefer gender-neutral language" rule should be changed to "Use of gender-neutral language is recommended.", and it shouldn't be enforced unless the mistake is intentional. If this is a reason for banning someone, then at certain points we should have all been kicked.

Comment: @void “prefer” isn’t a rule, it’s a recommendation. For example, using “he” as the default is discouraged, but explicitly allowed. And those cases were different from this. Robert was suspended for old-fashioned rude and abusive flags, not a "pronoun violation”.

Comment: @divibisan If it's in the CoC it can be enforced, otherwise it wouldn't need to be in there in the first place. Anyway, in the current climate I don't trust SE to handle problems related to pronouns or gender-neutrality fairly. Regardless of the exact wording in the CoC. And I assume you read through the posts related to Robert, I got the impression he doesn't think his case is old-fashioned at all. Several users voiced the suspicion that the flags were a good excuse to silence a strong dissenting voice. That's also the impression I got.

Comment: Not knowing the rules is never an excuse to break them. If you violate the rules, it stands to reason that you will be informed of them, and then be expected to follow them from then out. I don't think the non-native speaker issue is a big one, as people learning a language tend to respond well to being told that what they said was not correct. I have been on many sites with similar rules as this one, and non-native English speakers are never a problem.

Comment: Sure, but it's detrimental to both the site and it's users that those rules are not in line with what's normal around the internet. My country has laws that void EULAs if they are found to be *unusual according to local customs*. I think that's extremely reasonable. I have been on many sites too, and seen people struggle with simpler rules. I guess we associate with quite different communities.

Comment: @CesarM I think what you are saying is correct, yet highly problematic. The CoC and all surrounding FAQs *are* draconian. Yet, you do realize that they need to be applied in a non-draconian way for the majority of our users. This is highly problematic because it's totally arbitrary, and arbitrary stuff like this does not work when moderating. It exposes moderators to accusations of bias. In fact, it *will be applied based on bias*. You can't put out rules and put it on *moderators* to adapt them because they are misguided. Write them correctly in the first place.

Comment: "if you don't find those words on the recent edition of any established English dictionary" is a very wide description. You'll find an awful lot of Maori loan words in the Oxford Dictionary of New Zealand English, for example, and many will not be familiar to a lot of Maori speakers (just as many words in any large dictionary will not be familiar). Neopronouns are almost certainly collated somewhere, thus are valid by the definition above.

Comment: @pygosceles singular they has been a part of the english language since the 14th century.

Comment: History time: Singular they has been around since 14th century and predates singular you ("you" is plural, "thou" is singular!). Its use was deprecated by some in 19th century, swapping it for "default" he. Now the usage returns. | Defaulting to "he" is not only discriminatory against nonbinary people but also women. The language shapes our world. Using "he" by default erases existence of women, especially in tech-related spaces. I've been in such spaces. I've known some brilliant women who felt discouraged from posting because of it.

Comment: @h4z3 The past is not relevant here. Most users were born in the 20th century, and that's the English they are familiar with. Saying that the usage of singular they returns is inaccurate at best. English lacks a single governing authority that many European languages have. Declaring that "my" English is deprecated and "yours" or SO's English is the right one is unwelcoming. Language may shape our world, but our world also shapes our language. Unilaterally decreeing the language is to be changed and expecting the world to follow is the wrong way around and it's certainly not nice.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, as a native English speaker I was taught growing up that "he" is a perfectly acceptable neutral pronoun in lots of contexts. I have come across he-as-neutral in published authors (including women) in contexts that clearly is referring to a mixed-gender group. I personally try to use "he or she" or something like that, but it's sometimes awkward, and using "they" often leaves confusion about what the author is referring to, which defeats the whole purpose of using pronouns in the first place.

Comment: @void I was born in 20th century as well. I've been using singular you since secondary school, while not being a native English speaker. Nobody taught me it, I just picked it up while reading and I asked someone about it just to be sure. I've been using it for years and nobody minded before the whole "singular they is wrong" emerged. As for some governing authority, you're right, there is none, but big dictionaries add the definitions and usages for singular they and neopronouns, so maybe it really returns and means something? +I never said default he is wrong, just discriminatory.

Comment: @h4z3 As far as I can tell it's still the case that nobody minds that _you_ are using singular they. People start objecting when SE tells them they have to do so as well. SE left it each user whether they write American English or British English (or any other variant), now they started to enforce a particular way to write for a particular issue. It's not surprising to me that this doesn't go down well. I guess big dictionaries will add these usages when enough people use them. At that point it's OK for SE to recommend that usage (but demanding everybody use that language is still wrong).

Comment: @h4z3 Don't get me wrong. I'll fight for your right to use singular they, just as I'll fight for everybodies right to express their identity in any way they like (that includes pronouns). In return I expect those same people to allow me to keep writing the English I grew accustomed to. That default he is descriminatory is **your** (and SEs) oppinion. Again, I'll fight for your right to hold that opinion, but presenting this opinion as a fact, excluding all other viewpoints, is quite frankly not nice.

Answer (score 184):

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336367/287315):

> **U2. I'm worried that I may get banned. Should I be?**
>
> Not if you're acting in good faith. If you go out of your way to talk to, or refer to, people in ways you know they will find upsetting, then you are likely to get the same sort of escalating warnings and suspensions as you would for wilfully upsetting people in other ways.

What you did to Monica, *before* this policy was in effect, for *asking questions about its implementation,* combined with the fact that Monica's de-modding [has not been reversed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335508/287315) even provisionally pending actual process, mean the correct answer to this FAQ point is **yes.**

The FAQ should be updated to reflect that reality.  In the alternative, the reality should be updated to reflect that FAQ by reinstating Monica immediately* and providing stronger assurances, perhaps in the Terms of Use, that processes will be followed and users should not have to fear bans from good-faith interactions.

*: and probably also reinstating [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336339/287315) [for supporting her](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes#comment1112253_336236) (and/or [defending the CEO's silence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336314/287315)).

---

Update: A link to this discussion from under the referenced post keeps getting deleted, and a suggested edit to simply remove U2 and its incorrect answer was very quickly rolled back.  While discussion on possible corrections should be here instead of there, and the comment clearly indicates that, the in-context pointer comment should **not** be censored out to help prevent people reading that part of the FAQ from being misled by its content into thinking something that is inaccurate under present Stack Exchange enforcement practices.  This seems to be just another example of how the company is trying to cover up silencing of dissent from their views and hope that anyone who finds this problematic [just goes away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335508/287315).

Update 2: I have received an official response from the entire Meta.SE mod team, that I should **NOT** be pointing out this inaccuracy in the FAQ.  That is because the bans/demodding/suspensions others received were "in the past" and "We can not change the past." [sic] even though the conditions continue into the present (and per update 3, the future).  I pointed out that the FAQ should apply to the present, and that they could change the present state if they wanted to, but they don't actually want to.  The official response to that so far is silence, hoping that anyone observing this disconnect with present reality will just go away.

Update 3: As some readers may have discerned from my 1 rep, I was suspended specifically for calling out this issue (and could not edit this update in until after the conclusion of that first suspension week), without any substantive response from the mods to direct messages reinforcing that I do actually still think this is an issue that exists in the present.  By issuing the suspension, it is clear they know about the disconnect but don't care and will continue suppressing voices of dissent who would dare to call out their actions against the community.

Please be sure to spread the word further once I get banned/suspended again for a good-faith effort to get more accuracy in an FAQ answer incorrectly claiming people shouldn't worry about getting banned for something like that.  You are also welcome to respectfully call attention to this issue in context yourself, if you don't mind also getting ironically suspended/banned for pointing out the risk.

[image: User network profile]

Comment: Honestly at this point I have lost all motivation to contribute to Stack Overflow. My time can be better spent doing my work and being with my family, I don't need the headache of wondering whether or not I'm being polite enough when helping strangers.

Comment: Same here. If anybody wants they can add me to [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/287315) of users no longer contributing substantive content at least while the status quo remains.  (However, as a non-mod, I may not be eligible for that list.)  That's also why I'm not that concerned about consequences if I myself get banned for posting this Answer, which might happen.

Comment: I **really** hope they look into getting Monica back on board, but I do think it made sense to get an acceptable CoC in place first. They need to know that she'll follow the rules before they hire her back, and she needs to know what the rules are before she can agree to follow them. No one has ruled out reinstating her, have they?

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Asking questions about the CoC can get you kicked out. So can supporting someone who that has already happened to. The point I see reflected in your comment is that violating these rules regarding not using the right pronouns, or asking questions about the policy, **can** get you kicked out, which is contrary to what the FAQ currently indicates.  Either the FAQ or the reality can change to make the two more consistent, and that inconsistency is what this post tries to address.

Comment: The CTO of StackOverflow has acknowledged that the way Monica was treated was a mistake. He said, "We’ll be reaching out to her directly to apologize for the lack of process, privacy, and to discuss next steps." Do we have reason to believe that isn't going to happen? We know this company moves at a snail's pace; maybe they just need time to figure out what they're going to offer, and what they can accept. Monica seems like a reasonable person, so she probably never would have agreed to that last CoC if they had offered to reinstate her. I'm glad they waited (but they better get on it soon).

Comment: @DoctorDestructo He [said that, but then didn't do it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335873/287315). It would not take much time at all to do at least some of the things being discussed, like a correction statement or restoring mod privileges that never should have been removed in the first place (5 min!). Items that are fast & should be high priority (given the fallout) remaining undone is reason to think they won't be. Your point that it takes so long underscores that the FAQ as it stands is inconsistent w/reality, & at least one of the two needs to change to be consistent with the other.

Comment: @WBT I guess what I'm saying is, I'm glad they didn't put her back on the job before they had the CoC finalized. That could have led to a situation where they had to fire her again (if, for example, she said she could not in good conscience agree to the new rules). That wouldn't have gone over well with the community, even if they followed the rules this time. They kept us in the dark a long time before rolling out the revised CoC, but they did come through in the end. As far as I'm concerned, they bought another week. After that, it's time bring out the torches and pitchforks.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Then you would seem to vote for the FAQ being edited in response to this post.  Do you agree that would be a helpful improvement to the status quo?

Comment: This just doesn't really seem relevant to the *text* of the FAQ. There's certainly reasonable reasons for people to distrust SE and feel afraid, but that's a **bad thing**. We shouldn't change the FAQ to codify that fear into law, but push SE to better live up to the commitments they made to fairness

Comment: @WBT You mean modify it so that it says "Yes, you should worry about getting banned"? No, they shouldn't do that. I thought you were suggesting it for rhetorical reasons. If Monica can live with the new CoC/FAQ, and is still interested in being a mod even after everything they've done to her, then they should reinstate her-- or, to put it your way, "update reality".  Messing with the FAQ is the last thing they should do.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Or at least remove the clear untruth.  Monica has stated she thinks immediate reinstatement followed by some discussion process showing any violation is desired, but as the FAQ currently stands it tells readers something that is flat-out wrong.

Comment: Just to follow up on my previous comments: it appears SO is going to stop just short of cleaning up this mess. I apologize for defending them, and thank you for this post @WBT. I do think it's more of a protest than a serious request for clarification, but under the circumstances, I think protest is justified.

Answer (score 177):

> 4. I find it really distressing to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong. Is there really no alternative?
>
> You can often avoid using
> pronouns altogether. It's actually pretty rare to need third-person
> pronouns at all on most Stack Exchange sites. But conspicuously
> avoiding using pronouns for one group of people while using them
> normally for others is a way of refusing to recognize their identity,
> and that is discriminatory. Please don’t do that.

Does this mean that completely avoiding pronouns as a style of writing is now considered acceptable, presuming it is done consistently?

---

### Answer from Catija:

As Cesar and Aza said in the comments, if you want to stop using third person pronouns entirely, that is fine. What you can not do is stop using pronouns only when referring to people who have specific pronouns - whilst using them normally for other people. But, be warned, if you're doing this in a way that is particularly obvious it may be quite confusing to some. Aza words this well:

> For example, consistently wording sentences in extremely clumsy (avoidable) ways to avoid pronouns could leave someone feeling othered, even if you are consistent about it. And advocating vocally against using pronouns because those people would also be... not great.

The FAQ also links to a guide for how to write in a natural gender neutral way.

Comment: I imagine this is, at minimum, non-justiciable. A stated policy on this question beyond "don't conspicuously avoid using That Person's pronouns" is not likely to be meaningful. I wouldn't expect an official answer to this one, for that reason.

Comment: @Aza if SE is okay with people not using any pronouns, there wouldn't be a need to bring anyone to trial over it :)

Comment: I'm... genuinely not sure what you're talking about or how it relates to pronouns. I'm a little out of the loop. But to be clear, _are_ still some ways to hurt people here that are important to keep in mind, and I can see why one would warrant escalation. For example, consistently wording sentences in extremely clumsy (avoidable) ways to avoid pronouns could leave someone feeling othered, even if you are consistent about it. And advocating vocally against using pronouns because _those people_ would also be... not great. But just, quietly doing this? Probably non-justiciable, yeah.

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes. To a degree. If you are conspicuously not using pronouns for a specific group whilst using he/she normally elsewhere, then that's a problem. If you are not using pronouns at all, that's... not punishable. I wouldn't recommend removing pronouns from your writing altogether as exactly welcoming, but that is your call, not mine.
Aza put it well above.

Comment: @CesarM Thank you Cesar. Hopefully your clear answer will address Monica's original concern over enforced pronoun usage and help you folks make amends :-)

Comment: @Aza I personally don't have any issues with using pronouns of any kind, but others disliked the compelled speech aspect of the previous FAQ. With this new rule no one is compelled to say anything.

Comment: I hope you're correct.

Comment: *"Please don’t do that."* What does this mean in terms of actions from StackExchange when you still do that? E.g. Monica apparently got demodded for described how she does not liking to use the singular pronoun 'they' and suggests to avoid using the pronoun. But obviously she has not eliminated using 'he' and 'she' everywhere else as well. So she violates this point 4 (only as a thought crime because she may not have ever been in the *situation* to use they on SE). Does "please don't do that" mean you can not be moderator anymore if you do not (open to) use singular 'they'?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus The actual FAQ answers that specifically in the post regarding [moderators and curators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336367/284336) - M2.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus "she has not eliminated using 'he' and 'she' everywhere else as well" Apparently she has, at least that is what she says and as far as I can tell it is true.

Comment: @Goyo I must give it to you that she makes indeed very little use of 'he' and 'she', less then I would, but it is not absent. Anyway, you made a good point and it makes my comment about the implications of "please don't do that" even stronger. Without transparency about that issue this whole FAQ (and especially the accompanying calming comments that contributers, the community, do not need to worry) looks pretty but it is based on a weak foundation.

Comment: @Catija do the recent edits, which specify the situation more further, mean that it is *in principle* allowed to avoid selectively specific pronouns (although not advised or desirable)? But it is *in practice* that this should not be done in a clumsy or obvious way such that it becomes demeaning. Like: say if Sextus is 'he' and Eros is 'they' then a sentence like *"Sextus and Eros went to a bar. He drank beer and Eros drank wine"* would be considered unnecessarily obvious and clumsy. (regarding the M2 point, many people including me, might still consider this situation not cleared up)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus To be clear, she was made aware in mid-september that doing that could be problematic and then stopped (in SE, IIUC). From the [horse's mouth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes/cb=1#comment1112206_336236). Now, given the circumstances, I wouldn't be surprised if she made some mistakes but I have not spotted any.

Comment: @CesarM Is it OK if the "specific group" I avoid using 3rd person pronouns for is *all Stack Exchange users* (and probably pseudo-anonymous users elsewhere online)? I'd like to continue to use pronouns normally for people like public figures, people I know personally, and hypothetical people I made up.

Comment: @Catija "As Cesar and Aza said in the comments, if you want to stop using third person pronouns entirely, that is fine." That's less restrictive than the "What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?" post, which [says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336369/285745) _in the context of "I find it really distressing to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong"_ that pronouns can be avoided. As JohnathanReez says, this is a key point (as far as we in the public know it's Monica was de-modded). Would be great to clarify whether it's okay to avoid pronouns even if it isn't "really distressing."

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Since the genders of the two are unknown, I'd actually be confused by a version that used pronouns at all... so actually, "*Sextus and Eros went to a bar. Sextus drank beer and Eros drank wine*" would be preferred just because it's more clear. If Eros uses "they", using the pronoun would probably need to be avoided because it would be ambiguous whether it was singular or plural they... if you said "*He drank beer and they drank wine.*" you could actually be saying Sextus drank beer and both Sextus and Eros drank wine. It's compex but we're not asking mods to be draconian. :D

Comment: @henry I don't see the two statements as contradictory. I think the question title may be the problem there... the answer relates to anyone, not only people who feel that it's "really distressing"... the point in all of this is to treat people respectfully and equally. If you honestly want to stop using third person pronouns entirely, that's fine... It may be difficult.

Comment: @Catija so that means that we *can* avoid the use of 'they'. For instance 'Bob and Alice went to a bar, he drank beer and she drank wine' is ok. But say, when Bob prefers 'ze', then we are *allowed* to consider  'Bob and Alice went to a bar, ze drank beer and she drank wine' as unclear and therefore try to avoid the use of pronouns, yet keep the use of pronouns in the other occasions?

Comment: I get it that it is desired that there is some clause that prevents abbuse and trolling by means of 'not using a particular pronoun'. But [for some of us these clauses are very difficult](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335743). It would be more obvious as a non-draconian rule when this is made more explicitly. E.g. add after the 'conspiciously sentence' (that means, you can avoid using neopronouns but do not abbuse that right to specifically annoy a specific group of people).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus We’re not trying to require y’all to write in a way that may be ambiguous. The reason it’s problematic to use they in that specific case is because of the number. If you were talking about a single person who uses they, then you shouldn’t avoid it. “Blair ran a marathon last week. They came in tenth place.” I understand that some will find this odd and I did when I first started learning but it’s gotten much more comfortable as I’ve used it. With the ze example, it’s the same unless it’s commonly known that Bob uses ze. But you should use names for both, not Bob only.

Comment: I find that 'ze' is confusing because not everbody may understand it, because it may not be clear to everybody that Bob uses 'ze'. His friends and wider acquaintances may use it often but on a public forum/q&a-board it may not be obvious unless the people are very close collaborators. So even when it is in a single form 'Ze came in tenth place' (and in some cases also with 'they') I would not use it because it might be confusing (are all readers gonna understand that 'they' refers to 'Bob'? (With 'he' and 'she' we make these [connections easier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336273/389297))

Comment: @Catija  So something like  “Bob ran a marathon last week and they got very tired.” might be still ambiguous, even when there is a single person in the story. Of course, I get that only avoiding 'they' and 'ze', but keeping all other 'he' and 'she' in a *single* sentence, *single* alinea or even a *single* post, will be not so nice. But when writing a next comment or post and talking to a crowd without they or ze, then would it be fine to use 'he' and 'she' again?

Comment: The reason that I use singular pronouns 'he' and 'she' is because they are easier than the pronoun 'they' in the cases when the pronoun has a specific singular antecedent. In most cases the pronouns 'he' and 'she' unambiguously refer to a specific person for which it is clear that the person is a man or woman. When it is not clear for a particular person whether the person is a man or woman then I wish to *not* use pronouns. That has little to do with (creating/increasing) inequality and everything with writing in a particular preferred  (clear) way. Do not take Bob and Alice away from us.

Comment: @Catija, your answer here effectively writes the word "conspicuous" out of the FAQ. I was pleased with that word's inclusion, since I took it to mean that we may avoid someone's pronouns for reasons of conscience or style or clarity so long as we ensure the resulting construction isn't something clumsy that draws attention to what we've done. But your answer now makes it sound like any such approach will be automatically considered to be a rule violation if detected at all. That doesn't seem consistent with banning only "conspicuous" pronoun avoidance.

Comment: @Catija fair enough, it does sound like "the question title may be the problem there..." As far as I've seen the one place this is addressed directly is under that question title and in your comment response here. I don't know of course, but in light of what Monica statements I expect it's something many people are following. A rewording of that question title, or moving the answer to a different question, could help clear up this important point.

Comment: @Catija your "answer from Catija" section of this answer says: "The FAQ also links to a guide for how to write in a natural gender neutral way. " I searched, but couldn't find it. could you provide a direct link to that guide please? perhaps inserting it into your "answer from Catija" section of this answer? thanks.

Answer (score 125):

> **4. I find it really distressing to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong. Is there really no alternative?**
>
> You can often avoid using
>   pronouns altogether. It's actually pretty rare to need third-person
>   pronouns at all on most Stack Exchange sites. But conspicuously
>   avoiding using pronouns for one group of people while using them
>   normally for others is a way of refusing to recognize their identity,
>   and that is discriminatory. Please don’t do that.

What is *conspicuously avoiding* and how are you going to determine that?

I am not a native English speaker and my writing style is all over the place. It is not consistent. Sometimes I will use pronouns, sometimes I will use OP, sometimes I will use username. Sometimes I will repeat OP or username several times in a sentence if it is hard for me to write it at given moment.

I also use pronouns for people I know, and I avoid them for people I don't know. Even when someone states their pronouns, I will most likely avoid them unless I get to know (or encounter) that person often enough to be sure I will not make a mistake.

Under current rules, my writing can certainly be interpreted like *avoiding pronouns* for certain group of people.

I have no problem in doing my best to honor people's pronouns, but having potential suspension hanging over my head because how I might express myself makes me extremely uncomfortable in participating here.

---

This FAQ is not much of improvement over the old one.

As long as one can be punished for writing in certain way and as long as normal unoffensive sentence can become offensive depending on to whom you are talking there is a whole a lot of room for power abuse.

Comment: "conspicuously avoiding" is **conspicuous**, by definition: it's obvious, easy to see, easy to notice. A writing style that is really "all over the place" will not be avoiding anything.

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC What Raedwald said is correct. That's pretty much a case let's see how it goes. You're not going to get suspended outright without a warning first, and on that warning you can get more information on what caused it / talk about specific instances instead of abstract concepts, which is a lot clearer for everyone involved.

Comment: This is my main objection to the FAQ as well (for similar reasons even as a Native English Speaker). The fact that it says both "you can avoid pronouns" and then "you cannot" is extremely confusing and I just do not trust this policy to be enforced with the guiding hand I used to see from moderators on this site (basically I don't trust SE to let the moderators be moderators on this issue)

Comment: @LinkBerest This is basically just a specific case of: "Don't be a jerk". You can avoid pronouns, just don't be a jerk about it.

Comment: @CesarM This is inane. The point of a code of conduct is quite clearly to establish guidelines of how to act so the people might use SE sites without constant intervention from moderators. Making the policy "let's see how it goes" means exactly the opposite. If that is a policy you are happy enacting, you would probably be best off taking more time to write a better policy.

Answer (score 75):

If an answer is written, and uses a particular pronoun, let's say "he", and a user suggests an edit to this answer to change it to "they", and no other changes are required in the answer (i.e. it's otherwise perfect), do I accept this edit? What if I reject it instead? Assume the edit reason is "being more inclusive" and the suggester doesn't clarify that OP has specified (e.g. if they say link to OP's bio which says they prefer "they" then the edit is acceptable), and it's not visible anywhere on the QA itself.

An example might be [either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/349867/4) of [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/346416/2) edits I made (although mine were not suggested).

What if a user mass suggests edits changing "he" to "they".

---

### From Catija:

There's two separate cases, which is, I think, where the struggle here lies. In all cases, **mass edits are bad**. Please don't seek out edits to make.

1. **A post speaks of a hypothetical or generic person.** In this case, unless the gender somehow matters to the post, being gender neutral is beneficial.

   - Be very careful that the edits don't harm the post or make it confusing. This is particularly the case in code.
   - Be aware that *suggesting* pronoun-only edits should be acceptable but do be certain to correct more than just the pronouns. If there are spelling, punctuation or grammatical errors, fix those, too.
2. **A post speaks of an actual person.** In this case, unless you know the pronouns are incorrect **AND** you know that the person is generally known on Stack Exchange to have identified their pronouns, do not make the gender neutral.

   - It's possible the poster actually knows the correct pronouns.
   - If you know their pronouns from elsewhere, disclosing them yourself can "out" them to a community where they wished to be anonymous.

Comment: This is a reasonable question, I think. To me, the answer would depend on how old the question is, and how many edits are being made. If someone's making a one-off change to a question that was recently posted, yeah, I'd approve. If someone's mass-editing questions from 2009... eh.

Comment: Making a post more gender-neutral is generally ok - unless the user has stated their pronouns elsewhere and you're pointed to it, or if they roll it back (then leave it be). We do not recommend/encourage people to go looking for these and making mass-edits, but rather editing as they naturally encounter and wish to do so.

Comment: Mass edits are never okay, pretty much regardless of the motivation. Also, although I am perhaps personally invested, [this edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/349867/4) was problematic because you admittedly *did not know* what the individual's chosen pronouns were. As such, you should not have submitted an edit that imposed pronoun(s) *you* thought were correct. This is, in my mind, equally as insulting to the party being referenced.

Comment: I didn't mean any insult, I simply thought (at the time) that "they" was more inclusive than "he". But I believe Cesar is saying that, had that been an edit suggestion, it would be correct to accept, because it wasn't obvious on the QA what OP's pronouns were, and the edit was to make the answer more inclusive. Incidentally it was rolled back 1 minute later anyway and I never made that kind of edit again.

Comment: There's two separate cases, which is, I think, where the struggle here lies. 1. **A post speaks of a hypothetical or generic person.** In this case, unless the gender somehow matters to the post, being gender neutral is beneficial. 2. **A post speaks of an actual person.** In this case, unless you know the pronouns are incorrect **AND** you know that the person is generally known on SE/SO to have identified their pronouns, do not make the gender neutral. It's possible the poster actually knows the correct pronouns.

Comment: Exactly what Catija said. Note your use of the word "inclusive". This is a great *general* goal, but it isn't applicable when the post refers to a specific person. Then, it isn't so much about being inclusive (because there's only one person to include) so much as being respectful (of that person's identity).

Comment: Note, also, that both of those examples you gave were weird Meta cases, where the answers were referring to actual people. That's certainly not the norm on a Q&A site, or even on Meta, where we do prefer to speak in generalities rather than calling out individuals. But there are moderation-related cases where it is necessary, and it's okay on Meta, as long as you do so respectfully and judiciously.

Comment: @CesarM So just to make sure I'm understanding, it is acceptable to edit a post to be more gender neutral when pronouns are unknown? We have had a lot of strife at The Workplace in the past with some users being upset about their posts being edited to only change "he" to "they", some of which resulted in edit wars and locked posts. What is the guidance for moderators to handle this sort of situation?

Comment: The change of a generic he into something else like he/she, they or avoiding the pronoun is a change of the *style* of the post. I believe that this should be first mentioned in a comment rather than abruptly changed directly. (I would not be surprised if there are meta posts about the correct way to suggest these kind of minor edits without asking first).

Comment: I just want to highlight that, when reviewing edits, its *really really hard* to figure out who a given pronoun might be referencing. Many people *already* don't use the review queues because the mental burden of dealing with fact-checking every little detail is not worth *their* time. Adding pronouns into the mix feels very Papers, Please-y.

Comment: No, you shouldn't make edits just to change the pronouns used with no other changes, even if a word other than "he" is used when it should obviously be something else. Edits should improve the question/answer in a measurable way. [SO Meta discussion on this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265300/3011319). Though I would agree that moderators decline far too many good and worthwhile edits. I would make the edit only if you have the reputation to instantly edit without approval, and don't change "he" to "they".

Comment: Note that review queues are already problematic and avoided by many users because the automated review checking process is deliberately infested with traps for the unwary. Making that worse is not a win.

Answer (score 68):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

## FAQ contains language likely to offend or alienate people based on religion

The FAQ in its current state contains language likely to offend or alienate people by stating that things they deeply believe are objectively, factually false. If you don't believe that, imagine that the shoe is on the other foot, and some of the community members who believes that calling someone by a pronoun other than their biological sex is a personal insult to God<sup>1</sup> wrote an FAQ with answers like the following:

---

### Hypothetical disrespectful FAQ answers

> #### 1. What's this business about "pronouns"?
>
> God gave each person a pronoun at birth. It would be offensive to Him for someone to refer to a man that He created as "she" or a woman as "he". Some people are rebellious. For instance, a woman might be erroneously convinced that she is neither a man nor a woman and ask to be referred to as "they". Even if someone indicates what pronouns should be used to refer to them, please use the pronouns that God gave them as you would for others.

> #### 4. What was that about being neither men nor women?
>
> Some people erroneously claim they are neither men nor women. The usual term for such people is "non-binary" and they’re often included in the term “transgender”. Just as you would want to be corrected if you were driving the wrong way down a one-way street, you should correct someone who wants to be referred to with a pronoun that doesn't fit them.

> #### 3. My gender identity tells me that some people have fluid gender or are nonbinary. Aren't you treating me with disrespect in the name of treating others with respect?
>
> Our users may hold any beliefs they do - be it about religion or even having strong opinions about gender themselves. But if you go out of your way to point out your disagreement about the pronouns God gave you, you aren't behaving in a way we want here - just as people pointing out how wrong they think your gender identity is aren't behaving in a way we want here. Do not be rude to other people.

> #### 4. I find it really distressing to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong. Is there really no alternative?
>
> You can often avoid using pronouns altogether. It's actually pretty rare to need third-person pronouns at all on most Stack Exchange sites. But conspicuously avoiding using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others is a way of refusing to recognize God's sovereignty, and that is discriminatory against His true followers. Please don’t do that.

> #### 6. Are you saying that it's blasphemy to use the pronouns someone asks for?
>
> We’re not labeling people. Everybody makes mistakes. It’s important to note that for people who love God the impact of a refusal to use His pronouns is often the same whether the refuser is a ‘blasphemer’ or not. It is invalidating and hurtful. Through policies like this, we aim to help all Stack Exchange users avoid offending others.

> #### M2. I'm a moderator for a site on gender identity. I often have to refer to other users, I can't choose which ones I have to refer to, and often it isn't feasible to avoid pronouns. I would be more comfortable using the pronouns my users have asked me to use. So do I really have to use pronouns I find uncomfortable?
>
> Yes. As a moderator, you're held to a higher standard and are expected to set a positive example for your community. Using incorrect pronouns or conspicuously avoiding using pronouns is disrespectful. Telling them you refuse to use God's pronouns is harmful. If you think you will find using pronouns as God has stated difficult, please try. Most moderators won’t have to address this frequently. If you need help or have questions, contact the CM team for guidance. After that, if you cannot in good conscience follow it, reach out so we can find a replacement for you.

---

Of course there isn't an exact parallel for every word and phrase used in the FAQ, so some liberties were taken. That isn't the point.  It should be clear that by declaring so many things as fact that trans, intersex, and nonbinary people disagree with and implying that even quiet disagreement is a negative example that only meets a lower standard, the hypothetical FAQ is likely to offend and alienate them, and the claim in question 3 that they are being treated with respect rings hollow.

It doesn't have to be that way. Often the best way for people who disagree on an issue they feel strongly about to show respect for each other is to meet halfway. There is no need for the FAQ to state things so strongly in order to achieve its goals, and is more likely to not fall on deaf ears if it respects people with different beliefs.

---

### Example non-disrespectful answers

Here are some more respectful answers<sup>2</sup>, this time to the questions in the actual FAQ:

> #### 1. What's this business about "pronouns"?
>
> It would be rude to refer to a man as "she" or a woman as "he". Some people <del>are neither</del> **don't consider themselves either** men or women and might, for instance, ask to be referred to as "they". When someone indicates what pronouns should be used to refer to them,  please use the pronouns they state as you would others.

> #### 4. What was that about being neither men nor women?
>
> Some people <del>are neither</del> **consider themselves not to be either** men or women. The usual term for such people is "non-binary" and they’re often included in the term “transgender”. Just as you wouldn't want to be referred to with a pronoun that <del>doesn't fit</del> you **don't like**, neither do they.

> #### 3. My religion tells me that people can't change their gender. Aren't you treating me with disrespect in the name of treating others with respect?
>
> <del>Our users may hold any beliefs they do - be it about gender or even having strong opinions about religions themselves.</del> **You are welcome to believe anything you like about people's gender, just as they are welcome to believe anything they like about your religion.** But if you go out of your way to point out your disagreement about their gender, you aren't behaving in a way we want here - just as people pointing out how wrong they think your religion is aren't behaving in a way we want here. Do not be rude to other people.

> #### 4. I find it really distressing to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong. Is there really no alternative?
>
> You can often avoid using pronouns altogether. It's actually pretty rare to need third-person pronouns at all on most Stack Exchange sites. But conspicuously avoiding using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others <del>is a way of refusing to recognize their identity, and that is discriminatory</del> **will likely make them feel rejected and excluded.** Please don’t do that.

> #### 6. Are you saying that it's bigotry not to use the pronouns someone asks for?
>
> **No.** We’re not labeling people. <del>Everybody makes mistakes.</del> **Sometimes bigots deliberately use pronouns other than one ones people ask for, which is why it's mentioned in the "No bigotry" section of the Code of Conduct, but not everyone who is uncomfortable about some people's pronouns is a bigot.** It’s important to note that for trans people the impact of a refusal to use their pronouns is often the same whether the refuser is a ‘bigot’ or not. It is invalidating and hurtful. Through policies like this, we aim to help all Stack Exchange users avoid offending others.

> #### M2. I'm a moderator. I often have to refer to other users, I can't choose which ones I have to refer to, and often it isn't feasible to avoid pronouns. So do I really have to use pronouns I find uncomfortable?
>
> <del>Yes.</del> As a moderator, you're held to a higher standard and are expected to set a positive example for your community. <del>Using incorrect pronouns or conspicuously avoiding using pronouns is disrespectful. Telling them you refuse to use their pronouns is rude.</del> **That means you are expected to follow the same rules as everyone else.** If you think you will find <del>using pronouns as stated</del> **that** difficult, please try. Most moderators won’t have to address this frequently. If you need help or have questions, contact the CM team for guidance. After that, if you cannot in good conscience follow it, reach out so we can find a replacement for you.

---

1: Yes, such people exist, and post on meta.
2: These should sound familiar.

Comment: While don't know if I'm a fan of starting an answer by deliberately riling up your readers, I actually like this new wording. I don't think it changes the function of any of these rules significantly, so if that is enough to make certain religious people feel more welcome and included here, I'd be in favor of it

Comment: The problem with this wording you're proposing is that it ultimately capitulates to the transphobic position. Trans women are women. Trans men are men. Trying to hedge around that with "some people **consider themselves to be**" instead frames it as though their identity is just a matter of personal opinion. In fact, this kind of wording was specifically called out by [Aza's repsonse to the proposed rewording of the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335242/404162), with those considerations having gone into this new revision.

Comment: The problem ultimately becomes that this proposed rewording places a greater primacy on the feelings of latently transphobic users than it does on the feelings of the transgender users whose identities are being invalidated by those same users, no matter how much we frame it as "meeting each side half-way".

Comment: This entire answer doesn't seem like an actual attempt to ask a question or for clarification about how to use pronouns on SE sites. I'm not understanding what the purpose of "meet[ing] halfway" on the FAQ would be. The policy is still the policy. Would those people who believe that calling people what they want to be called is a "personal insult to God" really feel any different about the rule if the FAQ uses the phrase "consider themselves?"

Comment: @onetothrowaway The purpose of "meeting halfway" is to *de-escalate conflict*. The proposed changes to the wording do not meaningfully change the actual effect of the CoC, but make it less likely for certain kinds of users to become upset and become more combative in their interactions. It's not "capitulating to the transphobic position", it's not taking a position at all while encouraging respectful communication.

Comment: The core of this issue is that there are those with certain views on gender identity, and those with certain religious beliefs, and these two worldviews are incompatible. These CoC changes are intended to ensure that the former group is not excluded or alienated, but the problem is that the current wording sounds very much like it's agreeing with the former group and telling the latter group that their views are incorrect and they can only participate if they don't let that show. I'm sure SE has no wish to exclude or alienate people based on their religion, but currently, they risk doing so.

Comment: What you're proposing is factually wrong though. Intersex people are scientifically neither man nor women and almost all of them are already born like that. They don't just "feel" like neither, they are, biologically.

Comment: @Legxis While that's true, there are also a great many people who are not genetically or anatomically intersex (ie. they were born with XY chromosomes and masculine anatomy, or XX chromosomes and feminine anatomy) who nevertheless assert a gender identity that is not that of their chromosomes or anatomy. It's this scenario that the proposed wording addresses. In my experience, even those who very strongly believe that gender is fixed and binary are more willing to concede some ambiguity for those with measurable genetic or anatomical discrepancies.

Comment: "not everyone who is uncomfortable about some people's pronouns is a bigot." Name one non-bigoted reason why someone wouldn't want to use another person's preferred pronouns.

Comment: @Legxis: You might have preferred an early draft of other-shoe question 3: "My personal anatomy tells me that some people are nonbinary. Aren't you treating me with disrespect in the name of treating others with respect?" I ended up changing it out of a desire to make the parallels to the real FAQ more straightforward.

Comment: `The FAQ in its current state contains language likely to offend or alienate people by stating that things they deeply believe are objectively, factually false.` An FAQ that states that people of all races are equal would offend or alienate strongly racist people that deeply believe that statement to be objectively, factually false, but that is absolutely not a reason to keep it out of the FAQ.

Comment: @EttinaKitten: I suggest, in the spirit of this answer, that you try putting yourself in someone else's shoes and discover for yourself some reasons.

Comment: @Beofett: SE doesn't tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on religion. They are understandably more tolerant of language likely to offend strongly racist people.

Comment: @rockwalrus True, and I'm not saying that religion and racism are equivalent, but in some cases it is impossible to make a welcoming environment for one group without risking alienating some portions of another group.  Especially when a subset of one group is offended by the ideals that are core to respecting the other group.

Comment: @Beofett: You will notice that I didn't use the word "opinion" in the proposal. The wordings I chose in this answer were intended to dodge the opinion/fact dichotomy entirely. I just read through the entire Wikipedia NPOV style guide and it appears that the wording passes, although "Some people state they are neither men nor women" would be _Wikipedia's_ preferred phrasing. Would that phrasing satisfy you?

Comment: @rockwalrus-stopharmingMonica Your claim is that because some religions teach transphobic things, SE should meet transphobes halfway and not affirm the existence of transpeople. However if you make this argument for religious transphobia and then claim racism is different, then you're ignoring the historical and present reality of religions that teach racism and sexism. I have a hard time believing that you're up in arms about those pieces of the no bigotry policy because some religious people might be offended.

Comment: @jgon My position is that the FAQ violates the CoC, as clearly evidenced by some of the highest upvoted answers. Either the CoC should be changed to be less inclusive, or the FAQ should be changed to follow the CoC.

Comment: @rockwalrus-stopharmingMonica Your proposed changes to the FAQ are to make it neutral on the question of whether trans people exist because some people might be made uncomfortable due to religiously motivated transphobia... That's hardly making the FAQ more inclusive. I don't even see where religion factors into this discussion at all. Your religion is your personal business, as with everything else on SE, unless it's on topic it shouldn't factor into your interactions here. Religious or other personal belief is not an excuse for poor behaviour.

Comment: @jgon The measurement of inclusivity is not how you treat people you like, but how you treat people you don't like. For example, calling everyone who disagrees with you a bigot regardless of their motivation is not inclusive. Just as it's disrespectful to question someone's gender identity, it's disrespectful to question someone's religious identity.  The only poor behavior anyone is seeking to excuse here is the FAQ deliberately using language they know is offensive and alienating based on religion.

Comment: Inspired by Beofett, I made an alternate [proposal that uses Wikipedia's phrasing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337543/628364).

Comment: @Catija, have you declined the first “Hypothetical disrespectful FAQ answers” or subsequent Example non-disrespectful answers as well?

Comment: Hullo. Religious person using neopronouns here. Using wrong pronouns is not a "view". Imagine someone inventing a nickname for you that you don't like. You tell that person that. Yet that person refuses and calls you by it and refuses to stop. That's what it is. Deliberately misgendering is deliberately causing discomfort to other people. And imagine having this nickname being used previously by your bullies and triggering trauma response. That's how some trans people feel.  That's not only causing discomfort but actually causes harm and may lead to depression and even suicide.

Answer (score 64):

> 7. Am I obligated to find opportunities to use pronouns?
>
> Not at all! If you don’t need to use pronouns to say something, that’s fine. We ask that you use pronouns as you would naturally. If you’d use them in a sentence, use them; if not, don’t. Problems arise when a person or group feels singled out by having pronouns used for other people but not for them. If you're writing normally and naturally and it comes out pronoun-less, then that's fine.

This is based on a false premise. My native language is Polish. There is nothing natural in my usage of pronouns in English sentences. Natural for me is to omit almost all pronouns as the verb clearly indicates (in Polish) which pronoun is meant. The same applies to Spanish speakers.

It can go even deeper - OK, I try to learn the rules of English and apply them and after some time some way of writing in English becomes more natural than other. But as writing in a foreign language is an effort for me, my natural way is to avoid more difficult situations. So if I know "she - her", I use it freely. But if I don't know "xe - what?" I will try to avoid using "xe". But it is against:

> But conspicuously avoiding using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others is a way of refusing to recognize their identity, and that is discriminatory. Please don’t do that.

Comment: Well put. Portuguese here, and that also is not a native concern.

Comment: Same in french (afaik)

Comment: European languages are just a tip of an iceberg. What about people from Japan? https://www.dummies.com/languages/japanese/how-to-refer-to-people-in-japanese/

Comment: I've been a member on Stack Exchange for about six and a half years now. With my hand on my  heart, only once did a person ever correct me in the comments section, and said they would like to be referred to as "they" ( I had used "he"). Once. It's not such a big deal, you don't have to feel afraid, and if you use the "singular they" it's easier. The pronoun "they" you're familiar with, right?

Comment: This is covered by "Does this mean that I will be in trouble if I ever get someone's pronouns wrong?" and "What if someone wants some nonstandard pronouns that I don't even know how to use?"

Comment: @Mari-LouA it never happens, but still the rule is there and still there are being people being sanctioned according to it (apperently it happened recently with a highly respected moderator).

Comment: @Raedwald the way that I read the answers to those questions is like 'you are allowed to make mistakes, but don't do it again'. It seems like Tadeusz Kopec desires to not having to comply with it at all, neither after a first correction.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus there is nothing about not willing to comply in my answer. I am complaining about anglo-centric point of view taken by quoted part and generally by last CoC change. I desire to have content-focused culture agnostic resource. And now there is a shift from "be polite, no matter which culture you come from" to "obey to our culture, no matter which culture you come from".

Comment: "Natural for me is to omit almost all pronouns” then it doesn’t seem like you’ll have a problem. Avoiding pronouns is only a problem if you *conspicuously* avoid them only "one group of people”. If you naturally omit pronouns, that’s always fine

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes, in Portuguese it is easy. All you do is wait for that person to say "thank you", then listen to whether they said *obrigadO* or *obrigadA*. ;-}

Comment: @TadeuzKopec Asian cultures are an interesting point. My wife is supposed to command 3 languages, is supposed to be native in two, and fluent in the three. The grammar structure in her primary language/dialect is (very) weak. She consistently fails grammar, failing simple concepts like mixing bring and take and mixing up gender in both English and Portuguese to the point of getting into my nerves. We have been living together for 8 years now, she has been here for 20 years

Comment: @TadeuszKopec I read it as "It is okay when you make a mistake once, but obey afterwards to our culture when you are being corrected" and your post sort of goes against this-type ("make one mistake, but not again") of sentence. The "you are allowed to make mistakes" sentences are sort of straw-man arguments. Now it seems like the CoC/FAQ is making a concession, but the issue is not so much about 'making mistakes'. The CoC/FAQ is making it appear as if not complying with this novel form of politeness in the English language is just 'a mistake' while the discrepancies go much deeper.

Comment: Okay. I'm Hungarian. Hungarian language lacks gender specific pronouns, and distinctions between genders are also rare (aside of the most common expressions, such as wife, mother, woman, etc.). To add "insult to injury", some of us have a strong religious/educational background (especially in a rural environment), which makes things worse. We must understand, that change takes time and effort (from both sides). Some changes take _decades_, even _centuries_ to happen, we should show a little bit of patience and not cry wolf the very first time something happens we don't like or agree with.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But the problem and (partial?) reason for this whole change is that *people are offended and upset and don't tell you*. So that's why this whole thing seems to be around. So how many people ran away from the site for us being "exclusive" and we never knew? So it may happen more often, people just either don't care or get offended and stay silent. Anecdotes don't provide any value and I would *assume* the people running the show would've had proper research to this. But I fear they didn't.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I don't really buy that the sense of exclusivity new users feel about SE is related to gender.  As others have said, gendered pronouns only come up in a minuscule fraction of posts.  I think new users are much more likely to feel unwelcome due to our relatively strict rules as to what constitutes good questions and answers, which I don't think we should change.

Comment: @tchrist - `... obrigadO or obrigadA`: and I've seen artificial constructs such as `niñ@` in Spain which are presumably intended to be gender-neutral.

Comment: @divibisan - It doesn't say this in the FAQ : "Avoiding pronouns is only a problem if you conspicuously avoid them only "one group of people”. **If you naturally omit pronouns, that’s always fine" - that's the only thing I need it to say, which it explicitly says otherwise** : "must use". Which says to me, 'Disregard how you were taught to use the English language.' - That's gonna be a *no* from me, dawg.

Comment: @Mazura What is unclear about the section quoted in this answer? It explicitly says: "If you don’t need to use pronouns to say something, that’s fine" and "If you're writing normally and naturally and it comes out pronoun-less, then that's fine". That seems pretty clear to me. Where's the confusion?

Comment: Nothing wrong, it's just not what the FAQ says. No? Or at least, that's not what the CoC says. I'd assume the CoC overrides the FAQ...

Comment: @Mazura I mean, it is? Look at [implementation, question 7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336365/388335). It specifically says that you don't have to use pronouns when you wouldn't otherwise, and says that the issue is that: "Problems arise when a person or group feels singled out"

Comment: @divibisan - It specifically says otherwise: "If someone requests that you use other pronouns and you immediately continue to use they/them for that person, we may point it out to you." - point what out, that I know how to English? ;)

Comment: @Mazura Ah, I see. The FAQ clarifies the CoC. The CoC says "Use stated pronouns (when known)". Some people wondered if that means that you have to use people pronouns, even if you wouldn't otherwise. The FAQ clarifies that, no, this is not the case: the CoC just asks that you don't refer to someone with a pronoun other than their requested one

Comment: @Mazura Yeah, if someone tells you that their pronouns are "he" and you keep using "they" after they've asked you to stop, then the mods will point that out under the good faith assumption that you're simply making a mistake and are not doing it to be rude

Comment: @divibisan - [Singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) is still a *generic* pronoun, even if it is now also a *gender* pronoun. I believe the onus should be on those who choose to use *gendered* pronouns, and that no one should be able to request that decidedly gendered pronouns be used. If I keep using *they* it'd be because, "The increased use of singular they may owe in part to an increasing desire for gender-neutral language."

Answer (score 51):

> **Am I obligated to find opportunities to use pronouns?**
>
> Not at all! If you don’t need to use pronouns to say something, that’s
>   fine. We ask that you use pronouns as you would naturally. If you’d
>   use them in a sentence, use them; if not, don’t. Problems arise when a
>   person or group feels singled out by having pronouns used for other
>   people but not for them. If you're writing normally and naturally and
>   it comes out pronoun-less, then that's fine.

This needs clarity. Say, I regularly use 'he'/'she' and even singular 'they' (in the all-encompassing sense) to a certain extent. I have personal reservations against using neo-pronouns ('xe', 'xir', etc.) and that has absolutely nothing to do with not respecting the individual or their identity (of course, the individual could argue that that choice is disrespectful in itself; at the same time I could argue that not granting me that choice is disrespectful to me and my beliefs).

If someone explicitly says that their neo-pronouns are 'xe'/'xir' and I consistently use [gender-neutral language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335038/437611) for that person in order to avoid misgendering them while at the same time not violating my personal reservations, would that be acceptable per the updated CoC or not? Note that that is exactly how I use pronouns *as I would naturally*. If someone complains that I'm not using 'xe'/'xir' for them (and am consistently using gender-neutral language instead), I hope you wouldn't analyze my entire posting history (or say last 30 days) to determine whether I use 'he'/'she' for other people and suspend me if yes? Or would you?

Comment: This question has already been answered in the FAQ. By stated policy, using pronouns for some people and not others would not be okay.

Comment: @Aza Thanks, so that's compelled speech no matter how we look at it. I'll avoid the site altogether now that it has been made clear, as using neopronouns is simply not acceptable to me at a personal level.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a firm decision. If that doesn't sit well with you... well, they do kind of say that it's an expectation.

Comment: @Aza It doesn't sit well with anyone who would like to maintain their rights to neutrality, silence, freedom of conscience, thought, religion, opinion, emotions, etc. If I forced you to say something that didn't align with your values, you'd share the sentiment. You would request that neutrality be sufficient. There is no other walk of life where these concepts are not sufficient.

Comment: @TheAnathema I'm just conveying what's in the FAQ.

Comment: In reality, the odds of any SE user encountering a post where: a) pronouns are known b) using said pronouns is necessary to write an answer c) the user is using neopronouns; is... vanishingly small. The new CoC is mostly about making a statement rather than trying to address a practical issue.

Comment: @Aza, it's alright. I'm at least glad that you were crystal clear about it, unlike the SE folks who've beating around the bush about this crux of the issue (IMO). :)

Comment: @user437611 No problem. SE doesn't have as much access to conciseness as I do; theirs is policy, I'm just a user.

Comment: @JonathanReez Small, but important. I support all non-binary people and wish them complete happiness and health. I believe that they deserve respect, dignity, and kindness. I also respect their gender identity. What I do not respect is StackExchange telling its users that merely being neutral is not sufficient, and that they must acknowledge it by using the pronouns - i.e. OP/username is bannable. This has been strawmanned into "Hey, can we call them stuff they don't like?" and this mischaracterization of people's moral compass is frankly insulting and why people left over it.

Comment: @TheAnathema based on [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/508266/cesar-m), never using any pronouns is acceptable. I've been an active user for many years and I can't recall the last time I've used a pronoun on a non-Meta site.

Comment: @194636 Yes, that's an option. Though I would absolutely hate it if I had to ignore certain users just because of their pronoun choice. It places me in an almost impossible position where the choice is either "do this" or "leave". [Mutual compromises](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336291/could-all-of-the-confusion-around-pronouns-have-been-avoided-if-instead-it-was/336296#336296) are apparently not an option. Doesn't look like a healthy society to me!

Comment: It is not compelled. Instead of using the speech SE would like you to use, you can avoid all third person singular pronouns or disengage with users that cause you distress.

Comment: @user437611 I believe mutual compromise is allowed. A user could list in their profile *my pronouns are xe/xir but if you object to using them, then use whatever pronouns you are comfortable with (or avoid them all together)*.

Comment: It isn't really more compelled speech than asking people to use 'he' and 'she' when appropriate. Many binary people would (also) be upset if they are referred to with singular-they.

Comment: @TheAnathema That's too bad, You made an excellent point.

Comment: @Blackshift re the singular they. If a user consistently uses they in all cases of using a pronoun then they should not have to change Agreed if they do not use they in general or if they know exactly the user then using they in only some cases would be objectionable

Comment: I'm so confused that this final version of the CoC seems to completely support Monica C's preferences: avoiding pronouns equally for all people where possible.

Answer (score 40):

## I don't like using *'they'* for singular and try to recast to avoid it wherever possible. If unavoidable, can we use 'one' instead?

I'm aware the two pronouns are not directly interchangeable & that 'they' has perfectly unambiguous meaning when used appropriately, for example, from comments:

> User123 has a problem. They ought to ask about it on Meta.

However, 'they' as a singular pronoun has a lot of room for misinterpretation. It can be clumsy and often sounds inaccurate.

> Asfgl decided they were going shopping. Bertim didn't want to go with them. They bought shoes.

Who did what? How many people went shopping? Who bought shoes?
*Yes, I'm aware this is a tortured and not particularly elegant construction.*

It would be far better recast to avoid pronouns entirely:

> Asfgl decided to go shopping. Bertim didn't want to go along. Asfgl bought shoes.

Similarly artificial construction, pronouns avoided. Done.

> But if there was no need to refer to any specific individual, then one ought to be free to use one's common sense in avoiding potentially confusing pronouns.

… as opposed to the truly horrible:

> But if there was no need to refer to any specific individual, then they ought to be free to use their common sense in avoiding potentially confusing pronouns.

Comment: Of course you can! Rephrasing the sentence to use "one" generally makes for clearer sentences and *better writing*, and is fully keeping with the intent of inclusivity  and respect. There's nothing "antiquated" about "one".

Comment: What Cody said is correct - Kate touches on examples of gender-neutral language on this [great answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335031/define-gender-neutral-language-coc-faq/335038#335038). This is about gender-neutral writing. On the other hand, there are people who have they/their as their personal pronouns, so when referring to them in the third person, please respect their stated pronouns as you would normally with he or she.

Comment: "_One"_ isn't antiquated so much as it just serves a different linguistic function.  For example, if you say that "_User123 has a problem.  They ought to ask about it on Meta._", then "_They_" is directly referencing "_User123_".  By contrast, if you say that "_User123 has a problem.  One ought to ask about problems on Meta._", then you're not really referring to "_User123_" as "_One_" so much as you're making a generalized statement about a hypothetical "_One_", with the strong implication that User123 ought to observe it.  (To be clear, this seems entirely reasonable.)

Comment: Perhaps I should just remove 'antiquated' from the header. I do feel it's a bit "Spitting Image, Queen of England" & it's not something I would normally use in conversation, though I'm comfortable using it in writing. I'm also aware that the purpose it serves is different to 'they' - in particular that it is a generalisation, rather than a specific single person.

Comment: @CesarM "so when referring to them in the third person, please respect their stated pronoun" you referred to Cody's comment but the post from Tetsujin contained more examples. Can you make the change from "Asfgl decided they were going shopping" to "Asfgl decided to go shopping" (a reason might be that it might make it more clear, but it would be a case of conspicuously omitting 'they' when Asfgl has preferred pronoun 'they/their'). Is omitting a pronoun 'they' when it becomes confusing due to the conflict with plural 'they' considered as a violation?

Comment: So it becomes confusing. Cody says "of course you can" but you say "no you can not when you need to respect preferred pronouns."

Comment: With a pronoun 'he' and 'she' one actually also avoids using them in cases when there are two males or two females. If Alice and Bob refer to he and she, then the sentence *"Alice and Bob went shopping. He bought shoes"* works and 'he' is not being avoided. But in the case *"Alice and Bob went shopping. They bought shoes"* (and one of Alice or Bob associates with 'they') one might consider to avoid using the pronoun 'they'. So this is not a case of using 'they' as normally for others pronouns 'he' and 'she'.

Comment: I find "one" tends to be a better alternative for "you" -- students write "when you're flunking a class,  you should..." when they mean "people in X situation, which is kinda like me, so I assume it's everyone maybe?"  So at the VERY least I advise them to switch it to "one" ("When one is flunking a class, one should...") but ideally change to a descriptive noun phrase that more accurately captures the key characteristics ("When a transfer student is flunking a class...").  Students can use plural ("When transfer students... they should" if their other teachers don't accept singular-they.

Comment: I admit, I find singular-they awkward for drafting, but I ALSO find plural you awkward, and write "y'all" if I mean multiple people ("Can one of y'all review...") and "all y'all" to mean everyone addressed ("can all of y'all give me reactions...").  But when I revise, I check to see if "he or she" (or "he" or "she") could be a "they,"  (or if my *audience* doesn't grok "singular-they", then pluralize the sentence),  and if "y'all" could be "you," and if "all y'all" can become "all of you, including you, Lex."  I don't do MEGA-proofreading here, but I try to scan for comprehensibility and tone

Comment: Note - I'm not saying singular-they is bad, it's just less-familiar to me (I'm Gen-X), and in my workplace, a government agency, not accepted in documentation.   I tend to use "Students" or "Users" instead of "Guys" as my gender-neutral collective term.  (My friends are called "Peoples" most often:  "peoples - any of y'all going to the [event]?" and "Hello, Writing Peoples" to start my podcast.)

Comment: @April - personally, not being from the US, I find *y'all* sends out some bizarre Beverly Hillbillies-type connotation. It's simply never used in speech in the UK, it's only ever heard on TV. I kind of get what it means, but it doesn't feel like a natural part of language, it seems a filler, an adjunct; similar to how some people put "like" in front of ideas that simply don't require it.

Comment: And since I'm from just-barely south of the Mason-Dixon line (Maryland, with some school in VA), y'all just feels so dang useful!  But definitely casual.   Yet it fills the linguistic gap we created when "you" subsumed "thou" (or is it the other way around?)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus That is *fine*, the CoC says that you should use pronouns as you would use them normally on sentences, meaning, if you'd put a he or she there, use other stated pronouns too. You don't have to do it all the time, and clarity is fine, but if you're talking about one person and it's not confusing, them don't conspiciously avoid it when there's no need. The biggest thing here is: don't *misgender* people intentionally.

Comment: @CesarM - & I'm happy with that. My post wasn't any kind of 'complaint' in any way, merely a 'hey, folks, we could use this as well'.

Comment: @cesarM this 'intentionally' might be needed to be specified more clearly in the FAQ. Currently it seems to me that If *I feel a need* to avoid using 'they' or a neopronoun and avoid their use (but not intentionally in order to misgender a person, or deny their gender) then this is not considered to be allowed. The issue with Monica also still has a lasting impact in understanding these explanations/FAQ. She got demodded but not for having no need to avoid a specific pronoun.

Comment: The pronoun "one" is the formal version of generic "you", which is informal. "How does one do X?" "How do you do X?" Obviously I'm not asking about you specifically, but any person in general. Note that the same word can have multiple meanings! "They" can be singular or plural. "One" can be a number or a pronoun, etc. Context can be used to make clear which one is meant, and sometimes there is insufficient context to be able to tell. It's up to all of us to communicate as clearly as possible, and to try to grasp the true intent when it's not as clear as it could be.

Comment: @GershomMaes you are confusing schizophrenia and Dissociative identity disorder.  Also "two-spirited" means that a person is of a nonbinary gender and doesn't mean that a person has two identities.

Answer (score 39):

In [But what about...? The edge cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336369/233944), emphasis mine:

> My **religion** tells me that people can't change their gender. Aren't you treating me with disrespect in the name of treating others with respect?
>   Our users may hold any beliefs they do - be it about gender or even having strong opinions about **religions** themselves. But if you go out of your way to point out your disagreement about their gender, you aren't behaving in a way we want here - just as people pointing out how wrong they think your **religion** is aren't behaving in a way we want here. Do not be rude to other people.

Can this be reworded to be more general? There are also non religious people that say that people can't change their gender. Also religious people with stance not based on their religion.

How about this:

> My **religion or world view** tells me that people can't change their gender. ...

Comment: This is an actually useful point - TERFs, for all their rhetoric sounds *exactly* like certain religious-right talking points of the same flavor, are not a religion.  To my knowledge, at least.  I would hope that they are unwelcome to use this platform as a platform for bigotry as much as anyone basing their objections to trans people existing in religion is.

Answer (score 32):

> But conspicuously avoiding using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others is a way of refusing to recognize their identity, and that is discriminatory. Please don’t do that.

Is one afforded a guarantee, going forward with the new Code of Conduct, that by changing one's writing style to be pronoun free it will be compliant with the new Code of Conduct?

More concretely, if the style of writing under the old CoC used pronouns for a group of people, and then the writing style under the new CoC avoids the use of pronouns, is it possible for this to be interpreted as conspicuously refusing to recognize someone's identity, and thus a violation of the new CoC?

> As Aza stated, this is very much one of the specific edge cases that need to be actually looked at when it happens. In essence, I would say if you stop using pronouns for everyone altogether and consistently do not, that's fine. Even if you did before. It'll become a new pattern in time, and that's okay. However, as it is a very specific case, it may vary from case to case, the above is the general thought on it. - Cesar M♦

Comment: This question is already answered by the FAQ: "If you don’t need to use pronouns to say something, that’s fine. We ask that you use pronouns as you would naturally. If you’d use them in a sentence, use them; if not, don’t. Problems arise when a person or group feels singled out by having pronouns used for other people but not for them. If you're writing normally and naturally and it comes out pronoun-less, then that's fine."

Comment: @Aza: Not really. Will a user's old writing style under the old CoC be held as a standard to judge someone's writing style under the new CoC?

Comment: @jxh Yeah, I still stand by my prior statement. This requires human judgement and a case example in order to evaluate.

Comment: As Aza stated, this is very much one of the specific edge cases that need to be actually looked at when it happens. In essence, I would say if you stop using pronouns for everyone altogether and consistently don't, that's fine. Even if you did before. It'll become a new pattern in time, and that's okay. However, as it is a very specific case, it may vary from case to case, the above is the *general* thought on it.

Comment: @CesarM so even if we speak the way you demand, we might still get a ban? Is that what you mean? English isn't my mother tongue. If so what are the rules for banning someone that changed the way he talks and stopped using pronouns _completely_. Please provide examples.

Answer (score 32):

The FAQ is punctuated inconsistently. 
There are many sentences like

> It would be rude to refer to a man as "she" or a woman as "he".

where words that are *referenced* are quoted.
But then there are also a few like

> May I use they/them by default?

where words that should be quoted are not.

<sup>I suggested [an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/68144) to fix this, but it was rejected.</sup>

Comment: +1 for a sane voice for grammar in this horrible grammapocalypse.

Answer (score 32):

This actually sounds suspiciously like what Monica was asking to be allowed to do. That being said, would Monica have been de-modded under this version of the Code of Conduct? If so, which part of this did she violate? If not, are there plans to reinstate her?

Answer (score 31):

> **8. Isn't all this causing lots of inconvenience to everyone for the sake of a minority?**
>
> No. One thing is required of you: that when someone states their
>   pronouns you take notice and respect their request. We also recommend
>   that you don't make assumptions about people's gender and that you
>   prefer gender-neutral language when unsure. Using gender-neutral
>   language instead of default masculine makes the content here inclusive
>   of everyone, including both female and trans users.

Many non-English speakers have learned that *he* is a gender neutral pronoun. Many have similar rules in their native languages.

Old habits die hard. (For instance, I still use WordStar shortcuts while coding.)

This requirement to avoid *he* as a gender neutral pronoun, if *assume good intent* is not applied, can cause a lot of trouble for such people.

---

Point 3. in [What's this all about? - Implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336365/313443) seems to allow (or at least it is not considered a violation) using *he* as a gender neutral term, as long as you use stated pronouns once they’re made known.

Comment: Many native English speakers too. Probably most of them over the age of 60, and a non-trivial proportion over 30.

Comment: I'd say this was covered by "Does this mean that I will be in trouble if I ever get someone's pronouns wrong?", but specifically by "Is it a CoC violation if I use "he" or any other pronoun as a neutral one?"

Comment: I've got the impression that there are moderator tools to let other mods know if/how often an user's been told about the pronouns.

Comment: The FAQ already states that gender-neutral he is fine, as long as you change it when someone states their pronouns and it isn't "he".

Answer (score 30):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

From the answer [But what about...? The edge cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336369/346823), question 1:

> Some of our sites may have topics where gender is part of the subject of the site and may be a valid question for those experts. When answering these questions, it is important that answers are not conveying the author's opinions but reporting an objective answer to the question. Since these objective answers are at odds with the Code of Conduct, please take special care and frame them respectfully and politely [...]

This is a bit unclear. I think this is what it's trying to say (**bold** for insertions, *italics* for re-arranged phrases):

> Some of our sites may have topics where gender is part of the subject <strike>of the site</strike> and may be a valid question for <strike>those</strike> **the** experts **on that site**. When answering these questions, it is important that answers *report an <strike>objective</strike> **evidence-based** answer to the question* and *avoid conveying the author's opinions* **on the subject**. Since these <strike>objective</strike> **evidence-based** answers <strike>are</strike> **may be** at odds with the Code of Conduct, please take special care and frame them respectfully and politely [...]

Comment: The intent is a guide for the people writing the answers, that they should take care in *how they write* the answer. This rewrite does not seem to be conveying the same point. I agree with some of these changes, to the first and last sentences but the "when answering[...]" change seems to be changing the intent. Maybe I'm misunderstanding? If I can help explain better what I'm hoping to convey, let me know. :)

Comment: My interpretation of that sentence is that the goal is to avoid editorializing. If a question touches on gender, you can write an objective answer to it, but you shouldn’t stick in your personal opinions. Which seems like the goal for all answers on the site, IMO. Is that right?

Comment: @Catija ah yes that makes more sense. I think it's really just the order then that makes it confusing -- see my edit.

Comment: @divibisan Yes, exactly! I keep thinking of it like a good reporter who reports on the subject but we generally shouldn't know what that reporter's feelings about the subject are.  The rewrite looks much better to me. Thanks!

Comment: +1 thanks for making these changes, CMs, and I now approve of the faq - but yeah I struggled to understand this specific entry too.  Seems like it gets into the whole Good Subjective, Bad Subjective thing, and I’m not sure how this would gel with e.g. answers on Parenting.  Consider striking or significantly retooling this one part.

Comment: @mxyzplk As a former mod on Interpersonal Skills, I'm well aware of the concept. But having a site where opinions are more relaxed doesn't mean you can spew whatever you want. Answers on these sites should still *generally* be supported with... something other than just "this is what I think" and I have great trust of the mods on these sites to be able to handle this because they already are - they delete unsubstantiated stuff all the time, particularly when it's harmful to others.

Comment: I’m not saying “you don’t know that”, I am saying “the paragraph above does not reflect that.”

Comment: @mxyzplk I mean, asking us to remove it kinda implies that... What's great about LShaver's answer is that he suggests an improvement. Perhaps you have a suggestion for how this could be better conveyed?

Comment: Yeah, don’t say “objective” because those exact sites thrive on Good Subjective and not objective answers, so it will cause confusion about having to answer gender questions to an entirely different standard.  Crib your favorite turn of phrase from the GS/BS blog post to describe the support an answer needs.  Or you could just say “these answers should be backed up with evidence (link: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: @Catija to mxyzplk's point, I think you could replace the two occurrences of "objective" with "evidence-based." This allows different sites to have different standards for what constitutes evidence.

Comment: That makes sense, LShaver. Thanks. @mxyzplk edited based on his suggestion. :)

Answer (score 29):

> Edit: This has already been answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335708/under-what-circumstances-will-stack-exchange-inc-share-private-sensitive-infor/335749#335749)

One question that I've seen a fair bit recently is:

If a user gets this wrong, will the company publicly slander them to news organisations?

To me that's the most terrifying part of this mess.

Comment: Then this concern is resolved already via [stated policy changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335749/388335).

Comment: This is the first item on [Implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336365/232439): "**1. Does this mean that I will be in trouble if I ever get someone's pronouns wrong?** No. It's fine to make an honest mistake. But once you are directly informed of what someone wants, please act accordingly."

Comment: There is now an official policy of “No Comment”. So the answer is: No, they will not talk about you with the press. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335749/388335

Comment: @divibisan Thank you, I had not seen that post.

Comment: Oh yeah?  And has Monica been reinstated with public apologies in the same press she's been vilified in?

Comment: That's the thing. They didn't follow their own rules with Monica, and refuse to go back and fix that, so why should we assume they'll follow their own rules in other situations? It seems that, if the situation gets sufficiently emotionally charged, they're willing to break their own rules. That is the shadow that all of this otherwise good change looms under. People don't trust the organization because they won't make amends, which means their apology was false. Rules exist to restrict those in authority, to prevent misuse of power.

Answer (score 29):

Thank you for adding more clarification to the new FAQ and CoC. I'm posting this with as much good faith and respect as I can muster, and as you read it, please keep an open mind. I do not hate people. Anybody. I welcome you with open arms!

I am very concerned that this still contains text based on "We are setting the social standards here, so if you have religious, or non-aggressive disagreements then SO is not for you.

This would be fine, if we stuck to simply Q&A but SO has grown beyond this.

> In most contexts, your opinions about gender are off-topic.

I don't like how this is written, with the context of the answers after it pertaining to free speech, it comes off as compelled speech (if you disagree, whatever, basically). I can look past this, because in an ideal world you're right, this won't be an issue because being nice is just that.

> please be aware that many things you might want to say may be extremely distressing to some readers, and try to minimize that distress.

This needs to be worded better. My opposing point of view *cannot* be silenced on the grounds of it being distressing if it's not threatening, promoting hate or violence etc. As somebody who has opinions, I can't be expected to quell them (except to type them up politely, and as eloquently as I can)

These are small potatoes to my main point here:

What do we do about "gendered" statements that are incredibly common?

Yes, I am talking about "dude" (when not pointed directly at somebody). Yes, I am talking about "man" and "boy". What should I expect to hear back when I comment "Oh man, I didn't think about using X" or "Boy, this is going to cause an entire ..."

Am I expected to change the way I speak or get flagged?

As I stated in my answer on the now deleted old FAQ question: my right to not participate in your life is not harming you. My right to disagree with you does not mean I hate you, or disrespect you. Calling me a bigot, or a transphobe because I am not in direct alignment with you is not ok.

I know that might sound harsh, or come off as non-support, but you need to know that I love all of you equally, despite me sometimes opposing your views. We can all be heard in a productive manner.

> The expectation on how to answer a question and what is/isn't in scope on our sites is not changing, on our sites Q&A you have always had to state how things are viewed on a field backed up by references, not your personal thoughts. As using genderized words, @divibisan said it, you can continue to do so, albeit not recommended. Adjust if someone states differently for you. - Cesar M♦

Comment: Is there a reason to think that gendered statement will be an issue? The CoC says use "Use stated pronouns” (which only applies to pronouns) and "Prefer gender-neutral language”, which is a request, not a demand. The FAQ even says that defaulting to gender-neutral “he” is fine, as long as you change if requested.

Comment: The expectation on how to answer a question and what is/isn't in scope on our sites is not changing, you have always had to state how things are viewed on a field backed up by references, not your personal thoughts on main Q&A. As using genderized words, @divibisan said it, you can continue to do so, albeit not recommended. Adjust if someone states differently for you.

Comment: @CesarM can we make it more clear on the CoC that it mostly is applying to SO? I was under the impression that it was for all networks (including meta) so a directly line there would help clarify things

Comment: It is applying to all of them @SterlingArcher. Essentially, the intentional differential treatment of someone after they have pointed out an easily correctable mistake is what the CoC outlines as wrong (in my interpretation). Your display name is a character name from a popular TV show, and as such I wouldn't want to make any assumptions about you if I were referring to you in the third person. If I did end up making an assumption (and you corrected me on it), I would change how I referred to you for the sole reason that *I made the wrong assumption*. Why shouldn't that apply to all SE sites?

Comment: @SterlingArcher There seems to be one free pass per user per question without being flagged, so I would simply change the way you type for that one rare instance in which a user does actually correct you. It probably won't happen often, as people usually endeavour to keep comments on-topic and concise; users should never correct you without including information that's also relevant to the question/answer/comments, so it will just make their comments longer.

Comment: I just want to make it clear I have no issue using clear pronouns. I already use OP more dominantly so nbd there. I just want to make sure that I’m safe because I have different opinions on social situations, and that it’s not interpreted as hate or bigotry :)

Comment: It's not compelled speech to be told that you can't say something. You can call it a restriction on free speech, but free speech is inherently restricted in any forum that has rules. "Be Nice" is already a restriction on free speech. The rules on what is on topic for a particular SE is already a restriction on free speech. Not having long running chats in the comments is a restriction on free speech, even. The idea that it is better to remain silent than to break the rules is always the case, as well. It's better to remain silent than to be rude, ask the wrong question, etc.

Comment: That said, it seems unlikely to me that anyone could misunderstand "Oh, man" to be talking about a male human. It is merely a minced oath, where "God" was replaced with "man." However, calling someone "man," "dude," etc can easily be seen as assuming they are male, and there are non-gendered equivalents which would be better. "Bud," "mate," "chum," "my friend," etc. are all clearly gender neutral, and convey a similar tone to "dude" or "man."

Comment: Finally, to address a specific line in your post: "My opposing point of view cannot be silenced on the grounds of it being distressing if it's not threatening, promoting hate or violence etc." This isn't correct, and would make any politeness or civility policies possible. Being polite, nice, civil, etc inherently requires one to avoid unnecessarily causing distress to others. This isn't just on websites: you job probably has such rules. Your friends probably have such as a rule unofficially--as someone who deliberately distresses people is labeled an "asshole" and loses friends.

Comment: @trlkly: This is a rather weak understanding of social interaction. In all functional societies, an expectation of politeness is universally predicated on the recipient moderating their own behavior and conducting themselves in a socially acceptable and agreeable manner. Failure to do so demonstrates a disregard for the integrity of the group and naturally invites social censure. This is precisely why such enforcement attempts always fail, because demanding that the rest of the group accepts your personal values under threat of sanction is, ipso facto, anti-social behavior.

Comment: Re *"non-aggressive disagreements"* (near *"So if you have religious, or non-aggressive disagreements then SO is not for you."*): Don't you mean ***"aggressive disagreements"*** (the opposite of *"non-aggressive disagreements"*) (or the quote is wrong)? It would not make sense that the site ***is for them*** if they have the opposite, *aggressive disagreements*.

Comment: @CesarM, please remove your text from the answer. It’s your comment, and it is not endorsed by the author of the answer.

Comment: Using wrong pronouns is not a "view". Imagine someone inventing a nickname for you that you don't like. You tell that person that. Yet that person refuses and calls you by it and refuses to stop. That's what it is. Deliberately misgendering is deliberately causing discomfort to other people. And imagine having this nickname being used previously by your bullies and triggering trauma response. That's how some trans people feel. That's not only causing discomfort but actually causes harm and may lead to depression and even suicide. Deliberate misgendering is thus dangerous.

Answer (score 26):

[Implementation details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336365/299342) are still uncomfortably vague, especially for moderators. The FAQ says (emphasis added):

> #### 6. What if someone wants some nonstandard pronouns that I don't even know how to use?
>
> Then **just do your best. Again, honest mistakes are fine.** If you are
>   directly corrected, adjust moving forward. If you're not sure how to
>   form that pronoun, you may find guidance here. If you're struggling,
>   that's common. It can take a little effort but it's appreciated.
>
> #### 8. What if someone wants to be referred to as "the Great and Mighty One" or by an obscenity or something?
>
> If something is **obviously unreasonable and seems to be requested
>   unkindly**, please feel free to flag for moderator attention. **Pronouns
>   are a fairly well defined thing in language** and styles/nouns/titles
>   (Your Majesty) are generally poor substitutes for them. Note that **"it
>   sounds silly to me" is not sufficient grounds to think something is
>   obviously unreasonable**. If you and they can't agree, ask a moderator
>   (or, if a moderator is one of the parties to the dispute, the
>   Community Team) as you would in other cases of dispute. The Community
>   Team is also available to help guide moderators upon request.
>   Offensive/trolling “pronouns” (e.g.“attack helicopter”) should be
>   flagged.
>
> #### 12. There are still edge cases that aren't clear to me.
>
> There always will be. **Use your common sense**, be nice, presume good
>   faith but be prepared to revise that assumption in the face of the
>   evidence, and you are unlikely to go too far wrong.

The FAQ is basically telling us to use our judgment and common sense, and that mistakes are okay. That would be fine under the old "be nice" policy and when the community had good rapport with the company, but **the problem is that you have created a climate of fear**: a [respected moderator was summarily removed and her name was publicly dragged through the mud for holding the same position that she posted in the moderator Team back in January](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334271/299342) and which no SE employee said was against the CoC at the time. It was only later when the company's *interpretation* of the CoC changed that she was accused of ["repeatedly violating our existing Code of Conduct"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/299342). This climate of fear is evident from all the FAQ questions about "I'm worried I may get banned", "Am I going to get in trouble...?", etc.

**In this climate of fear the CoC/FAQ needs clear, objective criteria rather than vague assurances to just "do your best".**

The FAQ claims that "[p]ronouns are a fairly well defined thing in language", but while the *purpose* of pronouns is well defined the criteria for what constitutes a reasonable request for a pronoun is not. Without such well defined criteria you have created hell for well meaning users (especially moderators) and heaven for trolls who want to test the limits of reasonable/unreasonable.

The FAQ also tells us to "use your common sense". Now, my common sense tells me that I should be fine if I followed the guidance of the highest voted answer in the moderator Team of the discussion on the use of pronouns (which says not to use incorrect pronouns but that we don't need to use a specific pronoun) and which no SE employee said was a violation of the CoC. Apparently, however, the common sense of the majority of the moderators who voted on that discussion does not have much in common with SE the company since a respected moderator was removed for following that guidance.

I'm not sure what the solution to this problem is. Perhaps we could have a pre-defined list of recognized pronouns which are deemed always "reasonable", and SE can guarantee that users (and especially moderators) are free to use their judgment to decide if any pronoun not in that list is reasonable without fear of any punishment by SE. Users who want to use pronouns not in that list can petition to have their pronouns added to it. That would make it much easier to objectively determine the reasonableness of the pronoun request. However, I suspect this may not be acceptable to SE since users whose pronouns are not on the list would argue that they're still excluded and marginalized.

With this vague guidance and climate of fear I'm uncomfortable using my judgment in acting as a moderator for any but the most obviously reasonable or obviously unreasonable pronoun requests, lest I be summarily removed and publicly smeared for making the wrong call(s). For example, which of the below words are reasonable pronouns and which constitute unreasonable trolling? (I've actually seen some of these in the wild since the new CoC was released.):

- from (conflicts with an actual, non-pronoun word)
- let (also conflicts with an actual, non-pronoun word)
- supercalifragilisticexpialidocious (is this excessively long? when -- if ever -- is a word too long to be a pronoun?)
- grimble
- vlkivczq (very difficult to spell and pronounce)

**Can we get some more specific guidance on what constitutes a reasonable pronoun?** Unless we can get more specific guidance I see no option but to forward all but the most obvious pronoun flags to the CMs so that I don't make the wrong call.

Comment: Even if the company implements your suggestion, couldn't they just ignore it and fire you anyway? It seems to me the only way to allay such fears is to rehire Monica, and that can only happen if she agrees to abide by the CoC-- and wants to be rehired.

Comment: Basically the FAQ is almost the same content as before, and only in a less aggresive and less negative wording. It is nice to see this work being done on that FAQ, but when it basically remains the same then it seems to be more like a distraction from the distrust in the actions of StackExchange. It is sad that these gender issues turn out to be the battle field. The current discontent among the contributors to SE is not so much about gender (which has become a collateral damage), but much more about how it is being handled (strange apologies, but in no way is the issue made transparent).

Comment: @DoctorDestructo I don't see SE reinstating Monica. The message I got from SE's actions is that they *want* a climate of fear, though they did not anticipate and do not desire moderator resignations and strikes. But it seems clear to me that they absolutely want us to fear the threat of punishment, perhaps as a way to signal support for the people the new CoC is designed to help.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I have yet to see an actual apology from SE. Sara Chipps' was a total non-apology, and the CTO's post was promising but is ringing hollow.

Comment: @Null We're always happy to help... you can either ping us and ask in the TL (some of the other mods may have some input, too) or ping us in your mod room or raise a CM contact about it. We're learning, too, so we may not have all the answers immediately. There's many lists of the more widely-used neopronouns out there and there's already a partial guide on the Mod Team if you're using it.

Answer (score 25):

I am new to this topic in general (about genders and pronouns) and it's all very confusing.

1. Can I write to any person using "you"? For example, will the comment: *"You have XY problem, do this instead"* be appropriate to anyone? The Code of Conduct and the FAQ repeatedly simply says "pronouns", but it seems to mean only "third-person pronouns" (he/she/it and neopronouns instead of those pronouns).
2. Is it OK to refer person as "OP" (original poster) or use `@nickname`? For example, *"OP didn't mean that, but this."*?

I am asking, because if the above works then I don't need to change anything, all my previous and future posts will be appropriate.

But will those work in all cases? What are the exceptions? What am I missing​?

> Both these options are okay. - CesarM♦

Comment: Both these options remain entirely acceptable. You're good.

Comment: Okay?  Only okay? What's wrong with them that they're not perfect?

Comment: Which OP are you talking about when you reply to a comment about a comment on an answer to a question that is about another question? Not perfect. *You* is a second-person pronoun, so allowing usage of it does not resolve issues with using third-person pronouns. Not perfect. But seriously, why do you need something to be perfect, when the point is that it works? the latter being defined by appropriateness and effectiveness. @GeorgeM

Comment: I've encountered a person online who wished to be addressed in the second person as "zhou", not "you". This person additionally claimed to be deeply upset and hurt, as if by violence, by anyone who didn't comply with this wish. Maybe an extreme edge-case, but why not just include second-person pronouns under the new CoC as well, just in case?

Comment: @GershomMaes We don't specify third person anywhere, I don't think? It's extremely rare but there are people who have alternative first and second person pronouns.

Comment: The CoC seems to dismiss alternative second-person pronouns, since it constantly refers to 3rd person pronouns. If you want to prevent "violence" against at minimum this one person, you'd consider an explicit addendum concerning second-person pronouns. You'd also consider explicitly banning the use of "one", as there are those who would claim it is violent towards schizophrenic and "non-singular-identifying" people. Do you want to commit violence against schizophrenics? Please disallow the use of "one" in reference to people, there's apparently no downside.

Comment: @Catija, can you add this clarification in the main FAQ? I am sure there will be many people who are new to the topic about genders and pronouns and  it will be very confusing for them as well. To find this answer will be even harder.

Answer (score 23):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> **U4. If someone puts their pronouns into a question they're asking, should we leave that in or edit it out as noise?**
>   Add a comment noting what they said and suggesting that **they could add it to their profile** and comment on the question/answer next time.

(Emphasis mine)

May this be a left-over from what used to be in the answer to "10. I want to let people know what my pronouns are..."? The original FAQ said that you can put your pronouns in your profile to let people know of them, and that wording is removed now.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for noticing. We cannot legally recommend that.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot legally recommend that, @Cesar? What are the legal concerns with recommending that someone add personal information to their profile?

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not the best to explain it here, but as far as *I* know it relates to data collection/processing and the threat of miss uses.

Comment: I'm confused... How, then, would it be acceptable to recommend that people include this information in a post or comment? The profile seems like a perfect place to put personally identifying information, *if the person so chooses* (that's why it's a recommendation, after all; the default option is not to share). @Cesar

Comment: We're not recommending in posts either, in fact, under the new FAQ you're welcome to delete those as noise (Something the community requested).

Comment: @CodyGray you *can* put them in your profile if you wish, but SE cannot *recommend* it for legal reasons. So it's ok to put pronouns in your profile, but you do it at your own risk - basically it's a CYA thing.

Comment: @CodyGray The reason may well be related to what was mentioned in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335785/). Better if malicious actors aren't able to *automatically* scrape and identify targets of their ire

Comment: @Cesar FAQ 10 currently says “ How (and whether) you identify your pronouns is up to you.” I think adding a neutral statement like “some users choose to add their pronouns to their profile” provides useful information to any user that looks up this specific question in the FAQ, without in any way compromising the company.

Comment: @CesarM: I don't really understand. What legal ramifications is a user likely to encounter by having their pronouns in their profile and are we going to get some official guidance on where users _can_ best communicate their pronouns should they desire?

Comment: @CBBailey Legal ramifications are not for the user, but for SE. Putting pronouns into your profile makes them publically scrapable. If extremists then target you (online or IRL) because of pronouns they got from your profile, SE could get into trouble for suggesting you put them there. Note that people have already reported extremists posting (somewhere online) psuedo-code along the lines of "scrape SE profiles for transgender pronouns; target such people for torture/murder."

Comment: @ReinstateMonica, to be safe, SE should recommend not put  pronouns in user profiles nor in questions/answers/comments. It also would avoid a lot of recent conflicts/discussions.

Answer (score 23):

> ## Question: May a moderator openly disagree with the policy even while enforcing it fully?

The [FAQ says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336367/627282): "As a moderator, you're held to a higher standard and are expected to set a positive example for your community." Clearly there are users of SE who disagree with various parts of this policy and have respectfully voiced their opinions here on Meta. They have not been sanctioned as far as I can tell. Is a moderator held to a higher standard in this regard? **Assume the moderator has agreed to fully enforce the Code of Conduct despite the disagreements.**

For example, can a moderator publicly disagree with the policy, calling it silly, coercive, grammatically prescriptive, intolerant, etc. (to mention some critiques I've seen thrown around)? Can a moderator tell an offending user that while that moderator doesn't personally think a particular violation was rude in any way, it is still not allowed per site rules? Can a moderator openly announce that only user-flagged offenses will be dealt with and that nothing will be actively sought out by the mod team?

(I suspect, yes, that's all fine so long as the moderator has agreed to fully enforce the CoC despite the disagreements. But I want SE to officially say so, lest some moderator, even a very respected moderator, get in trouble accidentally by unknowingly stepping over some internal SE line of allowed opinions.)

Comment: @Unionhawk The entire point of rules more specific than "be nice" is to try to prevent moderators from simply acting based on their own opinions, which differ from moderator to moderator. If moderators were free not to enforce any specific rule with which they personally disagree, then flag handling would be highly dependent on which moderator happened to see the flag first. (There's always going to be an unavoidable aspect of that, but letting moderators ignore rules they don't like would make it far worse.)

Comment: @KyleStrand Do you think it is appropriate for a mod to tell a user they weren't being rude but rules are rules, or do you think instead that it would be more appropriate to just kind of keep that to themselves

Comment: @Unionhawk I think both can be appropriate depending on the situation. Mods are people not computers and they can have thoughts and opinions and can adapt to various circumstances and balance different values with nuance. There's a reason we have human beings handle many of these things. Computers don't do nuance so well.

Comment: Seeing as Monica was fired for basically trying to work out how to reconcile her position on singular they with the CoC changes in a private moderator chat, I am assuming that if I express my opinion about neopronouns too forcefully in public that would be cause for my removal. There are people that believe that simply expressing that you are going to avoid using pronouns because you don't agree with using certain pronouns is a serious violation of the CoC that should be punished. I would not assume anyone is free to express disagreement with the pronoun policy without consequences.

Comment: @ColleenV Exactly. There is no reason to "suspect yes" as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 22):

> #### 6. What if someone wants some nonstandard pronouns that I don't even know how to use?
>
> Then just do your best. Again, honest mistakes are fine. If you are directly corrected, adjust moving forward. If you're not sure how to form that pronoun, you may find guidance [here](https://lgbta.wikia.org/wiki/Neopronouns). If you're struggling, that's common. It can take a little effort but it's appreciated.

What exactly is required from me by "do your best"?

Let's take the sentence "as was stated by OP in *his* question" for example, this is what I would normally write for an OP of an unknown gender.

If it's made known to me that OP's pronouns are "ey/em" am I required to look [here](https://lgbta.wikia.org/wiki/Neopronouns), find out that "eir" or "eirs" should be used instead of "his" and then ask a question on ELL about which one should I use(I don't know what is the difference between Pronominal possessive and Predicative possessive, "his" would work in both examples given for "eir" and "eirs")?

That would be me doing my best.

Comment: You may ask them how to use it, you may do research, you may ask on another site, those are all options. You certainly don't have to do all of them. Do your best at an attempt, and if you make an honest mistake at it, that's fine too.

Comment: @CesarM I see. Then unfortunately I will have to continue not participating on SO or ignore people who want me to use neopronouns. The requirement to do research about neopronouns is unreasonable to me. If I will make a mistake it will not be an honest one, it will be caused by lack of research.

Comment: Again, let me reinstate: You're not *obligated* to do research, nor you will get punished for it. It's okay if you make a mistake once, someone will probably tell you the correct way of doing so, and you can learn and go from there. This isn't a draconian rule that you must get it right the first time.

Comment: You could also say 'As was stated by the OP in **the** question"... there's no need for a pronoun there in most cases.

Comment: @CesarM Okay. What you're saying now sounds reasonable. I still have a problem with the wording. Making a mistake would not be me "doing my best"

Comment: @Catija But then I would change my writing style because of stated pronouns and if I understand correctly violate the CoC.

Comment: So... you can change it generally and always write this way from this point forward and that’s just fine... I’m sure that many have taken the opportunity to write in a more gender neutral way. That’s good.

Comment: @Catija But.. I don't want to... that's not how I normally write, I have my own style that comes natural to me and I'm interested in just using it in most cases and concentrate on writing a good answer from a technical point of view. Can I use pronouns as I would normally and switch to gender neutral language when using them requires an unreasonable(IMO) amount of effort?

Comment: I think this is covered by "Does this mean that I will be in trouble if I ever get someone's pronouns wrong?" If you get it wrong by saying "ey" rather than "eir" when that person **said** "call me ey", you have made an understandable and minor error. If that person then made a big fuss about your minor error, *that* person would be in the wrong.

Comment: @catija You are suggesting that one can avoid neopronouns by avoiding the need to use a pronoun. But, from that point on, one is neither anymore allowed to use he, she, or they?

Comment: @194636 You're probably right. The original CoC was written as if everyone here wanted to act in bad faith and hurt LGBTQIA folks and a strict set of rules was needed to prevent us from doing that. The new one is much better but after all that happened recently I read "do your best" as a commandment to invest considerable effort to not use incorrect pronouns.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (as a native English speaker) that, in this context, "do your best" just means "make a reasonable effort," or "do the best that you can *without* spending a lot of time doing research." It does not mean "do the best that you possibly can." If you don't do any research at all, but you make your best guess, I think that counts as "doing your best."

Comment: In this situation, I'd suggest simply using the pronoun you'd use in any other situation where you don't know what pronoun to use. For me, that'd be "their"; in your style, it sounds like it'd be "his". It's not obvious to me that looking up the possessive pronoun that supposedly goes with the ones they've already stated would serve much purpose even in principle; I've seen as many people who mixed and matched from different neopronoun sets as who used one consistently, so you've got good chances of *still* being wrong even if you do the research.

Comment: @CesarM so then the onus is entirely on those who wish to have neopronouns used in references to themselves to call out and constantly educate those they are interacting with?

Comment: @oleg "Do your best" really means, "be respectful" or "do not be a troll/dick" etc. I'm not a mod but I think as long as you don't go out of your way to offend someone, you will probably be OK. Someone might edit your posts to make them more gender-neutral.

Comment: Hullo. A neopronoun user here. (Posting late because I didn't know about this post before.) Usually pronouns are posted in pairs or trios - e.g. xe/xyr/xem - exactly for this reason. If there are two and you can't do research or it's hard, ask or just use the 2nd form (kinda like she/her/her - two forms are the same). You're still "doing your best" for that time. :) I can provide some resources (kind of a list with most common and examples of their usage) if someone needs it.

Answer (score 22):

I note that [M2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336367/157730) states:

> M2. I'm a moderator. I often have to refer to other users, I can't choose which ones I have to refer to, and often it isn't feasible to avoid pronouns. So do I really have to use pronouns I find uncomfortable?
>
> Yes. As a moderator, you're held to a higher standard and are expected to set a positive example for your community. Using incorrect pronouns or conspicuously avoiding using pronouns is disrespectful. Telling them you refuse to use their pronouns is rude. If you think you will find using pronouns as stated difficult, please try. Most moderators won’t have to address this frequently. If you need help or have questions, contact the CM team for guidance. After that, if you cannot in good conscience follow it, reach out so we can find a replacement for you.

I know about the "you're held to a higher standard" part. That's been in [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) for approximately forever (or at least since May 2009).

Why not have an intermediary step of, say, **"talk to your fellow moderators and see if someone else on the team is willing to handle the situation"**? In other words, trying to resolve the situation amicably within the existing moderator team *rather than* resigning.

As pointed out in the comments, this is in line with long-established standard practice on issues where a moderator has a potential conflict of interest.

After all, the very answer to that question says that for most moderators it won't be a frequent occurence. (It certainly hasn't been for me.) And even if it were a frequent occurence, very few moderation situations need to be handled by *one specific* moderator.

Part of the reason why there are multiple moderators on each site is that no one moderator should have to handle everything, and to have someone to discuss details with before taking action. Sometimes, this means having a discussion among moderators hashing out the phrasing of a message before sending that message to the user, whether privately (mod message) or publicly (comment, meta answer, ...).

Comment: Current (hopefully temporary) problem with this: some sites having only one mod active. Do they ask the CMs to step in?

Comment: Surely if a moderator is unwilling to follow the rules they enforce, they are grossly incapable of doing their job?

Comment: @Daveoc64 Just because one moderator doesn't want to handle *one specific* flag or respond to *one specific* question or comment doesn't (in my opinion) mean "they are grossly incapable of doing their job". The important part is that the moderation team as a whole is capable of handling issues that arise, and handle those issues in a reasonably consistent manner; that already requires communicating between moderators, and not uncommonly discussing how to handle a particular situation before taking visible action. There isn't much of a leap from there to "can someone else respond to this?".

Comment: This is just like those civil servants refusing to marry gay people due to religious objections. Seems very against the new CoC IMO.

Comment: @Renan what about civil servants that refuse to give woman a hand, when the majority of the country believes giving hands is not only standard, but also polite and respectful?

Comment: @Renan *"This is just like those civil servants refusing to marry gay people due to religious objections."* Not really, in my opinion. It's more along the lines of civil servants asking a colleague to do something that they themselves feel uncomfortable doing. If we want an inclusive community, I feel that inclusivity absolutely *has* to also include the community moderators. Why should an otherwise great moderator be excluded -- no, expelled -- just because there is *one* thing they don't want to do because doing so goes against *that* moderator's beliefs?

Comment: Mind you, I'm not saying "any such issues should be dismissed by that moderator", but rather more along the lines of "each moderator should be allowed to ask their fellow moderators to handle issues they can't handle without going against *their own* conscience".

Comment: This seems akin to a moderator avoiding a potential or actual conflict of interest by asking another moderator to handle something.  This is *standard practice* on the moderation teams I've been part of.  Asking another moderator to handle something you yourself can't handle *for whatever reason* should not raise eyebrows.  If it were to happen often enough to become burdensome (unlikely!), the team would handle it internally.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yeah, this seems like something that moderator teams could deal with internally. As long as the mod in question doesn't make their recusal conspicuous or rude (for example by saying "Oh, in that case, I can't help you. Talk to X") and so long as their fellow mods are ok with it, then I don't see the problem.

Comment: It would be harder to do on small sites, though, where there might only be one moderator active at a time. It wouldn't be good if there were times when certain people couldn't get moderation. But as long as that wasn't a problem, a sites' mod team could probably figure out an arrangement that works

Comment: "For many decades British officers had to take an oath against transubstantiation. Its aim was to keep Catholics out of the ranks of officers. A relatively small matter was used to impose a big restriction. This is a requirement of the same kind. The request seems small but the implications are vast."

Comment: @MonicaCellio I find it ironic that [point 7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336364/what-does-the-code-of-conduct-say-about-pronouns/336365#336365) under Implementation seems to yield on the very thing that was being debated in the first place

Comment: @PinnyM indeed.  My usual writing style is not in conflict with this CoC.  And I didn't violate it before it was official, even if they say that a future CoC is somehow binding.  And some say that the pronoun thing was already part of the pre-existing CoC, but [Tim Post admitted that that was not at all obvious and that's why they're specifying it now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336146/162102), so any issues before that update can't be called violations unless, you know, somebody actually said "hey we think this is a violation". So the firing was never warranted under any CoC.

Comment: @MonicaCellio "[if you stop using pronouns for everyone altogether and consistently do not, that's fine. Even if you did before.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336381/157730)"

Comment: Of course the CoC can't allow this. What if there's a trans person on your mod team; do you think they'll feel welcome if they see you consistently refusing to work with trans people? Maybe you can get away with this behavior if no one recognizes your motive, or everyone agrees not to report you, but it's never going to get official approval.

Comment: @aCVn I think your points would make sense if you were talking about a moderator recusing themselves because a complaint was made about a friend's post (to avoid bias), or when they didn't have the skill set to deal with an issue (e.g. because the subject matter of the post was far outside of their knowledge base), but in the case of pronouns, the moderator would be actively saying "I do not want to enforce this **rule**, as I do not agree with it" - and that is unacceptable in my eyes. You couldn't have a police officer ignore some crimes they thought were morally OK.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Actually, both Monica and I have been on a mod team with at least one person who self-identifies as (among other things) a member of the Lavender community. https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2243/2533 Insofar as I recall, that was never a problem at all, whether interpersonally between the members of the moderator team or in carrying out moderation tasks. It seems to me to be extremely heavy-handed to require a moderator to resign *for something that isn't a problem*. If it becomes a problem, it can be handled without becoming a CoC violation.

Comment: @aCVn That trans person on your team may have been going along to get along. That doesn't mean they felt welcome. Maybe if the new CoC had been in effect, they'd have had the confidence to raise an objection. In any case, you're not going to get fired if everyone on your team is okay with what you're doing, and you keep it to yourselves. But it seems unlikely the CoC is ever going to explicitly allow anti-trans discrimination from mods. How do you think the bigots and trolls will react if your discrimination is approved and theirs isn't?

Comment: What if my deeply-held beliefs precluded me from working with non-white people, or Jews, or female programmers, or people with autism? Should the CoC allow me avoid those people too? No business I've ever worked for would have wanted to be represented by someone with those beliefs, nor would they have allowed me to only work with people I approve of.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Have you encountered the meme "on the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog"? A huge fraction of the times, *someone's pronouns aren't even relevant*. What I am proposing in my answer is, **quite simply**, that there should be a step *in between* "you, and you specifically, must be willing to address *every* user explicitly with their stated preferred pronoun, no matter how outlandish it is and no matter how much that goes against what you believe in or have trained to do" and "you must resign as a moderator" (those are not the words used by SE, but that is the effect). [1/2]

Comment: Writing in a gender-neutral manner is one way of handling such a conflicting situation by never having to use gendered third-person singular personal pronouns; another is to, if what needs to be said is actually impossible to say without resorting to gendered third-person singular personal pronouns (I can't imagine what situation that would be, but I am willing to concede that they might possibly exist), simply ask another moderator for help. Which isn't particularly different from how a moderator would handle any other situation that they feel uncomfortable with for some reason. [2/2]

Comment: @aCVn At your last job interview, if you had informed your prospective employer that there may be some situations in which you simply can't help but to discriminate against a client or colleague, but that's okay because it's possible those situations will never come up, do you think you would have gotten the job?

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Being a community moderator on Stack Exchange is an unpaid volunteer position handled on what is essentially an "as available" basis. That's pretty much the polar opposite of paid employment, so I don't really see how hypothetically comparing the two would be a particularly productive use of my limited time.

Comment: @aCVn Mods will be seen as representing the company, whether they're paid or not. I'm sure most organizations that have a volunteer workforce would prefer not to have volunteers that undermine the organization's goals.

Comment: The idea that an inclusive community must be inclusive of those who wish to discriminate based on immutable characteristics has been shown not to work in the wild. Back when gaming cons tried to be inclusive of even the misogynists, the result was that many women didn't feel comfortable and were excluded. By excluding the small amount of misogynistic people, they were able to become more inclusive to women. Similarly, excluding as moderators who have trouble being inclusive towards trans people can be actually make the community more inclusive.

Comment: That said, none of this should be seen as supporting what happened to Monica. She was simply asking questions at that point,  and the rules had not taken effect yet. Furthermore, she was removed without the due process provided by the rules. Plus, the rules that were enforced had not been properly vetted via the rules for creating new rules, and were thus flawed. I might be sympathetic if they admitted they jumped the gun due to emotions blaring, I might get behind them. But, as is, I see every step towards trans inclusion as performative, and question whether SE really does care about trans*.

Comment: Asking other moderators to handle flags can have dozens of reasons, now it has dozens +1. No need to mention it specifically.

Answer (score 21):

Why is so much of the FAQ phrased like this?

---

> 8. Isn't all this causing lots of inconvenience to everyone for the sake of a minority?
>
> No. One thing is required of you...

.

> 3. My religion tells me that people can't change their gender. Aren't you treating me with disrespect in the name of treating others with respect?
> 4. I find it really distressing to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong. Is there really no alternative?
>
> Our users may hold any beliefs they do... But conspicuously avoiding using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others is a way of refusing to recognize their identity, and that is discriminatory. Please don’t do that.

.

> 5. If someone is non-binary, does it really matter whether I call them "ey" or "they" or "xe" or some other gender-neutral pronoun? Do I have to handle dozens of different pronouns?
>
> Many non-binary people will be OK with whatever non-binary pronoun you use for them - however, if they have stated one, use the one they have stated.

.

> 7. Am I obligated to find opportunities to use pronouns?
>
> Not at all! If you don’t need to use pronouns to say something, that’s fine. We ask that you use pronouns as you would naturally. If you’d use them in a sentence, use them; if not, don’t. Problems arise when a person or group feels singled out by having pronouns used for other people but not for them. If you're writing normally and naturally and it comes out pronoun-less, then that's fine.

.

> 8. What if someone wants to be referred to as "the Great and Mighty One" or by an obscenity or something?
>
> If something is obviously unreasonable and seems to be requested unkindly, please feel free to flag for moderator attention... Note that "it sounds silly to me" is not sufficient grounds to think something is obviously unreasonable

---

In each of these answers, the FAQ immediately contradicts itself. It first gives the answer that will be acceptable to the community, then makes a blanket exception that completely undoes the first answer. Is it any wonder there's just as much confusion over the policy as before? Why not just be direct about what the policy really is:

---

> 8. Isn't all this causing lots of inconvenience to everyone for the sake of a minority?
>
> Yes. Sometimes the majority must accommodate a minority...

.

> 3. My religion tells me that people can't change their gender. Aren't you treating me with disrespect in the name of treating others with respect?
> 4. I find it really distressing to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong. Is there really no alternative?
>
> If your beliefs do not recognize the self-identity of trans and nonbinary people, they are not welcome here.

.

> 5. If someone is non-binary, does it really matter whether I call them "ey" or "they" or "xe" or some other gender-neutral pronoun? Do I have to handle dozens of different pronouns?
>
> Yes. You must handle any pronouns that a person asks you to. You can start with [this non-exhaustive list](https://lgbta.wikia.org/wiki/Neopronouns).

.

> 7. Am I obligated to find opportunities to use pronouns?
>
> Yes. If we think you're trying to avoid using someone's preferred pronouns, you may be sanctioned for it.

.

> 8. What if someone wants to be referred to as "the Great and Mighty One" or by an obscenity or something?
>
> We have no actual guidance to give you here because this policy is based on ideology rather than any sensible attempt to create inclusion. You're totally on your own, and if you guess wrong, there will be consequences.

(OK, that last one isn't very charitable, but the original version is totally incomprehensible, and given how many revisions this has gone through, I can only assume intentionally so.)

---

If you don't want to discuss the actual policy, as you have made clear in the original post, then so be it. But at least be honest about what it is, instead of dancing around it in the hopes the users don't figure it out.

Comment: Somehow people thought that wording it in a less direct way would be less aggresive and negative. But they forgot that programmers/coders and mathematicians - the main public here - are dealing a bit differently with this. I guess that a lot of people at StackExchange/Overflow are currently annoyed by "us", but this is how we think/process.

Comment: I'm a mathematician and hobbyist programmer/coder. I don't find this a difficult thing to deal with, and how I think/process has been an advantage in this situation, not a drawback or hindrance or creating a circumstance requiring alternative structure. You don't speak for me as a mathematician or as a programmer, and I reject the views that your comments (yes, plural, almost all of them you've posted on this page) try to represent me with. @SextusEmpiricus

Comment: @Nij you could have read a bit more in-between the lines and be less rigorous about my comment; don't take it personal. ----- My association with the ugly and messy discussions that are unfolding here is that it relates to how the *group* (not the individuals) of programmers/coders and mathematicians is *in general* dealing with these sort of things. StackExchange is the place where you get much more nitpicking comments than elsewhere (like responses to a particular comment about mathematicians/coders is not relating to an individual).

Comment: These long-winded discussions about gender and the related Code of Conduct and FAQ takes me back to a meeting among scientist related to computation and modeling. The entire afternoon program got hijacked by discussions that were only about how to define the 'model', and we still had not resolved the issue at the end of the day. What is currently happening here on StackExchange, the nitpicking, is one big deja-vu-explosion putting all my memories of the stereotypical behaviour of mathematicians and coders into one big melting pot inside an exploding volcano.

Comment: I think you're completely misrepresenting the answers here. They are not contradictory. In the first example, the one thing you have to do is hardly an inconvenience, given its rarity, let alone "lots of inconvenience." For the second one, it's just telling you, that as usual, you should keep your personal religious beliefs to yourself unless they are explicitly on topic. I confess I am puzzled why this bothers anyone, since it's the default in (US) society, where I'm from. You might as well tell me your religion compels you to treat women as property...

Comment: and therefore asking you to treat women as people is compelling you to speech against your religion. I have no sympathy for this position. I don't see why religious sanctioned bigotry becomes more acceptable if the target is trans/NB people. The third answer doesn't start off saying no, and doesn't contradict itself. I think you just misread the first sentence of the answer. The fourth answer is clear and again not contradictory. The policy is asking you to use stated pronouns if (a) you ordinarily would, and (b) they have been stated. Nothing in answer four seems to be saying anything else...

Comment: Finally for answer 5, "it seems silly to me" is clearly a different reason than "the person is requesting pronouns in bad faith or as an attack on trans/NB people."

Answer (score 19):

**Q: Am I expected to remember every time someone corrects me on a pronoun in case I have to interact with them again later?**

Like I commented in the (now deleted) previous FAQ: I don't care to remember every interaction I've had on this site in case I run into them again. I don't care about the person behind the post, I only care that there is a good answer to the question posted.

As part of that I don't even look at the name of a poster unless I need to @ them, let alone try and recall whether they expressed a pronoun preference to me before.

Comment: I think this is covered by "Does this mean that I will be in trouble if I ever get someone's pronouns wrong?" If you get it wrong for someone you interacted with a long time ago, you have made an honest mistake. But if you use gender neutral language (as recommended), or (as you imply you do) you use @user, error is impossible.

Comment: @Raedwald but "long time ago" is subjective. For one person that might mean a week, for others that can mean hours (if they were 2 independent interactions).

Comment: ""long time ago" is subjective": which is why moderators will *apply intelligent judgement*. Just like they do about *all other* claimed violations of the CoC. What is rude? What is condescending? These all require intelligent judgement.

Answer (score 18):

## Reword to follow Wikipedia NPOV style guide

This FAQ currently violates the CoC, which states:

> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on ... religion

This problem can be fixed by following the [Wikipedia NPOV policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Neutral_point_of_view), particularly their [style guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Words_to_watch). Wikipedia's style guide is designed to treat controversial topics neutrally, with respect to all parties, and without implying that the underlying issues are matters of opinion.

### Suggested changes

These suggested changes are the minimal changes required to make the FAQ follow the Wikipedia guidelines, and use actual phraseology from Wikipedia when possible.

> #### 1. What's this business about "pronouns"?
>
> It would be rude to refer to a man as "she" or a woman as "he". Some people **identify as** <del>are</del> neither men nor women and might, for instance, ask to be referred to as "they". When someone indicates what pronouns should be used to refer to them, please use the pronouns they state as you would others.

> #### 4. What was that about being neither men nor women?
>
> Some people **identify as** <del>are</del> neither men or women. The usual term for such people is "non-binary" and they’re often included in the term “transgender”. Just as you wouldn't want to be referred to with a pronoun <del>that doesn't fit</del> you **don't identify with**, neither do they.

> #### M2. I'm a moderator. I often have to refer to other users, I can't choose which ones I have to refer to, and often it isn't feasible to avoid pronouns. So do I really have to use pronouns I find uncomfortable?
>
> Yes. As a moderator, you're held to a higher standard and are expected to set a positive example for your community. Using <del>incorrect</del> **other** pronouns <del>or</del>**,** conspicuously avoiding using pronouns <del>is disrespectful. T</del> **or t**elling them you refuse to use their pronouns <del>is rude</del> **can be hurtful**. If you think you will find using pronouns as stated difficult, please try. Most moderators won’t have to address this frequently. If you need help or have questions, contact the CM team for guidance. After that, if you cannot in good conscience follow it, reach out so we can find a replacement for you.

> #### 4. I find it really distressing to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong. Is there really no alternative?
>
> You can often avoid using pronouns altogether. It's actually pretty rare to need third-person pronouns at all on most Stack Exchange sites. But conspicuously avoiding using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others <del>is a way of refusing to recognize their identity, and that</del> is discriminatory **and can be hurtful**. Please don’t do that.

Comment: I like objectivity in most cases, but this change would be transphobic.

Answer (score 16):

> However, note that debating the core of the new rule ("please use
>   stated pronouns") or the validity of people's identities or gender
>   expressions is off-topic for this post, and we won't be entertaining
>   those debates at this point.

- Can the users express their disagreement with the core of the new rule in any
  way?
- Can they use their profiles for that?
- If they do, will that be used against them if they disengage when asked to use neo-pronouns?
- How about answers and upvotes that reflect this opinion?
- **In general, will users be banned for not using certain pronouns if they have at some point, expressed their disagreement with this rule?**

Comment: I used my profile to express my disagreement. It was edited out within few days ... But I wasn't banned (yet?).

Comment: "is off-topic for this post": That message only applies to **this specific post**. You are free to talk about the core of the policy on other questions (and, indeed, there have been many of those) or in chat. This specific question, however, is just for clarifications about the FAQ.

Comment: @divibisan Yes, I know you can express disagreement on different ways, that is why I am asking if it will be used against the user

Answer (score 15):

Probably too minor to really warrant a proper answer, but I can't find a good place to add this as a comment ... From [Edge cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336365/169312):

> #### 2. But the free choice of language is important to me. This rule impairs my freedom of speech.
>
> By participating here you're agreeing to treat others with politeness. That includes not insulting people (even if you sincerely think ill of them, and even if you're right). It also includes not intentionally misgendering them.

I'm wondering if this section is necessary at all. If it is, perhaps it should be more explicit about how *any* argument about freedom of speech is a straw man. In most jurisdictions, we are already legally constrained by various well-known and common-sense restrictions about yelling "fire" in a crowded theater etc ad naus.

Comment: In fairness, there may be readers who have not yet finished primary school and thus are being exposed to this fact for the first time, though they are then probably violating the age clause in the terms of service.

Comment: Yeah, this one's a little iffy. In general, the "free speech" argument is one used as a way to communicate: "I don't think I should do this and am using free speech as a shield to defend that." This edge case... seems like it misses the point? But also, those aren't really people you can reply to constructively, so I'm not personally miffed about this one.

Comment: Take out "of speech", and the problem is solved. "Freedom of speech" gets people thinking about the specific legal concept, and that's not really the goal of this bullet point. The goal of this bullet point is to clarify that *your* rights and freedoms stop where *someone else's* rights and freedoms start. As important as freedom and self-expression are, you don't have the freedom to be impolite  or disrespectful to someone else.

Comment: @CodyGray The problem is that no one asked for the right to insult someone. They asked for the right to not express any opinion, and were told instead that they must explicitly acknowledge another's gender identity or be banned. This point has been raised many times but has been strawmanned into a request for abuse. Freedom of silence is vastly more important to people than freedom of speech because it is the default right and behaviour of humans, dogs, cats, etc. They can privately maintain their own thoughts and still be nice. That's not being respected.

Comment: @TheAnathema No, that's wrong. We specifically say that you don't have to go out of your way to use pronouns for people... There are so many options that meet that need. We've never stated that you have to continue a conversation that makes you uncomfortable... anyone can end a conversation with someone for any reason or no reason on our sites. You're not beholden to complete an interaction with someone.

Comment: @Catija that is unclear. I would say that it is not a desirable solution that instead of 'avoiding the use of some pronoun' it is better to 'avoid conversation'. So I am not allowed to use 'they' instead of some neopronoun, but I am allowed to *ignore* people who request/prefer the use of a neopronoun altogether?

Comment: *" There are so many options that meet that need"* What other options besides *ignoring/avoiding* people with preferred pronouns that one may not agree with or wish to not use?

Comment: 'yelling "fire" in a crowded theater' — oh, not this one again. Fun fact: the historical, legal origin of this particular analogy is a US Supreme Court decision that held that non-violent (Communist) war protesters could be arrested and punished for their objections to World War I. When you use this analogy, you are arguing along with the justices that upheld government censorship of conscientious objectors. I submit that this is probably not the side you wish to be arguing for.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks for this insight! I'll see if I can come up with a different example without tripping Godwin's law.

Comment: I’ve seen freedom of speech based arguments used here so I don’t think that it correct to say this is a straw man.

Comment: I think the quoted answer doesn't actually answer the quoted "question". It needs at least one sentence like "freedom of speech doesn't guarantee you to do your speech on our private website".

Answer (score 15):

> It would be rude to refer to a man as "she" or a woman as "he". Some people are neither men nor women and might, for instance, ask to be referred to as "they".

.. It **could** be rude, transvestites may still identify as a man but when in character be preferred to be addressed as 'she'.

I still feel like you're missing the point and a bit hypocritical because "trying to preemptively legislate for everything hypothetically" is *exactly* what you're doing.

Comment: 'Character' feels like it might be the wrong term.. if anyone knows the correct term please fix!

Comment: Not the point being made in this answer, but an observation.  Referring to a man as "she" or a woman as "he" happens innocently all the time and is a human foible.  It's typically more embarrassing for the person making the mistake.  What is rude is to knowingly and purposely do that.  The wording should make that distinction, rather than characterizing normal human behavior as rude.

Comment: I noticed on Drag Race, the contestants DO usually stick to "she" pronouns when In Character (or working on becoming the character), and "he" pronouns when out of costume -- for some there's a point in their transformation, different for each, where the pronoun shifts -- some it's the wig, some it's the undergarments, and some only when The Look is complete.    But my trans friends say they never feel like "The Look" is the key factor or that there's any one point in time, that it's all about self-knowledge and how much effort do they want to go into correcting others.

Comment: @Luuklag "may still recognise as a man" is not grammatical, I think you meant “*may still **be** recognis**able** as a man...*” But I  see nothing wrong with the earlier `may self-define`

Comment: @Mari-LouA - That was my original posts sentence.. "may still identify as a man" is probably a better alternative but i'm still not convinced that "character" is correct (I also didn't see anything wrong with may self-define)

Comment: @Sayse Character, in drag, or whatever. As that line is written now, it is ungrammatical.

Comment: I simply reverted to the original since a suggested edit was making a mess of it. @Mari-LouA

Comment: I've heard some transvestites refer to it as being "en femme" or "in girl mode".

Comment: @EttinaKitten - That would be a good alternative but it doesn't cover a female transvestite

Answer (score 13):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Is the new CoC and FAQ about gender pronouns or about pronouns in general?**

Reading [What does the Code of Conduct say about gender pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336364/what-does-the-code-of-conduct-say-about-gender-pronouns) it is focused on gender:

> The Code of Conduct has two direct references to gender pronouns:
>   “Use stated pronouns (when known).”
>   “Prefer gender-neutral language when uncertain.”

But CoC is not implying that pronouns must be directly related to gender:

> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate.

As far as I know there can be pronouns that are not related to gender but in general to individuals identity https://what-the-heck-gender-am-i.tumblr.com/pronouns

Comment: That's a fair point for the title/main post. I've updated those to remove gender.

Comment: In guessing this only applies to gendered pronouns—or, rather, third-person singular personal pronouns (which are usually considered to be gendered). So it applies to pronouns like "he," "she," and "they," but not pronouns like "I," "you," "who," "someone," and "each other." Am I understanding the policy right?

Comment: @TannerSwett: Correct.

Comment: "there can be pronouns that are not related to gender". I [disagree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336135/170084). We need to talk about pronoun use because English third-person pronouns are [grammatically gendered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender). Now, if we were using a language that [classified nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_class) (and pronouns) according to a human/animal distinction, genuine [Otherkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherkin) might have a genuine reason to complain. But we don't.

Comment: @Raedwald "English third-person pronouns are grammatically gendered" unless you use gender neutral pronouns. Then gender is irrelevant.

Comment: The problem is that 3rd person pronouns *currently relate to gender*. And some people may have a problem with that (not only transgenders or non-binary genders but what seems to be misrepresented here is the inequality between man and woman). The wide prevalence of prejudice in standard use of gendered pronouns makes it a problem. There is no problem with pronouns that do not relate to gender. When we are gonna generalize the issue and make pronouns an issue of other types of identity/personification then the situation grows out of hand (allowing helicopter identities and such things).

Comment: @cesarM so the issue is *not* about gender, but instead about opening up to the entire gamut of possible (neo)pronouns?

Comment: @CesarM So if somebody goes by - to take one of the examples from the post - *hoof/hooves/hooveself*, I am required, when speaking about them, to use that pronoun and thereby express my agreement that they truly are, in some sense, a horse? This is really the position that the company is taking on this; that *any* assertion a person makes about their identity, no matter how ridiculous, must, if made by way of a pronoun, not only not be rebutted but be actively affirmed by everyone here who talks about them in the third person?

Answer (score 13):

The edge cases may *seem* to specify in a less restrictive way how one should act and seem to take away a lot of the previously existing compelled speech and conflicts. You might even think that compelled speech is gone.

But, it is mostly confusing language that is used in answers to FAQ 3 and FAQ 4.

> 3. My religion tells me that people can't change their gender. **Aren't you treating me with disrespect in the name of treating others with respect?**
>
>    Our users may hold any beliefs they do - be it about gender or even having strong opinions about religions themselves. But if you go out of your way to point out your disagreement about their gender, you aren't behaving in a way we want here - just as people pointing out how wrong they think your religion is aren't behaving in a way we want here. Do not be rude to other people.
> 4. I find it really distressing to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong. **Is there really no alternative?**
>
>    You can often avoid using pronouns altogether. It's actually pretty rare to need third-person pronouns at all on most Stack Exchange sites. But conspicuously avoiding using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others is a way of refusing to recognize their identity, and that is discriminatory. Please don’t do that.

For instance it even seems to suggest that one can avoid using pronouns. But then... later it says that one can not *conspicuously avoid using pronouns*? This is very contradictory. I read the answer to Q4 as **"you can avoid using pronouns that way, but don't do it"**.

And how are people that do not like to use particular pronouns, for whatever reasons, being treated with respect?  I read the answer to Q3 **"we respect it when your religion only treats male/female gender, but here you are obliged to use non-binary gender pronouns"**

The question 3 isn't really answered just like the question 4 is not answered. There is some text below it but it seems to avoid an answer.

---

Written by [StackExchangeStrike](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/164061/sextus-empiricus?tab=profile)

Comment: It's stating that you shouldn't make it obvious that you're avoiding the OP's pronouns if a polite request has been made to use another set. If your writing style avoids gendered pronouns naturally, keep going, if it includes gendered pronouns however, and the only times you tend to avoid pronouns is with those who have asked for use of other pronouns, it may be perceived to be in bad faith, and while it may not happen often for you, the entire of someone else's experience may be plagued by others avoiding the topic while around them, which can inadvertently "other" some parts of the community

Comment: @KyleFairns the FAQ would be more clear when it simply gets to the point rather than sugercoating it. So compelled speech is still there or not? I can not decide that I find 'they' in some cases confusing or not correct (e.g. because there's also a plural they and there is not a plural he or plural she so I will tend to avoid 'they' more often than how I would normally use he or she) *and* act by avoiding pronouns in those cases? Neither am I allowed to avoid neopronouns in places where I would normally use he/she/they?

Comment: More compelled politeness than compelled speech if I'm being honest with you. [U2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336367/382667) sort of clarifies that a bit more for me. If you refer to everyone without using gendered pronouns (excluding some edge cases with "they/them") it shouldn't really effect you. Essentially it's about avoiding making the user feel singled out. If you're referring to others in that thread with gendered pronouns, refer to the requester with the gendered pronouns they have requested in order not to "other" that user

Comment: @KyleFairns when it means that people have to adjust their preferred way of speech, e.g. use exotic neopronouns or use they in an ambiguous way (or something against their religion) then compelled politeness turns into compelled speech.  Labelling it different doesn't change it. I agree that the 'conspicuously' part is of course a gray area. A sentence like "Bob and Alice went shopping. He bought shoes and Alice did it" is a more obvious and explicit omission of a pronoun than when it occurs isolated. For most other cases I'd say that people should be more free to choose their writingstyle.

Comment: (pt 1) Looking at your username, I wouldn't be able to tell what gender I should refer to you as if I were talking about you in the third person. I personally have always defaulted to "As Sextus said in their comment" - a username is just a display name after all. If you know a bit of Latin, you may be inclined to refer to someone with a similar display name to yours as "he", but you may be wrong on that, and if I were to make an assumption and it was pointed out as wrong by the person I'm making the assumption about, I'd change how I referred to them so that it was right.

Comment: (pt 2) Essentially, the intentional and transparent differential treatment of someone after they have pointed out an easily correctable mistake in how you have referred to them is what the CoC outlines as wrong

Comment: @KyleFairns I agree with it being wrong and it is fine when it is outlined as wrong. But I believe it should not be compulsive. Besides that it makes the rulebook unnecessarily bigger (the cases rarely happen, especially that somebody insists on a certain neopronoun) it is also suggesting repercussions (although not explicitly stated what will happen) that are potentially disproportionate.

Comment: *"As Sextus said in their comment"* This' a use of 'they/their' that's not much confusing. However [its not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336016/an-evidence-based-appeal-for-gender-neutrality-in-the-code-of-conduct/336273#336273) like 'they' is exactly equal to 'he' and 'she'. Those pronouns link much more strongly to an explicit singular antecedent. This inequality (not the people that they refer to but the words themselves are inequal) makes it possible that in some occasions some people might be more tempted to omit the use of the pronoun. This practice should not be disallowed.

Comment: Be careful with this edge case. I'm sure there are plenty of users who (for whatever reason) believe that gender is binary, but are perfectly nice people and understand it's their personal belief and don't wish to cause offence, so they quietly rephrase their contributions to avoid pronouns wherever those pronouns are ones that they are unwilling to use, but still wish to engage in an otherwise respectful manner. I understand that this itself may be seen as disrespectful and invalidating, but it's arguably not as bad as misgendering, and allows both groups to continue in civil discourse.

Answer (score 13):

“Implementation” Question 4 is under-punctuated. 
It says,

> Can I use he or she based on a user name/avatar
>   and correct if they tell me I was wrong?

It should be,

> Can I use **“**he or she**”** based on a user name/avatar
>   and correct if they tell me I was wrong?

or

> Can I use **“**he**”** or **“**she**”** based on a user name/avatar
>   and correct if they tell me I was wrong?

I guess it’s the second.

---

Also, it should probably say “May I”?

Comment: I assume that it means either, i.e. that "he", "she", "he or she", and "they", are all adequate -- SE prefers and recommends "they", though -- adequate, if-and-only-if you're willing to correct your usage for a specific person on request.

Answer (score 13):

Only two remarks this time.

### U4 -

> Add a comment noting what they said and suggesting that they could comment on the question/answer next time. Edit it out of the question as you would with "Hi" and "Thanks". Because you've made their request less visible, keep an eye out for mistakes in answers and comments and consider making polite corrections.

This still seems noisy in the face of technical sites, since a comment like that could be rife for quick and speedy cleanup.  For technical sites *only*, I still struggle to see how this information would be pertinent to a question or answer; maybe in comments would this come up during conversation, which would still be a signal to me that the comments are too chatty.

However, being able to edit it out as noise [addresses my original complaint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334909/175248) (10k only), so I'll *largely* acquiesce.  It'd be nice if the FAQ had more explicit guidance for technical Exchange sites.

### M2 -

> [...] As a moderator, you're held to a higher standard and are expected to set a positive example for your community. Using incorrect pronouns or conspicuously avoiding using pronouns is disrespectful. Telling them you refuse to use their pronouns is rude. If you think you will find using pronouns as stated difficult, please try. Most moderators won’t have to address this frequently. If you need help or have questions, contact the CM team for guidance. After that, if you cannot in good conscience follow it, reach out so we can find a replacement for you.

This reads like a bit of a chilling effect; non-moderators aren't necessarily forced to do this, but moderators must comply or be replaced.  This makes moderators slightly more vulnerable since I could anticipate some bad faith actors  plying on this angle to try and get a moderator removed from their position.

I see why this needs to be done, but it makes the unenviable position of being a diamond moderator even *less* enviable.  On the sites where this can quickly become a flash point, I'm not sure you could find others who would willingly fill that void.

Answer (score 12):

In **U1** you write:

> Avoid volunteering pronouns for third parties who have not indicated them on Stack Exchange (e.g. you know them in person) unless they are general knowledge.

I am not sure I understand the phrase *volunteering pronouns for third parties* correctly (I do not speak English natively). Am I right to assume that you mean a person I know does not want their real pronoun to be known in public so I should not use it too? (This sounds reasonable)

Or in other words: does *volunteer* in this context mean something like *reaveal a secret*?

If this is the case, I guess *they/them* would be the fallback pronouns, right?

Comment: Yes, that's a correct interpretation. I would go even further and say that if you don't know that they are ok with you revealing their pronouns, don't - but yea, that's it.

Comment: I would be "volunteering" your pronoun if you were having a conversation with *Bob* and I added a comment that says "Christine uses the pronoun *she*". In this kind of context the word "volunteering" means "intervene to try to help". The word "volunteering" does not generally mean "revealing a secret". However in this case it describes an action that *might* be revealing a secret.

Comment: Revealing a secret would be bad. But I suspect that the FAQ also wants to reduce noise and confusion by having people state pronouns only for themself.

Comment: If they've never posted their pronouns on Stack Exchange and you know them, do not give their pronouns out. Use gender-neutral pronouns unless told otherwise on Stack Exchange.

Comment: So how about explicitly putting in the CoC whether the desired pronouns or the closet status are more important?  Because there will be more opportunity for that conflict than most others

Answer (score 12):

> May I use they/them by default?

Counter question, that I would like to see answered in the FAQ:

**May I never use pronouns? But each and every time, address a specific user by using his profile name? Or *user X* for example?**

Pronouns are in the end, used to avoid redundancy. "Nancy became the new CEO, and then she ruined everything". It can be turned into "Nancy became the new CEO, and then Nancy ruined everything". And you can do that each and every time when you are talking about Nancy. Or Bob.

Is that a valid option for people who want to avoid the whole mess, on cost of writing in a style that most people will not find pleasing?

Comment: I imagine this would come under the "use gender-neutral language where uncertain" part - essentially, you're declaring that the whole thing is uncertain, so you're sticking to gender-neutral at all times to avoid the problem.

Comment: This is answered in the "What's this all about? - Implementation" FAQ, under #7. If you want to write in a way that completely avoids ALL pronouns period, forever, you may do so, but it has to be consistent. You can't decide a trans person gets no pronouns, but everyone else does.

Comment: I believe that replacing pronouns with proper names/handles, without otherwise changing the writing style, will not be regarded as using gender neutral language, but as an attempt to circumvent the CoC.

Comment: You need more practice in avoiding pronouns.  The example sentence would read much more naturally as "Nancy became the new CEO, and then ruined everything".

Comment: That'd be obtrusive, & exactly how people who wanted to make a point - that they were being prevented from using the pronoun *they* considered correct - would write. @Mark is right.

Answer (score 11):

### This is an answer praising the newly updated FAQ.

I believe that leaving positive feedback is also needed. It is all too easy to criticise and find faults and ignore the positive changes. You cannot please everybody but in this instance, the team has found a good compromise. We therefore begin mending bridges, and that means acknowledging positive progress has been achieved.

It doesn't matter one jot that the [pronominal proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335234/a-pronominal-proposal) earned nearly 300 upvotes or the team showed great humility and honesty in radically changing the now-defunct FAQ, and gave deserved credit to the author, Gareth McCaughan, if the community continues to downvote and nit-pick.

The continuing sniping, fighting and swiping at gender-neutral pronouns seems to be the reigning atmosphere. Instead of celebrating this progress, *some* users continue to feel upset, suspicious about gender-neutral pronouns and afraid of them, unnecessarily so IMO.

### R.E.S.P.E.C.T

[Respect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAI_Nv3qWto) should not be based on someone's username, avatar, low-quality posts, rep, profession, nationality, English language skills or gender. If someone says they're Corsican, you don't call them French a third time because you have never heard of Corsica and you're uncomfortable with the term “Corsican”.

Instead, say:

> *Course I can learn how to use that word.*

---

## No.5

> 5. "Gender-neutral"? Does that mean like "he/she"?
>    Not quite. While “he/she” and similar compound pronouns are better than a default masculine “he” alone, gender-neutral writing works to avoid gendered terms entirely when gender is unknown, either through rephrasing statements to avoid pronouns or through the usage of singular (or plural) “they”. For examples and other methods, see Kate Gregory’s answer to a related question - [Define "gender-neutral language"? (CoC FAQ)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335031/define-gender-neutral-language-coc-faq/335038#335038)

Perhaps the above could be worded in simpler terms, for users whose first or second language is not English, but these are not simple issues and this FAQ does not pretend to be [Simple English Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page). Kate Gregory's answer is well written, better than I could ever dream of writing, and provides great examples.

## **The singular they**

The snippets below are taken from answers I posted on English Language & Usage. In one, the acronym "OP" is used, and in the other, the person's username. Not knowing the gender of the user, I  used the singular and gender-neutral *they* and *their*

- [image]
- [image]

This is just an example, but I can assure non-native speakers they have seen the singular they in hundreds of instances, they just weren't aware of it before. So, as the British are wont to say

### Keep Calm and Carry On

Comment: As a french, this is accurate.

Comment: A *big difference* in the votes for the pronominal proposal and this new FAQ is the current distrust towards SE (that issue has not cleared up yet). In addition, some types of programmers and mathematicians regard rules in a less easy-going way than the average person. I get it that you might say 'common be less nitpicking and give the SE-staff a break', but then you forget that you are talking to [people that are used to rigor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127889), at least more than average people (I know, I did not define average here).

Answer (score 11):

**Q: How can I state my pronouns in my profile and at the same time indictate in a binding way that I do not consider them being ignored to fall under the CoC?**

My pronouns are ***se*** and ***sim*** but I don't care if anybody uses them or not. Do as you please. Not using my pronouns does **not** violate the CoC.

How can I **forbid** mods and staff to act against and punish anybody how ignores my pronouns?

Comment: I'd say that you'd just comment them in response to another user, or pre-emptively under your question/answer in the comments, or at least, that's my interpretation of point [U4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336367/382667), perhaps add a note on there that pronouns aren't an issue for you, so to disregard any misgendering toward yourself - but that may poke the bear

Comment: You could put them in the "about me" section of your profile, including a statement to the effect of, perhaps, you appreciate if people use them but you do not require them to be used when addressing you. (Adjust as desired to indicate your exact preference.) That of course won't *forbid* anything on the part of anyone else, but it will make your preferences clearly known to anyone who looks at your profile.

Comment: @aCVn Yes, that would be a possibility. But if overzealous user A flags an answer or a comment in which user B does not use by pronouns (which I am fine with), I have no way to indicate to the mods that this flag shall be ignored. This may result in user B being punished because user A did ignore my explicit wish.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that; flags are shown to moderators largely in isolation. "About me" is probably about the best you can do.

Comment: Hm, that's not good. TY for your comments.

Comment: If you say "se/sim but okay with any pronouns" in your profile I'd expect mods to read that before acting.

Comment: @Aza That's what I would expect, too. But I did not find anything in the published CoC and FAQs that indicates that it is *mandatory* for mods to check back with me before acting.

Comment: @Socken I think this is just common sense moderation. It's not really something that needs to be said -- moderators are, in every case, expected to look into ambiguities before acting.

Comment: If you don't really mind, then maybe not say it anywhere in your profile and only mention it to people you interact with regularly when it comes up?

Comment: Exactly what you have here. See also [my answer on the CoC change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334942) (10k+ or if you're logged in as me),

Comment: @JL2210 I don't understand what you mean by your comment.

Comment: @Sockenpuppe You put "My pronouns are se and sim but I don't care if anybody uses them or not. Do as you please." in your profile.

Comment: To be fair, if a user gets a flag saying "deliberate misgendering", the only real way for a moderator to decide whether that is true or not is to check your profile to work out what the correct pronouns are. As soon as they do that, they'll see that you've said you don't care what pronouns people use, at which point the moderator knows that they can drop it.

Answer (score 11):

### But what about the edge cases? Pt. 1:

> **1. Am I forbidden to express my opinion about this?**
>
> Some of our sites may have topics where gender is part of the subject and may be a valid question for the experts on that site. When answering these questions, it is important that answers report an **objective answer** to the question and avoid conveying the author's opinions on the subject. **Since these objective answers may be at odds with the Code of Conduct**, please take special care and frame them respectfully and politely — please be aware that many things you might want to say may be extremely distressing to some readers, and try to minimize that distress.

Several points about this:

1. You are *implying* that the Code of Conduct is at **odds** with objective facts, and that these facts could come from someone who is an expert on gender.
2. This implication does the exact opposite of what you want it to do. It highlights for those who do not believe in gender-fluidity that there are objective facts that disagree with your policy.
3. It also alienates the group of people whom you are trying to make feel welcome.
4. It also **implies** that you, Stack Overflow Inc., do not believe that gender-fluidity is compatible with objectivity.

---

This is not a statement of whether I believe in gender-fluidity or not. It is also not an admission of desire to follow, or not follow the new CoC. It is simply an observation of the effects it *most likely* would have in the mind of those reading it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the intention is to highlight that, when writing an objective answer to a question where gender identity is on-topic, that you have the freedom to discuss these kind of issues (as opposed to a answer about Javascript, where you should not include your opinions on gender). I don't think they intended to imply anything about the validity of gender-fluidity. Can you think of an alternate wording that would make that clearer?

Comment: That bit of the FAQ is saying, IMO, that e.g. on an SE site whose theme is a religion or politics or law or etc., it may be OK (on-topic) to say in an 'objective' answer that, "Church X doctrine doesn't support gender fluidity", or, "The laws of country Y don't support gender fluidity" -- that's OK in an answer and is not the same as saying, "I don't support gender fluidity" (which could or would be against the CoC).

Answer (score 11):

It still feels very dictatorial. Quoting a Python design principle, we  are all consenting adults. According to the current CoC, the following would be a conversation where Person B doesn't want to use the pronouns used by person A.

> Person A: Thanks for your answer. I have a few more question, are you
> happy to discuss this in a chat room? My pronouns are they/them
>
> Person B: .....tumble weed
> (Person B notices the use of he and she in their previous SE communications,
> but does not want to use the pronouns stipulated by Person A and decides to disengage.
>
> Person A: Hello??

Using the "be nice" and "we are all consenting adults", the conversation could flow as follows:

> Person A: Thanks for your answer. I have a few more question, are you
> happy to discuss this in a chat room? My pronouns are they/them
>
> Person B: Regarding your pronouns, based on my personal beliefs, I feel uncomfortable using these. Are you happy to proceed if I avoid using pronouns altogether?

This gives Person A an option:

> Person A: I respectfully disagree with you, but I am happy to proceed.

or

> Person A: The use of these pronouns is really important for me, let's respectfully agree to end this conversation.

The last scenario empowers Person A to make a choice and if Person A decides to end the conversation, at least it is clear the discussion with Person B has come to an end. However, this is not allowed under the current CoC. Even if Person A and Person B are happy with this conversation, someone can visit the post months or even years later and flag it for moderation. This introduces the risk for Person B to get banned if the moderation flag gets picked up by an overzealous moderator.

Is disengaging really better than a respectful conversation?

Why can Person A not decide what is acceptable for them?

-----------UPDATE------------

Given the comment below on my post, I would like to clarify that for some people using certain gender pronoun is absolutely nothing minor. For example, a devout Catholic could fear eternal damnation given the recent Vaticans statement on this issue.

In reality there will only be a handful of cases where the Person A/Person B scenario occurs.  The majority of the users, including me, will have no problem with the pronouns specified by the SE user. However, if StackExchange wants to be an inclusive community, they should respect different viewpoints on this issue.

Comment: If person B wanted to have a "respectful conversation" they would simply *respect* person A's choice of pronouns. The fact they refuse to do so tells me that a respectful conversation isn't their goal. If you refuse to do something as absolutely minor as use their pronouns correctly, is it really still "respectful"?

Comment: For some people using pronouns is not something absolutely minor. For example, a devout Catholic could fear eternal damnation given the recent Vaticans statement on this issue.

Comment: And the other way around, if Person A wants to have a "respectful conversation" with Person B, why can't they accept the other person may have an issue with using pronouns. Again in reality it will only a handful of cases where the Person A/Person B scenario occurs, the majority of the users, including me, will have no problem with pronouns. However, if StackExchange wants to be an inclusive community, they should respect different viewpoints on this issue.

Comment: Religious objections have already been declared as invalid; see [this response.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336522/629395) It simply isn't something that is being considered, nor should it be. If someone's chosen religion declares they must disrespect trans and non-binary people, they are free to just not engage with them.

Comment: As far as your second comment, because Person A has done nothing wrong. They shouldn't have to be required to be spoken to with the wrong pronouns simply because Person B has an irrelevant hangup on the issue. Person B is in the wrong, and Person B is the one that, per the CoC, needs to adjust their behavior.

Comment: Religious objections are not ruled out in this scenario as Person B doesn't go out of their way to avoid pronouns or in fact misgender Person A, nor is it their intention to be rude. Personally I find it much worse if Person B disengages from the conversation all together. Differences like this can only be resolved if there is an open dialogue. Without an open dialogue, Person B will return to their own protected world view without ever being challenged.

Comment: Again, the FAQ does state that religious objections are ruled out. It's a total non-starter of a discussion. If your religion dictates you have to treat transgender or non-binary people poorly, just disengage. Furthermore, their world view IS being challenged by the very fact that intentionally using the wrong pronouns, which is what they want to do, is now banned. If they want to intentionally misgender people, they can move to a website where that is allowed, but it isn't welcome on SE. That alone is a fantastic challenge to their views.

Comment: Again, Person A is not the one that the discussion should hinge on, which is what  your proposed change does. It isn't Person A's fault that Person B can't handle using a pronoun correctly, and so it shouldn't be up to them to either be misgendered or leave the conversation. It is entirely on Person B to correct their own behavior and respect their fellow SE users, and THEY can disengage if that's too much for them.

Comment: Let's respectfully disagree. I think dialogue is really important to resolve these differences. Without dialogue Person B will move into a different echo chamber where their beliefs are not challenged and society as a whole will not move forward.

Comment: @Jaco It is important to show people that $minority are human beings who deserve rights, but it is not the job of every single member of $minority to have that conversation over and over *and over* with hostile strangers on every question and chat room. Meta.SE *should* probably have a great Hashing Out Of Trans Rights when tensions aren't so high, but it shouldn't be shoved at all trans and non-binary people on all sites.

Comment: You have the right idea, but SO Inc. has dug themselves a hole they can never get out of, and they surely realize this as well. That's why the merits of the CoC are not even up for discussion.

Comment: @LeopoldsaysReinstateMonica Everyone has the right to disengage. If you avoid the Meta pages, it seems to be business as normal for SE sites.

Comment: I would rather keep Person A in control and not let Person B dictate things. If Person A started with "My pronouns are they/them, but if it distresses you to use them, call me whatever you want, because I value your input". Then Person B can decide what to do.

Comment: @StrongBad I am happy with any implementation that would allow Person A and Person B to talk to each other, provided Person A agrees to this.

Comment: The "other" group here is people who are not trans, not non-binary, but have pronoun preferences. That explicitly includes preference for he or she as well as "neopronouns" (as a part-time pedant I struggle to call things invented more than a century ago "new", let alone the "new" use of singular they which could better be described as archaic). There's *nothing* in the exchange above to suggest that A and/or B are not religious persons with very strong views about this area of dissension. Wait until the pope says "I prefer to be referred to as xe or je"...

Answer (score 9):

**QUESTION: FAITH and POLICY**

**PERSON 1** - identifies as non-binary. They insist that I refer to them using non-binary pronouns. Special rules have been set up to protect PERSON 1.

**PERSON 2 (me)** - believes the Bible as being God's word and that God made Man and Woman [Gen 5:2]. Instead of pushing that on other people I keep that standard for myself and let everyone else decide how they want to live their life.

**QUESTION:** Why does PERSON 1 get to make me use specific language that goes against my belief?

**CONTEMPLATION:** I believe all [including me] have sinned and need Christ. So I don't judge others for their sin because I have plenty in my own life and am trying to overcome it. BUT I should not be pushed to use alternative pronouns which is contrary to the Bible.

**Question 2:** In a post conversation, if I were to reference Sally as "She" and Sally said, I am not a "She" but a [non binary reference] my conscience would be free with only using her name in future posts, but would not be free to use their [non binary reference]. Is that OK per SE/SO policy?

---

### Answer from JNat:

This is answered by questions 3, 4, and 5 in the [But what about...?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336369/208518) section of the FAQ. In particular, the answer to question 3 has the most pertinent answer:

> Our users may hold any beliefs they do - be it about gender or even having strong opinions about religions themselves. But if you go out of your way to point out your disagreement about their gender, you aren't behaving in a way we want here - just as people pointing out how wrong they think your religion is aren't behaving in a way we want here. Do not be rude to other people.

Comment: Or see also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336372)

Comment: A valid point, perhaps poorly articulated. In essence: there are many people who hold beliefs (religious or otherwise) that tell them that gender is fixed and binary. Many of these people are in fact perfectly nice people, willing to live and let live, and who simply alter their language to avoid pronouns when those pronouns are ones they disagree with, because this allows them to continue a civil discussion and not force their views on anyone. While I understand that this can feel invalidating, forcing the religious user to use words they disagree with is just as dismissive of their beliefs.

Comment: Using a pronoun isn't "following" any "belief", and nobody is forcing you to "walk a path". They simply asked you to use "she" or "they" -- really not a big deal. If that is so unbelievably offensive to your religion that you are unable to function, refer to answers 3, 4, and 5 in the "Edge cases" FAQ.

Comment: @Baron Calling a person "xe" is an acknowledgement that this person is not male or female, which contradicts the view that male and female are the only genders, which for some people is a view rooted in their religion. Thus, using "xe" contradicts their religious belief. "Edge Cases" Q5 says that these people can still participate if they can do so politely. This is fine. The problem is that Q4 makes it easy for people who try to follow Q5 by simply avoiding pronouns that they find objectionable to find themselves being banned anyway if a moderator decides it's too "conspicuous".

Comment: @anaximander No, it doesn't contradict anything. That person could still be male or female, they simply asked you to use "xe" when referring to them. You don't know why. You don't know if it is because they are trans or non-binary, and so don't know if it violates any religious beliefs. I'm male, I'm not trans or non-binary, but still prefer people use gender neutral pronouns to refer to me because it's more welcoming to everyone in my opinion. You're making a religious argument where there isn't one.

Comment: @Baron The hypothetical religious person would have to maintain a level of deliberate ignorance for that sort of plausible deniability. If a person says "I'm non-binary, please use "xe" to refer to me" then it's kind of obvious, and frankly, the latter half of that sentence kind of implies the former. There *is* a religious argument here, and there are plenty of religious people here making it. Note that this very answer says *"PERSON 2 (me) - believes [...] that God made Man and Woman [...] I should not be pushed to use alternative pronouns which is contrary to the Bible."*

Comment: @anaximander If they have to maintain "deliberate ignorance" to treat another person with simple respect, then that's fine with me and I don't see an issue with that. The FAQ made it clear that religious objections to pronouns are not valid on SE, and I don't see anything wrong with that, so there's really no argument to be made here. Again, they're not being FORCED to do anything; they're free to simply not respond to people they aren't able to be nice to. Like your parents used to say: if you can't say anything nice then don't say anything at all!

Comment: @Baron Personally, I agree that correct pronouns should be used. I also believe that people should be allowed to practice their religion in peace as long as a basic "live and let live" policy is followed. The core of the issue is that there are mutually exclusive viewpoints: those who are gender-nonbinary, and those whose religion tells them that gender is binary. The problem is that SE is resolving this by taking a side, and basically telling people "you must act the way we think you should, and if your religion won't let you, shut up or go away" and I'm not comfortable with that.

Comment: @anaximander And I'm perfectly comfortable with that. If your religion tells you that you can't be non-binary, then don't be non-binary. That's your choice, you picked that religion, and you have that freedom. However, what **isn't** your choice is picking someone **else's** pronouns for them. It's disrespectful, it's rude, and if you can't be respectful, you don't have a place on SE. That's always been the case. It's not like non-binary people are telling this guy to change his religious beliefs or even challenging them simply by existing. Thou shalt love thy neighbor as thyself, right?

Comment: @JNat I don't take offense when people disagree with my religion. They do it all the time. This policy is a case in point. My question was if I used their name instead for the purpose of not offending my own conscience would that be wrong. Is it? Ending with, "Don't be rude" leaves me wondering if you are making a judgement or a suggestion. If someone is offended that I don't abandon my faith and speak contrary to Genesis 5:2 there is nothing I can do.

Comment: Did you read the answers to the other two questions I pointed to, @Bryan? They should answer you question, no? :)

Comment: @Baron All that is true, but it misses my point. I'm not saying they should get to choose other people's pronouns. I'm saying that there is a way that people whose religion holds that gender is binary can still participate politely - namely, by avoiding pronouns. My worry is that when people do so, intending to be civil and keep their religion to themselves, they'll get banned anyway for "conspicuously avoiding pronouns", at which point we've excluded someone who was trying to participate in good faith because of something they did for religious reasons. Which is not cool.

Comment: @anaximander Avoiding pronouns for specific people because you don't want to use their pronouns isn't good faith, nor is it "keeping religion to yourself". It's exactly the opposite; you're targeting and excluding someone because of their status as non-binary due to religious belief. If OP *truly* wanted to keep his religion to himself, this wouldn't even be a question. The "Implementation" FAQ #7 addresses this specifically: if you don't use pronouns for ANYONE, then that's fine, but singling out trans or non-binary people by avoiding only their pronouns is not acceptable (nor should it be).

Comment: @Baron I've already agreed that singling someone out to not get a pronoun is invalidating and disrespectful. The issue is that a) an answer that reads as perfectly respectful (but gender-neutral) on its own can still be flagged as disrespectful because "I looked at every post they ever wrote and they used pronouns for other people, so I'm clearly being singled out" when it might well be an honest slip, or just that they decided to start writing gender-neutrally at some point and haven't edited all their old posts, or some other innocent reason.

Comment: @anaximander And I have enough faith in the moderators that they can read a timestamp on old posts and realize that they were made prior to the COC change.

Comment: @Baron So you're saying that in order to assess a flag on a post, a moderator will now have to look through the user's entire post history to ascertain what their "normal" pattern of pronoun usage is? Can we not just judge a post by its content? That's my objection: a post that reads as respectful should be considered respectful. Moderators should not have to trawl a user's post history to gain sufficient context to determine whether an apparently-respectful post is in fact a CoC violation.

Comment: @anaximander Okay, now you're just making strawman arguments. A moderator would not have to look through their "entire post history" -- they'd simply need to check a few posts that were made post-COC change, see if the user in question uses pronouns for people who *aren't* trans or non-binary, and go from there. And if that means moderators have to actually check something before taking action on a user... so what? That's part of their job as a moderator. They're free to go back to resigning en masse like they were before if it's too much for them.

Comment: @Baron That's not a strawman, that's clearly implied by what's in the FAQ, and by what you've been saying: if you use pronouns, but avoid them for one person, then that's disrespectful to that one person... which means that in order to assess a flag, the moderator would have to look back through the user's post history. Perhaps not every post, but enough to establish a baseline for "normal". That's more work for moderators, more room for subjective judgements, and more thought-police-esque scrutiny for users. I agree with the motivations here, but the implementation is still imperfect.

Comment: @anaximander Yes, moderators might have to *perform moderator duties,* including checking someone's post history, in order to make a decision. I genuinely don't see anything wrong with that. That's part of the job. If this causes so much work that they can't handle it (which I really, really, really doubt), they can add another moderator.

Comment: @JNat - I apologize, for some reason my eyes jumped over the text above the box and just read what was in the box. This clarifies everything. 1. Yes I can hold my beliefs and respect others at the same time. 2 Yes I can choose to not use pronouns. This puts my mind at ease because I didn't want to loose the benefits of StackExchange/Overflow. For transgender people that read this: I do care for you and look forward to you sharing your intelligence and learning and hope I can reciprocate the favor!

Comment: Ones religious beliefs do not preclude one from using polite language and referring to people as they ask me to refer to them. My religious beliefs are actually against the Pro-Life message (due to a scripture and how it's been politically hijacked), but I still refer to them as a the Pro Life movement. Simply using a term out of politeness does not inherently mean that I agree said word is actually correct.

Comment: @Trikly equating the pro life movement to trans people is irresponsible and inaccurate. I'm as atheist as they come but I'm still on the side of this answer - you can't have equality if there are people "more equal than others".

Comment: @Qix Using this same logic, should someone whose religion says women aren't equal to men be allowed to be dismissive and rude to female users? Or are we supposed to tolerate some religions and not others? You can't have one without the other and still call it equality; you're condoning one religion and not the other, after all. If you validate OP's religion and allow him to use incorrect pronouns to hurt trans people intentionally, where do you draw the line?

Comment: @Baron That's false equivalence and thus is a fallacy.

Comment: @Qix That doesn't answer the question, nor does it make it go away. Where is the line drawn on religious objections? If you accept one, you have to accept the others, or it isn't equal.

Comment: @Baron: "The religion you picked" is as offensive to some faithful as "the gender you picked" is to some transgender, and for pretty much the same reason.

Comment: @rockwalrus I'm not going to get into a religious debate with someone. It goes against my faith.

Comment: @Baron: that's wise. Will you stop using that phrase?

Comment: @rockwalrus No. I chose my religion based on which faith aligned most with my ideals. I take no offense to someone saying I picked a religion -- because I did. Unlike transgender folk, who were born into it and were not given a choice.

Comment: @Baron: Interesting perspective. The number of people I've met that have expressed that people are born into a religion and cannot legitimately change it I can count on one hand, but most people I've met treat "picking a religion" like "picking the correct answer to a math problem", where the point is to decide what is true, not what is preferred. Regardless, you don't get to choose what is offensive to people, so to be consistent you should probably conclude that using that phrase is disrespectful and rude.

Comment: @Bryan I've intentionally left my beliefs about religion and gender identity out of my activity on Meta Stack Exchange, as I consider them as irrelevant to the conversation as my beliefs about gravity. I do agree with you that SE, Inc is pushing their views into people's faces while you were quietly living out your faith without pushing it into others, and I think they are being deliberately blind to the hurt that causes. Perhaps you were intending to tag Baron.

Comment: @Baron You have asserted your world view as being absolute fact, "Transgender folk... were born into it" and consequently by default saying the Bible and my faith is wrong. I would make the opposite statement and we would be at the same point in a reversed roll situation. The only difference though is that your view is being pushed into people's faces while I quietly lived out my faith without pushing it into yours (until i had to ask a clarifying question about the pronoun rules). Hmm. Forcing beliefs on someone and requiring them to abide by them. It is like a coerced atheist conversion

Comment: @JNat You quoted the wrong thing. You should have quoted 4. `You can often avoid using pronouns altogether. [..] But conspicuously avoiding using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others is a way of refusing to recognize their identity, and that is discriminatory.` This answers the concerns.

Comment: In other words, we must change the way talk. Either never use pronouns at all on SE, or use requested pronouns.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest clarifying the answer to Implementation, Q2 as follows:

**2. May I use they/them by default?**

**Yes.**

**Note that if someone subsequently requests that you use other pronouns, then "default" no longer applies, and you should adjust as requested.  If you continue to use they/them for that person, we may point it out to you.**

*Original text for comparison:*

*Yes, but be prepared to make adjustments if so requested. If someone requests that you use other pronouns and you immediately continue to use they/them for that person, we may point it out to you.*

Rationale:

"Yes, but" sends a confusing/mixed message. The original answer was trying to both answer the question as stated, *and* pre-emptively answer the unstated question of whether it's ok to *keep* using they/them after someone asks you to do otherwise. The proposed rewording directly answers the question that was actually asked; and frames the pre-emptive answer to the unstated question as a non-default case.

Answer (score 8):

### Avoidance of pronouns vs. gender-neutral language

There seems to be a self-contradiction here, and I'm concerned that it may trap well-meaning users into bans and other backlash.

> Prefer gender-neutral language when uncertain.
>
> *Code of Conduct*

Ok, this seems fine by itself. Except...

> ...conspicuously avoiding using pronouns is disrespectful.
>
> *[What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336367/218767), question M2*

So I should avoid pronouns, but only inconspicuously? What counts as "conspicuous"? I know the principle is "assume good intent", but as the recent days and weeks have shown, this is an emotionally-charged subject where people sometimes take knee-jerk reactions.

**What measures are in place to ensure that users who default to pronoun-free phrasing are not unfairly punished for the exact kind of disrespect they were attempting to avoid?**

Comment: This seems pretty related to this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336381/388335

Comment: In context, the second quote is talking about moderators avoiding *known* pronouns. Avoiding them when the user's pronouns are *unknown* is still fine. (But it probably wouldn't hurt to edit that clarification in.)

Comment: So now, along with the research I do to write answers, I have to research everything I can about the user asking the question in order to make sure that, if they've tucked away any "My pronouns are" statements, I've incorporated them everywhere I write anything for fear of being banned - instead of just writing gender neutral language in the first place?

Comment: @Qix See #11 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336365/627445): `11. Do I need to go looking for people's pronouns before interacting on Q&A?` In short, **no**. And you don't need to worry about suddenly getting banned for not knowing someone's pronouns (see #U2 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336367/627445)).

Answer (score 8):

One clarification given in comments on the old FAQ that I don't see explicitly addressed in the new FAQ is whether disengaging is permitted. I don't have the rep to see deleted questions, but if I remember the content of this comment correctly, [Catija wrote that silently disengaging is not inherently a CoC violation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes?cb=1#comment1098210_334901).

I think this might be a good thing to address to either the "implementation" or "edge cases" section. I don't actually know what the official policy, if any, would be, but here's some possible verbiage that I think matches the spirit of existing Q&A's:

> Q. Can I disengage from a thread if another participant's stated pronouns make me uncomfortable?
>
> A. You are never required to continue participating in any public conversation on the Stack Exchange network for any reason. Therefore, silently discontinuing posting in a thread is always an option. However, stating that your *reason* for disengaging is that you will not use another user's pronouns would be inappropriate, and may be considered a CoC violation.

I can also imagine that a user might develop a pattern of "ghosting" threads as soon as a request for a non-binary or unusual pronoun is made. I don't know if SE would automatically consider this a violation or not, or whether it would be worth addressing in the FAQ as an edge case.

> It's certainly not advisable or welcoming, and people shouldn't be campaigning/advocating for it. But, It is an option you have, and if you do so silently, that's unlikely to cause any trouble and be actionable for moderators. Cesar M♦

Comment: Maybe it would be better to say “rude” instead of “inappropriate” to make it clearer that it’s not about judging appropriate reasons to disengage, but instead that the point is that disengaging is fine – just don’t be a jerk about it!

Comment: @divibisan Hm - I meant it more as a statement about rules rather than a judgment about the "rightness" of the behavior. I wasn't sure how to phrase it, but I'm not sure whether or not "rude" is an improvement. (I did re-skim the FAQ to see how it phrased similar statements, but the closest I found was some verbiage about "respect".)

Comment: It's certainly not advisable or welcoming, and people shouldn't be campaigning/advocating for it. But, It is an option you have, and if you do so silently, that's unlikely to cause any trouble and be actionable for moderators.

Comment: @CesarM to be clear, it is not inherently rude (or at least the less rude option) to merely cease all interactions *immediately upon* the request to use neopronouns rather than to continue them, incorrectly? That seems to be very explicitly exclusive (ie. not inclusive), and perhaps in breach of "conspicuously" avoiding neopronouns for those requested. This feels like a dangerous precedent to set.

Comment: AFAIK this option has been explicitly ruled out for moderators, the answer only applies to users.But for users, yes, I think it's a great option and I don't have a problem with ghosting. IMO the dominant use case is going to be users who are somewhat abrasive but occasionally useful and losing them isn't going to bother me. I may even make pronoun requests deliberately.

Answer (score 8):

> **M2. I'm a moderator. I often have to refer to other users, I can't choose which ones I have to refer to, and often it isn't feasible to avoid pronouns. So do I really have to use pronouns I find uncomfortable?**
>
> Yes

I read this as "compelled speech" for moderators -- i.e., "*yes*, moderators really *do* have to use pronouns even if they did find that uncomfortable".

Speech isn't so compelled for users -- who, per the "Is there really no alternative?" question, might be allowed to avoid talking about 3rd parties altogether, and/or avoid using pronouns.

Unless you take a "don't ask, don't tell policy" with moderators (i.e. so moderators don't have to declare whether they're willing to) -- which, I'd guess you will -- I read this as saying that moderators are now officially required (by SE) to be willing to use pronouns and neopronouns and that their not being willing to would be contrary to the CoC.

---

People have contradicted this "bright line" and equivocated on this subject before, posting comments to say that moderators aren't compelled -- with other people posting other comments to contradict that -- which I found to be obfuscation and therefore slightly annoying and a waste of time.

The lack of clarity on that specific subject seemed deceptive, wishy-washy or incompetent -- how could you not be clear?

Still it seems to be clear now.

Unless you change that "Yes" there to a "No" -- which you haven't -- I don't see another way to read it.

Comment: Is it "compelled speech" when you're required by your job to say "May I take your order" or "Thank you, come again"? Is having to address someone as "Mr. ___" or use "sir" and "ma'am" compelled speech? If not, then why is having to use the right pronoun compelled speech? On the other hand, if it is compelled speech, then it would seem not all forms of compelled speech are inherently bad.

Comment: The mods here are volunteers who signed up to do a job, and part of that job requires them to use people's preferred pronouns. If they do not want to, they can quit. Fortunately, I haven't seen any mods quite for that reason, so that suggests this isn't an issue for most mods. (They have quit due to how Monica was treated, but that's not the same thing as quitting because they have to use required pronouns.)

Comment: "Compelled" and "required" are synonyms IMO. And apparently that "job" does now require the use of neopronouns on request -- that requirement wasn't explicit before.

Comment: If a mod never uses a neopronoun and has in the past expressed a reluctance to normalize those pronouns by using them, would that mod be operating under a cloud of suspicion because every time they had the opportunity to phrase something so they could refer to someone with their pronoun they choose a different phrasing? If a mod uses singular they instead of stated pronouns in a private moderator room where the person they are referring to will never know about it, would they violate policy? Can we ask without getting marked as a potential dissident (aka bigot)? I don’t know.

Comment: @ColleenV My *guess* is that it will be "don't ask, don't tell" -- i.e. if you want to resign on principle you can, otherwise SE won't ask, and it probably won't be an issue in the normal course of discourse (unless you engage in discourse on that subject, possibly in TL). Perhaps there'd be an Inquisition only if somebody denounces you officially for your pronoun usage. I guess SE will want this to blow over (unless they reckon this is fun or good publicity), hope they've made a clear policy, and that the one person directly/immediately affected by this policy-as-stated might be Monica still.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1392/discussion-between-chrisw-and-colleenv).

Comment: @trikly Yes, of course those are all compelled speech: they are things someone is forced to say under threat of punishment. The difference is that compelled speech is an expected element of customer service work, whereas it was not an expected element of volunteer moderation on this site. (Personally, I think it's okay for sites to change their moderation requirements, which is what's happening here, but I think it's clearly true that the compelled speech in this instance is not something that current moderators expected when they originally volunteered.)

Answer (score 7):

I think these two entries would be easier to understand if examples of sites within SE network where these adjustments are relevant are provided.

> #### 1. Am I forbidden to express my opinion about this?
>
> In most contexts, your opinions about gender are off-topic. **Some of our sites** may have topics where gender is part of the subject and may be a valid question for the experts on that site. When answering these questions, it is important that answers report an objective answer to the question and avoid conveying the author's opinions on the subject. Since these objective answers may be at odds with the Code of Conduct, please take special care and frame them respectfully and politely — please be aware that many things you might want to say may be extremely distressing to some readers, and try to minimize that distress.

and

> #### U4. If someone puts their pronouns into a question they're asking, should we leave that in or edit it out as noise?
>
> Add a comment noting what they said and suggesting that they could comment on the question/answer next time. Edit it out of the question as you would with "Hi" and "Thanks". Because you've made their request less visible, keep an eye out for mistakes in answers and comments and consider making polite corrections. Note: **on some sites** stating one’s pronouns may be vital information for the question being asked, so don’t remove them in those cases.

Currently I have to guess where the adjustments apply and where they don't.

Comment: Interpersonal Skills is an obvious example, but it is not the company's place to dictate on which sites gender issues may or may not be on-topic. That should be up to the community behind each of those sites. It's also not a hard-and-fast rule (site scope can and does change over time, and it is dependent on the question itself). I don't see why it would be especially beneficial to make this explicit. Use your common sense. The point of the "some of our sites" exception is to allow that there *are* edge cases, not to exhaustively enumerate places where gender identity is and is not on-topic.

Comment: IPS definitely for U4 - we often need to refer to people, and always using names can be clunky. Religious sites might be a better example for 1: it's not okay to say "I'm religious and I think [demographic] is wrong", but (if on topic) you could say "Prominent Religious Writing is widely interpreted to say [demographic] is wrong" - I believe most? all? such sites already have rules like this anyways.  If you encounter a pronoun/gender-related issue on a site you're not very familiar with, and can't tell from their on-topic page, you could always ask on their meta.

Comment: Catija mentioned on [a comment on another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336366/post-for-clarifications-on-the-updated-pronouns-faq/336370#comment1112995_336370) that the goal of the first part was to prevent editorializing. If gender is relevant to the question, that’s fine, just don’t stick your personal opinions where it’s not relevant

Answer (score 7):

> 7. This seems like a small thing to make a fuss over.
>
>    > While on its surface it may seem like a small thing, we should keep in mind that for some people it's important and significant as it speaks to how they are respected and viewed. It can convey far more than a mere linguistic choice.

Equally, for some people it is important and significant in that they cannot morally accept gender-fluidity or refer to people using pronouns they perceive to be invalid.

I accept that in most cases the issue can be avoided, but I did see it written somewhere - I apologise, I cannot see where, maybe someone can aid me - that if a user specifically asks you to refer to them by a specific pronoun, you may not avoid this. I have never understood how your pronoun is relevant to your question but that aside, if this is the rule then you are clearly prioritising one group over another.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't see it in the current FAQ you probably just ran across misinformed comments. Implementation 7: "Am I obligated to find opportunities to use pronouns? Not at all!"

Comment: It is in the _answer_ section of the top-rated answer to this question. It mentions _"a user who asked you to refer to them with a neopronoun"_

Comment: I see, you should [edit] that link and quote the part you're concerned about in here then so people know what you're talking about.

Comment: Only moderators are not given the option to disengage. As a user you are free to disengage. What you mustn’t do is use the wrong pronoun once you’ve been made aware of the correct pronouns.

Comment: This post could be improved by explaining why "prioritising one group over another" is a bad thing. The rules also prioritise female users over users who cannot morally accept women who use computers.

Comment: @ColleenV "Free to disengage" is a fancy way of saying that those who are unable to accept non-binary gender have no option but to stop participating, which only supports the point. I'm just pointing out that there are two groups, and SE is stating that in order to be more inclusive, one of these groups will be excluded. I don't want to debate which group is right or wrong, or whether SE is right or wrong to do this. I just want them to stop denying that they're doing it, and acknowledge the impact it might have.

Comment: @anaximander I wasn’t making a statement about whether it should or shouldn’t be that way; I was just noting how it is. I think it’s fairly obvious from the FAQ that if someone is unable to participate without making folks who identify as non-binary feel excluded, then their participation is not welcome. If it’s not obvious that someone believes there are only two genders, then that someone is free to participate so long as it stays that way.

Comment: @ColleenV That's my point. One could just as easily say "if someone is unable to participate without making folks who hold certain religious views feel excluded, then their participation is not welcome". There are two mutually-incompatible views, and SE has chosen one that they wish to protect. That's their prerogative and I'm not commenting on whether or not it's the right decision, but it annoys me when they try to pretend that it's not going to exclude anyone. I get that when there are contradictory views, you kinda have to pick one - I just wish they'd acknowledge that they're doing so.

Answer (score 7):

Why not stick to simply dictating behavior ("don't be disrespectful to each other or intentionally misgender anyone")?

I think that this policy is overly complicated for what it's trying to accomplish. Why not just have something like the following alternate version instead?

> We're trying to make the site welcoming and inclusive to everyone. Sometimes, transgender members have been made to feel unsafe and/or unwelcome. To help everyone be able to participate in the community equally, please ensure that you either use people's preferred pronouns or write in a gender-neutral way for everyone.
>
> If uncertain of the individual's gender, please prefer gender-neutral language rather than assuming a particular gender.
>
> Controversies regarding gender identity are, in general, out of scope for the site. Please refrain from arguing or debating with other users related to this topic.
>
> Rude or discriminatory behavior based on gender identity will not be tolerated. If you see someone engage in this type of behavior, please flag the comment(s) in question as "Harassment, Bigotry, or Abuse." Violations of this policy will result in a warning from moderators, and continued violations after that will result in suspension.

Answer (score 6):

### A few tweaks, and this CoC change could be beneficial to numerous minority groups across SE

It's stated:

> #### 1. Am I forbidden to express my opinion about this?
>
> ... please take
>   special care and frame [objective answers] **respectfully and politely** — *please be
>   aware that many things you might want to say may be extremely
>   distressing to some readers, and try to minimize that distress.*
>
> #### 8. Isn't all this causing lots of inconvenience to everyone for the sake of a minority?
>
> No. One thing is required of you: that when
>   someone states their pronouns you **take notice and respect their
>   request**...
>
> #### M1. I'm a moderator. What should I do if I see these rules being broken?
>
> **If someone makes an honest mistake**, you could point it out
>   gently...
>
> ***But if someone knows and is refusing*** to
>   [make an adjustment], treat this as you would any other case where someone is
>   deliberately breaking the CoC.
>
> #### 2. But the free choice of language is important to me. This rule impairs my freedom of speech.
>
> By participating here **you're agreeing to
>   treat others with politeness**...
>
> #### U2. I'm worried that I may get banned. Should I be?
>
> Not if you're
>   acting **in good faith**...

---

This CoC change could be boiled down to locating bad actors, and dealing with them appropriately, while also asking our users to be polite and respectful when utilising this platform.

There was an anecdote I saw the other day about a uniform policy, whereby there were pages of banned items. A review happened and it was cut down to two words: "Dress appropriately".

The employees were free to manage their own dress code, felt less restricted, and it allowed the community to self-regulate - often bringing about the same result as when they were under the pages of rules.

I'd suggest that we increase the scope of this CoC change, opening up the community to be able to voice reasonable suggestions to other users to allow any user to feel welcome here.

---

My suggested amendments can be summed up to two points, and the points could be treated as complimentary to the FAQ (which is, in effect, a terser ruleset on how these points are enforced)

> #### 1. Presume Good Intent
>
> Make the assumption that someone is meaning well, because the majority
>   of users are attempting to respond to your queries and feedback
>   politely. Correct them with that in mind (if you feel something needs to be said) and then move back on topic.
>
> However, if you believe there is enough evidence to suggest that someone may be a bad actor (*even in the first instance*), flag the comment/post/question that
>   concerns you most and a moderator will review your feedback and take
>   appropriate action
>
> #### 2. Be Polite
>
> Keep in mind that our users come from all over the globe and have many
>   different life experiences - not all of them good.
>
> We'd like users to feel welcome here and as such, if a user requests
>   for a reasonable adjustment to be made to allow them to feel more
>   welcome, we ask that you try your best to accommodate the requested
>   change.
>
> If you aren't comfortable with making that change, try your best to
>   continue responding to that users points (keeping on topic) and take
>   appropriate steps if you feel like you can't do so in a respectful and
>   considerate manner (stop responding to that user and/or flag if there
>   is good reason to)

---

This will improve upon the original "assume good intent" that had previously been abused, and how the suggestion is worded, it could help the entire community, including lavender community, who (having been singled out by the changes) have been made targets by the last round of proposed changes.

It will be able to be used by people who are requesting that people be patient with their English, to those with autism who experience compulsive and repetitive behaviours that may be the reason they take a while to respond, and other minority groups who are not already catered for by the proposed changes, as well as being a sort of summary of the proposed changes.

It leaves enough open to interpretation to be useful to more than just one subsection of the community, restricts the abilities of bad actors to abuse the new rules, reiterates that individuals always have the right to remove themselves from a situation they no longer want to be part of or request aid from a moderator - reinforcing the idea that the community is trusted to make self-regulatory decisions in a fair way, and covers the communities that aren't already covered by this new CoC change.

Comment: See [We need “assume good intent” back in the Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335026/we-need-assume-good-intent-back-in-the-code-of-conduct).

Comment: We must assume that SE *deliberately* removed "assume good intent" from the CoC. To understand *why* they might have done that, see [Kate Gregory's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335130/170084) to [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335026/we-need-assume-good-intent-back-in-the-code-of-conduct) question. She provides a link to [an article](https://thebias.com/2017/09/26/how-good-intent-undermines-diversity-and-inclusion/) that shows *why* some people think that "assume good intent" is problematic.

Comment: The directive "Assume good intent" is unintentionally proliferating systemic discrimination. To deal with systemic discrimination (such as misgendering, microagressions and related problems), a clear set of rules is necessary. That doesn't mean that assuming good intent goes out the window, it just means that it's not a suitable prime directive to adress the issues that the code of conduct is intended to adress.

Comment: Presume good faith is different from assume good faith. Presumption is the assumption while a lack of evidence exists. **I do not state that it should be put in instead of the proposed changes**, the rules are complimentary. Assume that a potential slip up is a slip up. If it continues and there is reason to believe it is intentional, something should be done about it. Nowhere in my answer did I mention "assumption of good faith" other than in that context.

Comment: A specific FAQ has been proposed to help those who are in the lavender community, and this proposal is to add in two segments to help those who are in other minority communities, while we figure out the specifics for them

Comment: "There was an anecdote I saw the other day about a uniform policy, whereby there were pages of banned items. A review happened and it was cut down to two words: "Dress appropriately"." That sounds like a nightmare. How am I supposed to know what they think 'dressing appropriately' means?

Comment: @EttinaKitten it’s what you feel is best for the situation you’re going to be in. If colleagues usually wear formal wear, do the same, same for casual, or even fancy dress. It’s about being able to have a stab at what’s appropriate, and being ready to change if your colleagues (or in this case, fellow contributors) let you know that something isn’t quite right. I’m also not suggesting that this goes in place of the current CoC changes. It’s intended as an addition to cover other user groups that haven’t had an FAQ section to clarify how to approach their conduct related suggestions in comments

Answer (score 6):

This is much better.

I would prefer it if it had a reminder that somebody who goes overboard correcting someone on these issues is still subject to "be nice", and if there were some language saying that users who see an existing comment train on the issues should probably do nothing other than flagging, as the behavior is already dealt with.

As I've said before, my biggest concerns are workflow issues, and the new FAQ removes this concern, and "third person in the fight" issues. New FAQ is better in that regard, as I thought the original FAQ came close to actively encouraging people to jump in,  but I'd prefer active discouragement.

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR: Is secretly modifying a user's profile, exposing personal information on anonymous profiles, a just and proportionate punishment for (alleged) CoC violation?

---

To quote, emphasis mine:

> M1. I'm a moderator. What should I do if I see **these rules** being
>   broken?
>
> If someone makes an honest mistake, you could point it out **gently**. (Or
>   let the person in question do it. If it seems likely that they would
>   prefer that.) But if someone **knows** *and* is refusing to comply, treat
>   this as you would any other case where someone is deliberately
>   breaking the CoC.

A user's profile page had been modified by a Stack Exchange staff member to remove mentions of said user's pronouns, and in doing so, the user's personal information has been exposed on profiles which were originally anonymous. See [My profile's about me randomly changed across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338188/259700).

Under my interpretation of the FAQ(*), the reason behind this is that the staff member had decided that the said pronouns are a violation of point 8 of section ["What's this all about? - Implementation"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336365/259700). (Whether the decision is correct is not the scope of this post.)

This means at least one of the following conclusions must be true:

1. M1 applies to moderators only and not to Stack Exchange staff members. Stack Exchange staff members are allowed to be as *ungentle* as they want to be.
2. Stack Exchange considers the act of modifying a user's profile page, without the consent of the user (not even the knowledge of the user), a *gentle* act. And that they have "pointed it out" by not informing the user.
3. Stack Exchange thinks that the user *knows* the rules are being broken by using some unusual pronouns. Without informing or discussing with the user, Stack Exchange thinks that the user is omniscient enough to just *know* that.
4. The official FAQ is not defined to be part of "*these rules*", "*these rules*" is defined to be the CoC only. Thus, violations of other rules, such as rules listed in the FAQ but not in the CoC itself, can be dealt with in whatever way Stack Exchange wants to.

So, I would like Stack Exchange to clarify: which of my conclusion(s) is/are true?

---

Note: For completeness, logically there is one more option: that my assumption in (*) is wrong. In which case would Stack Exchange please explain why the user's pronouns were removed from the profile page?

Comment: Regarding last paragraph: we don't need a public statement about the reason for moderator action against a specific user (especially if the user has twice emphasized desires for privacy). I think the linked question needs more clarification, but I guess I would need to write my own answer to argue it.

Answer (score 6):

(I hope this is still the right place to ask what the right course of action would be.)

---

EDIT: Well, seems like it is not? This is a genuine question, and it's been almost two months since I asked it, and I've yet to receive an answer.

Could any mod or CM please look into it? Thanks.

---

I've been using "singular they" in English-speaking sites, like Reddit and StackOverflow, for ages now — well before any pronoun controversy arose here. I use *they*, *their* and *them*; and I used *themselves* too... until I learned that ***[themself](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/themself)*** is just as valid and more clearly conveys that I am referring to one singular person (it's called "*singular* they" for something, right?) and not some other plural group that may also be included in the sentence. So nowadays what I use by default is *they*, *their*, *them* and *themself*.

However, let's say there's one user whose pronouns, as specified in their profile, are: `they, them, their,`*`themselves`*.
So **question 1, general case**:

1. **Would it be a CoC violation to use *themself* instead of *themselves* when talking about users who specifically mention *themselves* as their self-pronoun?**

Now, I've known and interacted with a user like this for some years now. They told me long ago, in private, that they'd rather be addressed as *they* instead of *he* or *she*, and that's what I've been doing. They didn't want to be public about it, but recently they found the courage (way to go! ) to specify their pronouns in their profile for everybody to see.
The thing is... We've actually discussed this "*themself* vs. *themselves*" issue before, and they told me that they use *themselves* because they believe *themself* to be **grammatically** incorrect.
So, **question 2, specific case**:

2. Would it be a CoC violation if I used *themself* instead of *themselves* when talking about users who I know (for a fact, because they told me so) that their reasons to state *themselves* as their self-pronoun are grammar-related instead of gender-related?
   In other words: **if a user asked me to use *themselves* instead of *themself* when talking about them, not because they feel misgendered but because they think it's not grammatically correct, would I be breaking the CoC if I kept using *themself*?**

---

Mind you, I don't really have a problem with using *themselves* instead of *themself* with this or that particular user if they ask me to. It's all about being nice, after all. But it'd bother me if they tried to *force* me to do so *for reasons that were not what the CoC is there to protect*.

If the CoC could be used to force me to employ a standard pronoun because of some user saying the one I'm using is not grammatical, that'd be... mind-blowingly ironic.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for this vast improvement of the FAQ.  I found your first attempt at the FAQ to be very confused and self-contradictory.  This is much less so.

There is an answer in implementation that is still too vague.  I hope you can remove the ambiguity.

> 5. **If someone is non-binary, does it really matter whether I call them "ey" or "they" or "xe" or some other gender-neutral pronoun? Do I have to handle dozens of different pronouns?**
>
>    Many non-binary people will be OK with whatever non-binary pronoun you use for them - however, if they have stated one, use the one they have stated.

I'm not sure what this answer is telling me.  Is it *"Why don't you start by using singular they?  A lot of people will be OK with that."*?  I think the sentence up to and including the "however" just adds confusion.  My personal phrasing in answer to that question would be: *"If someone has asserted that their pronouns are 'xe' or 'ey', it must truly matter to that person.  Please be respectful, and accommodate that assertion."*

Answer (score 5):

> Here's the place to post your requests for clarification/new questions.

Q: *What happens when someone is genuinely against using non-binary pronouns?*

Are their rights revoked in favour of the CoC "enforcing" the usage of someone's preferred pronoun?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1446/discussion-on-answer-by-james-post-for-clarifications-on-the-updated-pronouns-fa).

Answer (score 4):

> 6. What if someone wants some nonstandard pronouns that I don't even know how to use?
>
> Then just do your best. Again, honest mistakes are fine. If you are directly corrected, adjust moving forward. If you're not sure how to form that pronoun, you may find guidance here. If you're struggling, that's common. It can take a little effort but it's appreciated.

As I used to be active mostly on SO, I would rather focus on question one asks, not on searching for rules of some pronoun usage. If I decide to still contribute, my options are either try to avoid the difficult pronoun or give up answering to persons requiring such pronouns.
The first option is clearly against:

> 4. I find it really distressing to use pronouns in a way I think is wrong. Is there really no alternative?
>
> You can often avoid using pronouns altogether. It's actually pretty rare to need third-person pronouns at all on most Stack Exchange sites. But conspicuously avoiding using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others is a way of refusing to recognize their identity, and that is discriminatory. Please don’t do that.

So do you accept the second option? Do you consider it improvement?

Comment: Avoiding people is worse.

Comment: You also have the option to try and correct if someone corrects you. It's pretty rare that third-person pronouns will come up when *answering* a question anyway.

Comment: @CesarM - dismissing people's valid concerns on the "it's rare" is rather disingenuous (never mind a logical fallacy), since this WHOLE issue was over something that's pretty rare, and your desired solution being the preferred solution is even rarer.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus - avoiding people is better, as per official SE position twitted by their employee.

Comment: `or give up answering to persons requiring such pronouns` If people begin to get suspensions or bans for this, this is the trend SO will go. Stack doesn't seem to understand this - by compelling speech, you're going to force users away.

Comment: @Qix I think they understand just fine. Someone not using the correct pronouns at all is already not desired, but merely tolerated. It is a compromise to avoid getting rid of people who are willing to have their beliefs but not push them onto others. If that compromise is not good enough for them, then it's perfectly acceptable for them not to post. The goal is to make this a more trans friendly community, and if that means losing some people, that is acceptable. Such is always the tradeoff when making new rules--those who can't stand them will leave.

Answer (score 4):

The point I made in [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335311/164922) to the unofficial FAQ proposal still stands: if you want to communicate clearly, you should avoid or define neologisms. In particular, in "Edge cases",

> #### 2. But the free choice of language is important to me. This rule impairs my freedom of speech.
>
> By participating here you're agreeing to treat others with politeness. That includes not insulting people (even if you sincerely think ill of them, and even if you're right). It also includes not intentionally misgendering them.

the word "*misgendering*" will be new to many native speakers, not to mention non-native speakers. It shouldn't be necessary to guess its meaning from context. **The code of conduct and its FAQ should be clearly understood by everyone with a working grasp of English (say, Cambridge First Certificate), not just a subset of native speakers.**

Answer (score 4):

> **May I use they/them by default?**
>
> Yes, but be prepared to make
>   adjustments if so requested. If someone requests that you use other
>   pronouns and you immediately continue to use they/them for that
>   person, we may point it out to you.

This is silly. The whole point of using a genderless pronoun like 'they' is to avoid misgendering and the discussion about it. It's like using [UGT](http://www.total-knowledge.com/~ilya/mips/ugt.html) when you enter a chatroom. To demand that users change commonly accepted genderless pronouns to something else isn't really helping anyone, is it? It only adds noise.

If it becomes so important to use that right pronoun that the genderless version won't do anymore, you might as well demand someone who managed to construct a sentence without pronouns to rewrite it to contain your specific pronouns.

Comment: It doesn't seem that silly to me. If I kept referring to someone as a "they", and that same user came to me and requested to be referred to as "she", it seems kind of imprudent to continue to use the word "they" toward that user.

Comment: In a more familiar environment, yes. But in the concrete, informational, noise-free Q&A setup that SE is trying to be, where even greetings are removed from questions and answers, because they would add noise, I think that shouldn't be asked in the first place.

Comment: UGT is a continually moving UTC that's always -8 hours out relative to the subject. :-p  (This may be an even more appropriate analogy than it first appears! :-p)

Comment: The request may add noise, but actually changing the pronoun does not, since there apparently needs to be a pronoun there anyways. And it's perfectly find to have noise in comments--it's just that they may be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 4):

- I would like to get clarification about what SO, the company, is doing to prevent external targeting of users revealing their pronouns, especially if they belong to a minority. Is there any plan to work to together with local authorities and hand over collected evidences? Are users actively informed about the risks? Is there some kind of process in place how to deal with such cases or only reasonable suspicion of such cases?

(I'm aware that the means are rather limited, but it's probably better to think about it before and not after the fact. A quick but temporary hide/change/anonymization of user contributions might be some idea, for example.)

- While the expectation is clearly not to check the user profile of every interaction partner before starting a communication, doing so would surely increase the success rate of used pronouns. However, it would also be impractical. Please consider a better UI process that provides the required information more readily. Similar matter is that probably not many people will read the commentary to the CoC unless you notify them about it. Maybe it should become a notification similar to the recent podcast notifications.
- Maybe and despite of the public interest, the new FAQ could further be shortened a bit. The more text there is the less likely it is that somebody reads it all. At the very least, some summary of the FAQ (a few bullet points with the gist of it) might be good.

Comment: "The expectation seems to be to check the user profile of every interaction partner before starting a communication." - the FAQ says otherwise: "11. Do I need to go looking for people's pronouns before interacting on Q&A? No, that is not required. [...]"

Comment: Question 11 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336365/208518) clearly states you're not expected to go check users' profiles, etc., for pronouns before interacting.

Comment: @JNat and npostavs. You're absolutely right. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 4):

> 8. Isn't all this causing lots of inconvenience to everyone for the sake of a minority?
>
> > No. One thing is required of you: that when someone states their pronouns you take notice and respect their request. We also recommend that you don't make assumptions about people's gender and that you prefer gender-neutral language when unsure. Using gender-neutral language instead of default masculine makes the content here inclusive of everyone, including both female and trans users.

1. Surely it self evident from all the turmoil, particularly on meta and amongst moderators, that all this *is* causing lots of inconvenience?
2. And surely there is little debate that only a minority of users are concerned about use of their or others' pronouns in the first place (I have no idea if users ever asked for this initially or not, perhaps someone can clarify).

So to simply answer "no" doesn't seem very open-minded. It sounds to me more like the position has been decided and anyone who disagrees is just wrong, in SE's eyes.

Comment: The question was asked in a way it would be easy to answer "No". It states the combination of (1) inconvenience (2) lots of it and (3) for the sake of a minorty.

Answer (score 3):

What does "stated pronoun **(if known)**" mean, and does "general knowledge" from U1 apply?

There are many cases where someone's pronouns could be argued as "publicly known" / "general knowledge", but grepping the string on the FAQ, as it is currently written, only gives U1: "I'm not a moderator. What should I do if I see these rules being broken?" Can I apply public / general knowledge when creating new content, or does the principle of public / general knowledge only apply if one sees the rules being broken?

If not, then, what does "if known" mean? Do the pronouns need to be explicitly stated by the person, or can it be inferred from existing official documents? I.e., are the pronouns only known when the person state "please refer to me with the pronoun $pronoun", or is it OK to refer to the current Queen of England as "she" because I know she owns a ship called [**Her** Majesty's Ship *Belfast*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Belfast) (and because I'm inferring from her title as the Queen)?

Looking forward, if I were to discuss certain government departments in the future, where the British monarch may have been changed, and I do not know the gender of this future monarch, can I still use, say, [HM Passport Office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM_Passport_Office), with the HM assumed to mean "His/Her"? Or do I have to start calling it "TM Passport Office" for "Their Majesty's", which at present is not the actual name of this department?

Comment: I think the policy is mostly meant for talking about other users of the site, not about public figures.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - It's part of the Code of Conduct, which [applies to talking about non-users as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286082/does-the-be-nice-policy-require-se-users-to-be-nice-to-people-who-are-not-se-u) ("Be Nice" = the CoC).

Answer (score 3):

How does the new pronoun policy apply to non-living objects?

Traditionally certain kinds of objects are typically associated with some gendered pronouns. For example, "she" is typically used when referring to [ships](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15178/using-she-pronoun-to-refer-to-a-ship) and [countries](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204217/using-her-vs-its-to-refer-to-a-country).

Under the new CoC, can I still use "she" in these cases?

Comment: Yes, but if the ship or country states a preference for a different pronoun, you must use that pronoun in the future.

Comment: @fixer1234 to be clear, I would be correct in non-conspicuously using gender neutral terms for *all* ships and countries, if I should have some objection to gendering ships and/or countries? Do ships and/or countries (etc.) fall under singular they?

Answer (score 3):

If person1 sees person2 use certain pronouns for person3, but person2 doesn't explicitly state that they are the preferred pronouns for person3, what happens?

If person1 uses the same pronouns person2 used, because person1 believed in good faith that they were the correct pronouns, but it turns out they were the incorrect pronouns, will person1 be treated as engaging in misconduct?

If person1 thinks that person2 wasn't using the correct pronouns, and decides to use different pronouns, or avoids pronouns, will they be treated as wilfully misgendering person3 because they had been "told" what pronouns to use for person3?

In addition, does any of this change if person2 is a moderator?

(This is a real life scenario I dealt with recently - a moderator used male pronouns about a person, and then it turned out to be a "generic he" rather than "I know this person's preferred pronouns he".)

This may be technically two concerns, but if so, they're very closely related.

Answer (score 3):

**Why this fixation on pronouns and not misgendering in general**

Consider this comment exchange:

> Hi, I'm Jane Doe (known as John before my operation), and a mother of 2 children. Having worked in the police I can vouch it is safe to send a child to school I'm Boston without an assault rifle in the backpack.

Answering comment:

> Hello **Mr. John** Doe, thanks for taking the trouble to comment despite your condition, **Sir**. So **John** thinks being a **father** and a **policeman** is sufficient to give us *her* parenting advice, but I think *she* should figure out her identity first before giving advice to others.

Beside the fake politeness and the anti-trans contents, this shows all the other obvious words that can be used for misgendering, staying inside the confines of the current CoC.

Misgendering is not just about pronouns, so why that fixation on those?

Answer (score 2):

You advise that questions and answers should be free of references to pronouns.

**Do you plan on introducing a feature for making one's pronouns more accessible?**

I mean by this, for example, a colored dot near the avatar or an expandable card with a visual cue when there is something to expand.

Comment: This is not answered by the FAQ, but Stack has previously implied that there are some legal implications to this and they may not introduce an official feature for this purpose.

Comment: @Aza Well I thought it was on topic, how we interact with a rule is closely tied with how that rule is accessible.

Comment: Oh, don't worry, I definitely think it's on topic, I'm just not sure an FAQ can really answer it. But it's a useful question and worth answering here, anyway.

Comment: @Aza do you have a link where SE implied that? I expected some UI support for pronouns, at least a field where one can write own preferred pronouns.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken @Aza is referring to [this comment by Cesar M](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336366/post-for-clarifications-on-the-updated-pronouns-faq/336378#comment1113050_336378)

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek I would prefer a tag. Something like `[they:@Arthur Havlicek]`, but it will be long to write.

Comment: @aloisdg: So what if a user changes his name? `[they:<userid>]`? Nobody's gonne check a user's ID to write a tag to automate one of several forms of pronouns... It's easier to avoid pronoun usage in sentence structure altogether.

Comment: There is a userscript that adds this feature: https://stackapps.com/q/8440/34061

Comment: Legally they can't recommend the feature, but I don't think they'd get into legal trouble simply for providing it, as I know of many, many GPDR compliant sites that allow you to OPTIONALLY display your gender in a special place, or to have badges that happen to include gender or preferred pronouns as an option. I suspect that they are just being overly cautious right now, since there is no such feature on SE yet.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this vast improvement of the FAQ.  I found your first attempt at the FAQ to be very confused and self-contradictory.  This is much less so.

There is an answer in implementation that is still too vague.  I hope you can remove the ambiguity.

> **10. I want to let people know what my pronouns are. What should I do?**
>
> How (and whether) you identify your pronouns is up to you. In many cases it's unnecessary. Please don’t put pronouns in your posts unless it’s somehow relevant.

One of the biggest problems with the previous FAQ is that it did not provide good guidance on this question, and in fact recommended filling posts with clutter.  I'm glad you're taking a stand and saying that pronouns don't belong in the question (with exception of certain sites where it's relevant).

But the FAQ isn't "What shouldn't I do?", but "What *should* I do?"  This answer has to assert a solution to that question.

From what I've seen in answers to other questions (and implied in FAQ Implementation 11), it seems you want the OP to put their pronouns in the comments.  If that's the case, it should be stated plainly in this answer to the FAQ.  Perhaps: *"How (and whether) you identify your pronouns is up to you.  Please don't put pronouns in your questions unless it's relevant to the question.  If you want to post your pronouns, the comments section is the most appropriate place."*

Comment: There's no reason to present them until necessary. When it is necessary, it will be obvious where they should be presented.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for taking the time, effort and, to at least a certain extent humility, to listen to our feedback and make these changes. I believe they are an improvement compared to the original version of the FAQ.

In the [But what about...? The edge cases.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336369/562482) #4, there is

> You can often avoid using pronouns altogether. It's actually pretty rare to need third-person pronouns at all on most Stack Exchange sites. But conspicuously avoiding using pronouns for one group of people while using them normally for others is a way of refusing to recognize their identity, and that is discriminatory. ...

This doesn't specify any groups or people it only applies to, so I assume it applies to everyone, in particular it appears to allow members to completely avoid using pronouns. However, in the [So, as a curator or moderator, what's my role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336367/562482) M2, there is

> Using incorrect pronouns or conspicuously avoiding using pronouns is disrespectful. ... If you think you will find using pronouns as stated difficult, please try.

To me, not using pronouns at all is about as conspicuous as you can get. This seems to state the earlier statement doesn't apply to moderators, so they *have* to use pronouns. If this is not the case, then this section should be reworded. I suggest adding an initial clarification to the first sentence above so it would be something like

> Unless you're not using pronouns at all, using incorrect pronouns or conspicuously avoiding using pronouns is disrespectful.

Alternatively, if the earlier part doesn't apply to moderators, you should make that explicit there. However, I wish & hope that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a CoC violation if I use "this user" or "you", which are gender neutral non-pronouns and not the non-formally accepted made-up<sup>✽</sup> form of the singular "they", and **more neutral** than gendered pronouns, **even after** an adjustment is requested?

<sup>✽ (Please see OED References at the end of this post.)</sup>

Me as a user who is here to contribute by answering questions and responding to requests for clarifications is completely disinterested in choosing pronouns that differ from person to person. Even if someone asks to be referred to as "xe", I don't find it necessary to follow suit **when my content does not address a user, but all future readers**.

I understand that this may come across as passive-aggressive, but it is not my intention and I doubt will be considered offensive to any other person under the context of reasonable discourse. Is this still a violation or must I follow pronouns as requested even when I wouldn't need to as is?

### Patterns of comments I've made that are similar to "this user" which I think are not passive-aggressive and are not "they"

> "the user":
>   As a solution, the user should use Arrays.<Double>asList. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40880006/3622940#comment68975219_40880322)
>
> "the OP":
>   This preserves numbers, where OP wants to only preserve letters and angular brackets. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27790676/3622940#comment43992442_27790741)
>   This doesn't preserve letters as asked by OP. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27790676/3622940#comment43992428_27790734)
>
> "the poster":
>   Mandatory link for poster: youmightnotneedjquery.com [source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26832769/3622940#comment42239771_26832810)

For all of these patterns, I find using neutral non-pronouns **superior** to switching over to desired pronouns. (as a solution, xe should... ← It's **not natural** to me.) I do not find this a violation of "do not misuse pronouns" since they aren't pronouns. I do not find this as not respecting my peers and I am staying polite with non-pronouns. This is not discriminatory right?

---

**Addendum** While the quoted phrase, "Prefer gender-neutral language when uncertain." might appear to address this, it does not - this question is an inquiry on using gender-neutral language even w[hen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hen) given.

**Addendum-2** I understand the rationale and implication of "in most contexts, your opinions about gender are off-topic," and my above claim that "It's *(this expression is)* not natural to me" is not an opinion on *using gendered pronouns* but *[using terms not yet recognized in English dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Xe)* - it's about correctness of my sentences, not an opinion on how to address someone. I'm not here to argue about whether gendered pronouns are correct, but they will be words defined in dictionaries when they show up in dictionaries. Please treat this stance as-is in face value. It is about how it is **to me**, and is not a commentary on people who use this pattern of expression.

**Addendum-3** In light of the fact that I have used gendered pronouns such as *he* in the past as well as *(s)he*, I am physically not allowed to edit these comments as they are too old. However, under the [grandfather policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_clause) they were retroactively following the *use common sense* rule and should be allowed. If any of my comments have been unacceptable **they should be flagged** and reviewed. I have taken the liberty of fixing [all known instances of me not using gender-neutral language - the one (1) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27791811/3), to show that I am not being hypocritcal. If you find instances of me using gendered language in other answers, please let me know.

---

## OED References for “singular” *they*

Here for the benefit of those who lack access to a paywalled source are the full and complete operative senses from the *Oxford English Dictionary* mentioned but only partially cited due to length considerations in this post’s ephemeral comments below. [Per the OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200700) the pronoun ***they*** has these specific subsenses for the various scenarios under discussion here:

> 2. In anaphoric reference to a singular noun or pronoun.
>
>    <sup>Use of *they* to refer to a singular antecedent has sometimes been considered erroneous.</sup>
>
> > <sub>[**Dennis Baron • *A brief history of singular ‘they’***](https://public.oed.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-singular-they/)</sub>
> >
> > <sub>…But that’s nothing new. The Oxford English Dictionary traces singular *they* back to 1375, where it appears in the medieval romance William and the Werewolf. Except for the old-style language of that poem, its use of singular *they* to refer to an unnamed person seems very modern. Here’s the Middle English version: ‘Hastely hiȝed eche  … þei neyȝþed so neiȝh… þere william & his worþi lef were liand i-fere.’ In modern English, that’s: ‘Each man hurried… till they drew near… where William and his darling were lying together.’…</sub>
> >
> > <sup>[4 September 2018]</sup>

> - **2a.** With an antecedent that is grammatically singular, but refers collectively to the members of a group, or has universal reference (e.g. *each person, everyone, nobody*).
>
>   <sup>Sometimes, but not always, used to avoid having to specify the gender(s) of the individual(s) being referred to; cf. sense [A. 2b.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200700#eid1288185420)</sup>
>
>   [[citations ranging from **1350–2014** omitted]]

> - **2b.**  With an antecedent referring to an individual generically or indefinitely (e.g. *someone, a person, the student*), used esp. so as to make a general reference to such an individual without specifying gender. Cf. [**ʜᴇ** *pron*. 2b](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/84893#eid302969944).
>
>   <sup>In the 21st century, other *th–* pronouns (and the possessive adjective *their*) are sometimes used to refer to a named individual, so as to avoid revealing or making an assumption about that person’s gender; cf. sense [A. 2c](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200700#eid1288185480), and quots. [2008 at **ᴛʜᴇɪʀ** *adj*. 2b](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200291#eid1033522681), [2009 at **ᴛʜᴇᴍ** *pron*. 4b](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200315#eid1033548561), [2009 at **ᴛʜᴇᴍꜱᴇʟꜰ** *pron*. 2b.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/334443#eid1033656331)</sup>
>
>   [[citations ranging from **1450–2010** omitted]]

> - **2c.** Used with reference to a person whose sense of personal identity does not correspond to conventional sex and gender distinctions, and who has typically asked to be referred to as *they* (rather than as *he* or *she*).
>
>   [[citations ranging from **2009–2019** omitted]]

> > > <sup><sub>Copyright © 2019 Oxford University Press. All rights reserved.</sub></sup>

[Retrieved 2019-10-25 23:46:13 UTC](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200700) and shown here under the [Fair Use Exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use).

Comment: To point 3: I can't find the link, but there was another question about that issue and the answer was that there's no need to worry about past posts – only things going forward matter.

Comment: My reading of your other issues are that all those examples are fine as long as you don't do it in a conspicuous or disrespectful way. Those all sound like normal sentences and I don't think a reasonable person (or in the worst case, a mod) would see them as jerkish behavior

Comment: @divibisan Define "disrespectful way", because I'm not here to care about random people's feelings, my content stands on its own and all these ambiguities are not helpful.

Comment: In the context given, both "you" and "the user" refer not to any particular individual but to a generic person. A generic person cannot have preferred pronouns, so the only applicable rule is "prefer gender neutral language." Both "you" and "the user" are gender neutral, and so do not violate the rules.

Comment: @Unihedron I’m saying that in the situation you mention, where you switch to non-gendered language, your interaction is covered under the old, but ambiguous, “Be Nice” rules. I don’t know how you can always ensure that you’re being nice, but that’s always been a problem with social interactions.

Comment: @Unihedron Actually, I might be misreading. If you avoid pronouns for everyone, then you’re in compliance with the CoC. If you always use “the user” or “you” or OP, then you’re fine – there’s no requirement to use pronouns. It’s only an issue if you use pronouns for everyone *except* trans people

Comment: "non-formally accepted made-up form of the singular 'they'". Singular they is accepted and has been for hundreds of years (and, side-note, is no less made-up then any other use of any other word. Grammar by definition is made-up). You can find accepted definitions to that effect in major dictionaries such as the OED. [Useful reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they).

Comment: @Unihedron er yeah. Given that you've sent 4 angry responses to one informational comment that was in no way attacking you, I'm going to pass on a lengthy chat. If you are seeking to actually learn and understand though, I'm always happy to talk.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I'm not interested in defending a position where I consider a usage erroneous as reflected by the OED while I'm trying to get clarifications. I'm neither offended or angry. The CoC is ambiguous and I'm asking it here in the citations post. I want answers, not to get sidetracked. I understand if you have a stance to make, but not in the comments here please. Sorry.

Comment: @Unihedron What you’ve said here is not quite right: the OED does ***not*** itself consider these uses catachrestic ones as you seem to imply. They merely note that it ***“has sometimes been considered erroneous.”*** That’s entirely different from saying **that they** think it’s wrong. They don’t; that’s simply not how lexicography works. In the interests of full disclosure for the truncated references in ephemeral comments and to promote greater understanding about what the OED is actually saying, I have therefore edited your post to include the full OED senses mentioned here in comments.

Comment: @tchrist Thank you. Allow me to reiterate. I consider the singular "they" not suitable for use when it's not plural just as "you is" is not a form I would use. OED does not reject the singular they and has valid cases given where the antecedent is generic. Because of the supposed wide-spreadness of the singular "they" usage, I have redacted the "more grammatically correct" statement since it takes away the light of the actual question when it doesn't need to.

Comment: @Unihedron You’re welcome. It's interesting that they managed to antedate 2c all the way back to 2009. I'd only found cases from the past three-ish years or so myself. Still MMIX ⋙ MCCCL. :)

Comment: It is noteworthy that [the OED blog article](https://public.oed.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-singular-they/) cites a 1794 usage that "used singular they on purpose because ‘they wished to conceal the gender’" - not sourced, cited or used in dictionary entry, can't find it. This block brings me to [a blog entry written by the same person with lots reused segments](https://blogs.illinois.edu/view/25/677177), which has a story on "the Tennessee state legislature passed a law banning the use of taxpayer dollars for gender-neutral pronouns." [Found myself.](https://legiscan.com/TN/bill/HB2248/2015)

Answer (score -2):

The Code of Conduct states:

> **No bigotry.** We don't tolerate any language likely to offend or
> alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion
> — and those are just a few examples. Use stated pronouns (when known).
> When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate.

This is self-contradictory and biased, for the following reasons:

1. It automatically sides with one class of people against another class, and enforces one worldview over and against other worldviews.
2. It gives one class the right to assert their belief in 2+ genders and takes away the right of other classes to equally assert their belief in 2 genders. If one is not only able, but invited, to assert that they believe there are more than 2 genders, why can't someone else assert that they believe there are only 2 genders?
3. It affords the right for one class to demand others to acknowledge, agree with, and accommodate their belief system, but does not grant the same right to others who hold to a different or contradictory belief system and who, therefore, cannot make such acknowledgement, agreement, or accommodation.
4. It states that it does not tolerate language that offends those who embrace a worldview in which more than 2 genders exist, but then it enshrines and itself employs language that offends those who embrace a worldview in which only 2 genders exist. Several religions teach that there are only 2 genders; to insist otherwise is to call into question these religions and the sacred texts of these religions, which is extremely offensive, yet such offense is not only tolerated, but codified in the very language of this Code of Conduct. It would be offensive for one to tell another that their religion is wrong, yet that is exactly what the Code of Conduct is doing; but not only that, it also requires those who embrace those religions to themselves adopt language that contradicts their own belief system. This is doubly offensive.

To get particular, the claim that there are only 2 genders, which can never be changed, is very offensive to some people. This Code of Conduct does not allow this offense, but defines it as bigotry. However, many Christians believe that God created only male and female, and the claim that there are more than 2 genders is very offensive to them, because they understand such a claim to directly contradict biblical teaching. Yet, this offense is allowed. These people are not only expected to endure such offensive language, but also to verbally assent to it and accommodate it, even though it will involve nothing less than compromising and repudiating their own religious convictions. So this group of people are doubly offended by the Code of Conduct.

Why this double-standard? Why can't we recognize that everyone will have different views and that these views will be offensive to some, and simply allow people to believe whatever they want, without forcing others to accommodate any one specific belief system? If one is allowed to assert that there are 2+ genders, another should be allowed to assert that there are only 2 genders; the Code of Conduct should not be siding with either, but should remain impartial to all.

Comment: Point 1 reads like “It favors (e.g.) non-racists and disfavors racists”. I don’t really see an inherent problem with that. Unless you’re on Politics.SE or Biology.SE and specifically discuss race, what’s the issue? Same thing applies to Points 2 and 3 (seems redundant). See [Wikipedia: Intersex](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex); you don’t need to _believe_ that there are more than two genders. No rights are taken away. If I went on Stack Overflow and started discussing that there are _more_ than two genders, this discussion would be correctly deleted, because it’s irrelevant to programming.

Comment: Point 4: The CoC states that SE doesn’t tolerate language that _might offend_ people _based on gender_. It doesn’t say anything about favoring or disfavoring worldviews or any specific worldview in your quote. You don’t need to offend people if you hold a specific worldview. You also don’t need to believe in any specific number of genders to simply use the stated pronouns. A woman shouldn’t be called “he”, a man shouldn’t be called “she” (unless they specifically request that). Next: religions teach all sorts of outdated things.

Comment: The quoted CoC doesn’t prevent you from saying anything against religions itself (where on-topic), only from offending people based on their religious affiliation. And sorry, but this is nearly impossible, given the contradictions between different religions, between flavors of the same religion, and between religion and reality. The mere existence of one religion may offend another. How would _you_ codify something that resolves all these issues? Barely anyone follows their religious text to 100 % accuracy — no issue. Does the Bible actually say there’s only man and woman?

Comment: And finally, the religion debate isn’t new. See [this other answer](/a/336382/289905), [What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?](/a/336369/289905), [FAQ contains language likely to offend or alienate people based on religion](/a/336529/289905), [Why are the Code of Conduct changes received so negatively \[…\]](/a/335093/289905), [Brothers, I must go…](//christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718), [Should we allow or avoid non-standard pronouns?](//christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/514), and countless other posts.

Comment: @SebastianSimon the CoC specifically tells you to "Use stated pronouns (when known)," which automatically sides with the worldview held by those who believe in 2+ genders that gender is fluid. That gender is fluid or that there are 2+ genders is very offensive to some because this claim contradicts their sincerely held religious beliefs and the sacred texts of their religion. The CoC is insensitive and disregards religious convictions in telling people to "use stated pronouns" when doing so contradicts their own religion.

Comment: Can you provide a suggestion for how the CoC could "remain impartial to all", and avoid offending those who believe in the gender binary *and* those who don't, while simultaneously safeguarding both groups from offence? Alternatively, could you explain why your religious beliefs take precedence over those who believe in non-binary genders?

Comment: @F1Krazy Certainly, by simply omitting the requirement to "Use stated pronouns." Some people don't believe in stated pronouns. The whole issue of stated pronouns assumes gender fluidity is true. If people want to believe gender is fluid, let them; if people don't want to believe, let them; don't side with either. Recognize that one's belief offends another, and another's disbelief offends another. We're all adults, so expect both to understand that their beliefs are offensive to others, and to treat people with respect without demanding that they accommodate one's own views.