# Document pronoun policy debate exclusion from scope

Tags: bug, scope, code-of-conduct, tour

The [Meta.SE tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) says:

> Be part of the community that decides how the sites work
>   Any question that has to do with the Stack Exchange family of communities is fair game.
>
> Ask about...
>
> - Specific issues with the software that powers the Stack Exchange network
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered using this software
>
> While we discourage opinions on our main sites, questions here are likely to generate discussion and involve opinions. That's okay!
>
> However, you shouldn't ask about...
>
> - Anything not directly related to the software that powers the Stack Exchange network
> - Questions that require the expertise of a specific Stack Exchange community - these should be asked on that site's meta instead

Based on this, debating or proposing changes to network wide policies, like the Code of Conduct, is on topic.

However, a [recent staff post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336366/627282) stated explicitly that:

> debating the core of the new rule ("please use stated pronouns") ... is off-topic, and we won't be entertaining those debates at this point and posts that aren't questions or requests for clarification may be deleted.

Please document this exception ("debating the core of the new rule") explicitly in the tour (and anywhere else this site's scope is documented) for accuracy and so that people don't make mistakes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You seem to have read that sentence out of context.

> This post here is the place to talk through that. For ease of voting and responding, please limit each answer to one specific concern.
>
> However, note that debating the core of the new rule ("please use stated pronouns") or the validity of people's identities or gender expressions is off-topic, and we won't be entertaining those debates at this point and posts that aren't questions or requests for clarification may be deleted.

The paragraphs in that question sets up the process on how to provide feedback on the specific topic the question is about. That strict process is there because the team expects a lot of feedback/tips/critique/improvements and they want to make sure they can handle all of that with the limited resources they have given the broad interest of a lot of members from the  communities across the network.

As such you can raise a new question on topics mentioned in/related to the Code of Conduct or the detailed FAQ, provided it is not already asked and/or answered before. Do know that also for these questions the generic guidance applies that posts need to be on-topic, useful and of interest for the community of the Stack Exchange network. The community is free to not entertain a debate you want to have, that is not only for SE staff to decide.

<sup>to be welcome to everyone I made the suggested edit that was rejected earlier</sup>

Answer (score 14):

This was only applicable for that question specifically, as it was meant for a *request for clarification*, not *let's fight some more about the policy*. This is how request for clarification threads seem to work (I'm not a usual lurker on MSE, I might be wrong).

You can post a question on the policy, this is on-topic. In fact, there are many questions on the current one, or the old policies for that matter.